# What best practices or performance considerations are there for choosing between Cases, Position, Pick and Select?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, pattern-matching, filtering, function-comparison

`Cases`, `Select`,`Pick` and `Position` each have different syntaxes and purposes, but there are times when you can express the same calculation equivalently using either of them. So with this input:

```
test = RandomInteger[{-25, 25}, {20, 2}]

{{-15, 13}, {-8, 16}, {-8, -19}, {7, 6}, {-21, 9}, {-3, -25}, {21, -18}, {4, 4}, {2, -2}, {-24,  8}, {-17, -8}, {4, -18}, {22, -24}, {-4, -3}, {21, 0}, {19,    18}, {-23, -8}, {23, -25}, {14, -2}, {-1, -13}}
```

You can get the following equivalent results:

```
Cases[test, {_, _?Positive}]

 {{-15, 13}, {-8, 16}, {7, 6}, {-21, 9}, {4, 4}, {-24, 8}, {19, 18}}

Select[test, #[[2]] > 0 &]

 {{-15, 13}, {-8, 16}, {7, 6}, {-21, 9}, {4, 4}, {-24, 8}, {19, 18}}

Pick[test, Sign[test[[All, 2]] ], 1]

 {{-15, 13}, {-8, 16}, {7, 6}, {-21, 9}, {4, 4}, {-24, 8}, {19, 18}}


test[[Flatten@Position[test[[All, 2]], _?Positive] ]]

 {{-15, 13}, {-8, 16}, {7, 6}, {-21, 9}, {4, 4}, {-24, 8}, {19, 18}}
```

Are there performance or other considerations that should guide which you should use? For example, is the pattern-matching used in `Cases` likely to be slower than the functional tests used in `Select`? Are there any generic rules of thumb, or is testing the particular case you are using the only solution?

Comment: For completeness in comparisons, the below might be included. `Extract[test, Position[test[[All, 2]], _?Positive]]` Note its near identity, but for the bracketing of the list of positions, with `Part[test, Flatten[Position[test[[All, 2]], _?Positive]]]`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In my view, `Cases` and `Position` are in one camp (pattern-based functions used for general expression destructuring), while `Select` is in another: (more) special-purpose functions optimized to work on certain efficient data structures.

As was mentioned already, both `Cases` and `Select` do generally unpack when used with packed arrays. What wasn't mentioned is that `Select` can easily be compiled, including compilation to C:

```
sel = Compile[{{lst, _Integer, 2}}, Select[lst, #[[2]] > 0 &], 
        CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

In[98]:= (res3 = sel[test]);//Timing
Out[98]= {0.125,Null}
```

which gives an order of magnitude speed-up in the case at hand. Needless to say, `Cases`, being a general function using patterns, cannot be compiled and any attempt to do so will result in a callback to the main evaluator in the compiled code, which destroys the purpose.

Another difference is that `Select` can also work on sparse arrays, while `Cases` and `Position` can't.

OTOH, `Cases` and `Position` are more general in that they can work on arbitrary expressions (not necessarily packed or even regular arrays), and at an arbitrary level. If you happen to have an (even numerical) irregular nested list, where you can't utilize packing, `Cases` and `Position` may be able to do things `Select` can't (`Select` is limited to one level only). Performance-wise, `Cases` / `Position` can also be very efficient, if the test patterns are constructed properly (mostly syntactic patterns, with no `Condition` or `PatternTest` involved, and preferably not containing things like `__`, `___` etc as sub-parts).

There are instances when `Cases` (`Position` also, but not as much) are practially indispensable, and this is when you want to collect some information about the expression, while preventing its parts from evaluation. For example, getting all symbols involved in an expression `expr`, in unevaluated form, wrapped in `HoldComplete` (say), is as simple as this:

```
Cases[expr, s_Symbol :> HoldComplete[s], {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True]
```

and quite efficient as well. Generally, patterns and destructuring are very (perhaps most) powerful metaprogramming tools that Mathematica provides.

**So, my final advice is this: when you have an expression with a fixed regular structure, or even better, numerical packed array, `Select` or other more precise operations (`Pick` etc) may be advantageous, and also more natural. When you have some general (perhaps symbolic) expression, and want to get some non-trivial information from it, `Cases`, `Position` and other pattern-based functions may be a natural choice.**

Comment: I have a question. As a frequently used built-in function, why `select` is so slow compared to compiled `select` even for `Select[lst, #[[2]] > 0 &]` such a  simple and useful case? `Select[RandomReal[{-7., 7.}, 10000000], # < 0 &]` takes 10 sec, while the compiled version takes 0.37 sec on my computer, it is almost 30 times speed up!! Is `Select`  written in C code?

Comment: @matheorem The problem is that non-compiled `Select` has to make a round-trip through the main evaluator for every element it tests. Top-level evaluation is expensive, so this is slow. When you compile `Select` together with the predicate passed to it, there is no such round-trip, everything happens in compiled code, at much lower level. This is the reason for the speed-up you see.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But I don't understand why mathematica didn't optimize this? At least for such kind of simple implementation that everyone will use, it could add an internal branch as many other built-in function does. In this way, users won't have such a annoying performance issue. What is your opinion?

Comment: @matheorem In this particular case and similar, I agree that Mathematica could try to optimize / autocompile. I don't know why it doesn't do this, it would be a nice improvement if it did. I may file a suggestion for this some time soon.

Answer (score 42):

Another useful thing to do when testing such things is to determine whether packed arrays are unpacking. For all of your cases there is a lot of unpacking going on (I've only shown the first of such messages...)

```
In[1]:= On["Packing"]

In[2]:= test = RandomInteger[{-25, 25}, {10^6, 2}];

In[3]:= (res1 = Cases[test, {_, _?Positive}]); // AbsoluteTiming

During evaluation of In[3]:= Developer`FromPackedArray::punpackl1: Unpacking array with dimensions {1000000,2} to level 1. >>

Out[3]= {1.060814, Null}

In[4]:= (res2 = Select[test, #[[2]] > 0 &]); // AbsoluteTiming

During evaluation of In[4]:= Developer`FromPackedArray::punpackl1: Unpacking array with dimensions {1000000,2} to level 1. >>

Out[4]= {1.856424, Null}

In[5]:= (res3 = 
    test[[Flatten@
       Position[test[[All, 2]], _?Positive]]]); // AbsoluteTiming

During evaluation of In[5]:= Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to Position. >>


Out[5]= {4.742461, Null}
```

Now Pick can be written so that it doesn't unpack...

```
In[6]:= (res4 = Pick[test, Sign[test[[All, 2]]], 1]); // AbsoluteTiming

Out[6]= {0.046801, Null}

In[8]:= Off["Packing"]

In[9]:= res1 == res2 == res3 == res4

Out[9]= True
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is using version 8. In version 7 and before, Pick was not optimized for packed arrays.

Answer (score 11):

I disagree with the way some of these tests have been constructed. Firstly `test[[All,2]]` for positives is quite different from testing `test` for positives in the second column. When you make these tests an apples v apples comparison the results are quite different:

```
test = RandomInteger[{-25, 25}, {10^6, 2}];

AbsoluteTiming[Length[test[[Flatten@Position[test[[All, 2]], _?Positive]]]]]
{3.304881, 489913}
```

IMO `Position` is the winner of other tests solely because you are only testing the second column.

```
AbsoluteTiming[Length[Select[test[[All, 2]], Positive]]]
{0.784350, 489913}

AbsoluteTiming[Length[Cases[test[[All, 2]], _?Positive]]]
{1.140218, 489913}
```

So an apples v apples comparison shows `Position` to be slowest for this example. More generally sometimes I find `Cases` a little bit faster than `Select`, sometimes a little bit slower. Worth testing both each time.

(Note that the above doesn't change the fact that `Pick` is the fastest answer for this)

Answer (score 9):

A little testing says that at least in this case `Position` wins hands down:

```
test = RandomInteger[{-25, 25}, {10^6, 2}];

AbsoluteTiming[Length[Cases[test, {_, _?Positive}]]]
{2.087033, 489565}

AbsoluteTiming[Length[Select[test, #[[2]] > 0 &]]]
{2.265396, 489565}

AbsoluteTiming[Length[test[[Flatten@Position[test[[All, 2]], _?Positive]]]]]
{1.417782, 489565}
```

There's some variability in the results between runs of the test, but at most a few percent.

Comment: Note that `AbsoluteTiming[Length[Select[test, Positive[#[[2]]] &]]]` runs slightly faster than the current version. Better to use `Positive` so as to compare apples to apples I think.