# How can I ensure that I am constructing patterns in the most efficient way possible?

Tags: performance-tuning, pattern-matching

Inspired by [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42/8), I am interested to know if there are best practices or rules of thumb for constructing patterns, for example for use in function definitions (`f[x_Pattern ]` or `f[x:Pattern]`), replacement rules (`expr /. x:Pattern :> y`), or functions that use patterns as arguments (e.g. `Cases`).

Leonid mentions that "syntactic patterns", without `Condition` or `PatternTest` elements, are faster for things like `Cases`. Is this a general observation for all pattern-matching constructs in Mathematica, or is it specific to `Cases`? Is there a definition of a syntactic pattern as opposed to other kinds?

And if the test in question requires "slower" constructs like [`BlankNullSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) (`___`), are there workarounds or optimisations that are effective, or is it not worth the time spent optimising code?

Comment: Somewhat related: What is the difference between `f[x_Pattern]` and `f[x:Pattern]`? I don't know how to really look that up on the documentation.

Comment: The *Mathematica* help system will search on special characters, @Mike.  Searching first for ":" and opening the "More Information" cell will answer your question directly ("The form s_ is equivalent to s:_.")

Comment: @whuber: Thank you, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Some pitfalls in pattern-construction

You should ask several questions:

- Will your pattern involve frequent invocation of the evaluator (this happens if it contains `Condition` and / or `PatternTest`, *and* is tested many times). If yes, this will slow down the pattern-matcher.

Here is an example taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786389/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-check-that-a-list-is-a-list-of-numbers-in-argumen/8787304#8787304)

```
randomString[]:=FromCharacterCode@RandomInteger[{97,122},5];
rstest = Table[randomString[],{1000000}];

In[102]:= MatchQ[rstest,{__String}]//Timing
Out[102]= {0.047,True}

In[103]:= MatchQ[rstest,{__?StringQ}]//Timing
Out[103]= {0.234,True}
```

- Will your pattern make the pattern-matcher perform many a-priori doomed matching attempts (and thus, underutilize the runs of the pattern-matcher)? If yes, this will slow it down *a lot*. Patterns with `BlankSequence` or `BlankNullSequence` are notorious for that, particularly in combination with `ReplaceRepeated`.

For example, this list sorting is very inefficient:

```
list//.{left___,x_,y_,right___}/;x>y:>{left,y,x,right}
```

However, there are cases where such patterns are very efficient as well, such as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740033/is-there-an-equivalent-of-stringposition-for-searching-lists-if-not-whats-t/8740525#8740525).

- Will your pattern lead to excessive copying of parts? This happens also for patterns like `x___`, because the rule like `{x_,y___}:>{y}` will copy the entire sequence (array) `y` during the match. This is because lists are implemented as arrays in Mathematica.

As in example here, consider the following implementation of mergeSort, taken from my answer in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/37c39a26b425cfba):

```
Clear[merge]; 
merge[x_List, y_List] := 
 Block[{merge}, 
   Flatten[merge[x, y] //. {
    merge[{a_, b___}, {c_, d___}] :> 
      If[a < c, 
         {a, merge[{b}, {c, d}]}, {c, merge[{a, b}, {d}]}
      ], 
      merge[{}, {a__}] :> {a}, 
      merge[{a__}, {}] :> {a}}]]
```

This one is very slow. The detailed analysis is in the same answer I linked to, but here is the version based exclusively on `ReplaceRepeated`, but made efficient because it uses linked lists:

```
Clear[toLinkedList]; 
toLinkedList[x_List] := Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Reverse[x]]; 
Module[{h, lrev}, 
  mergeLinked[x_h, y_h] := 
    Last[{x, y, h[]} //. {
        {fst : h[hA_, tA_h], sec : h[hB_, tB_h], e_h} :> 
              If[hA > hB, {tA, sec, h[hA, e]}, {fst, tB, h[hB, e]}], 
        {fst : h[hA_, tA_h], h[], e_h} :> {tA, h[], h[hA, e]}, 
        {h[], sec : h[hB_, tB_h], e_h} :> {h[], tB, h[hB, e]}}]; 

  lrev[set_] := Last[h[set, h[]] //. h[h[hd_, tl_h], acc_h] :> h[tl, h[hd, acc]]]; 

  sort[lst_List] := 
     Flatten[Map[h[#, h[]] &, lst] //. 
         x_List :>       
           Flatten[{toLinkedList@x, {}} //.
            {{hd1_, {hd2_, tail_List}}, accum_List} :> 
               {tail, {accum, lrev@mergeLinked[hd1, hd2]}}], 
         Infinity, h]];
```

Just only due to the use of linked lists and resulting from them memory/run-time savings, this implementation recovers the correct `n log n` asymptotic complexity of the merge sort angorithm, *even though* `ReplaceRepeated` is used all over. The benchmarks can be found in the quoted post.

- Does your pattern lead to accidental unpacking of packed arrays, even when that is not necessary? This can slow things down significantly. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700934/why-is-cases-so-slow-here-are-there-any-tricks-to-speed-it-up/8701756#8701756), I discussed some possible work-arounds to avoid such situtations.

#### Summary and recommendations:

---

- Be careful with `__` and `___`
- Be careful with `ReplaceRepeated`
- Try to construct patterns such as to minimize failed pattern-matching attempts.
- Avoid `Condition` and `PatternTest` whenever possible, and use syntactic patterns
- Watch out for unpacking during the pattern-matcher
- In place of `__` and `___`, try using linked lists when you can

Comment: Thanks Leonid, that is awesome! I am still a little unclear on what a "syntactic pattern" is.

Comment: @Verbeia Well, this is my own term for it, I don't know if it is used by anyone else... Patterns in `mergeLinked` would be good examples. Generally any pattern (preferably with single blanks only), the fact of the match against which can be established based only on the syntactic structure of expressions, without any semantics involved (in particular, `Condition` and `PatterTest` must not be present). Thanks for the accept b.t.w.

Answer (score 12):

In the case of patterns, you should try to use the most specific pattern possible.

The `BlankNullSequence` aggressively tries to match and will recursively trace through your expressions to find something that fits. This takes a lot of time, so you should only use it when necessary.

When you use the most specific pattern possible, you save Mathematica from having to do more work than it needs to. Sometimes you have to use `BlankNullSequence`, but if you can avoid it then by all means do so.