# Combined numerical minimization and maximization

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I want to numerically calculate the maximum of a function defined by the minimization of another function, like the following:

```
NMaximize[b/.NMinimize[(a^2+b)^2,{b}][[2]],{a}]
```

Obviously the intended result (for this simple test function) would be:

```
{0., {a->0.}}
```

because the inner minimization would give b=-a^2 for any value of a, and maximizing that gives 0 for a=0.

However I get the error message `NMinimize::nnum: "The function value (-0.829053+a^2)^2 is not a number at {b} = {-0.829053}."` and the result `NMaximize[b/.{b},{a}]`. I figured that this is due to premature evaluation of the argument (i.e. before `a` got anumerical value), therefore I tried to wrap either the whole first argument of just the `NMinimize` call in `Unevaluated`, but neither helped.

So my question is: How can I do this combined numerical optimization?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a rather common issue that comes up with many numerical functions (`FindRoot`, `NIntegrate`, `FindMaximum`, `NMaximize`, etc.)  It is also explained in [this Wolfram Knowledge Base article](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820). Sometimes you want to pass these functions an expression that has a symbolic parameter, and compute the result for different values of that parameter.

Example:

```
fun[a_] := Block[{b}, b /. NMinimize[(a^2 + b)^2, {b}][[2]]]
```

This will work nicely if you call it with a numeric argument: `fun[3]`.  But it will cause an error in `NMinimize` if you call it with a symbolic parameter: `fun[a]` (for obvious reasons).

The solution is:

```
Clear[fun]
fun[a_?NumericQ] := Block[{b}, b /. NMinimize[(a^2 + b)^2, {b}][[2]]]

NMaximize[fun[a], {a}]
```

(Be sure to evaluate `Clear[...]` to get rid of the previous definition of `fun`!)

This ensures that `fun` will only evaluate for numerical arguments, i.e. `fun[a]` won't evaluate inside `NMaximize` before `NMaximize` actually substitutes a number for `a`.

And this is also the answer to your specific question: make the inner `NMinimize` expression a separate function, and make sure it only evaluates for numerical arguments.

---

**Requested edit**

An important related point is: how can we match only numerical quantities using a pattern?  One might think of using `_Real` (as in the comment below).  The problem with this is that it will only match numbers whose `Head` is `Real`.  This excludes integers (such as `1,2,3`), rationals (`2/3, 4/5`), constants (such as `Pi` or `E`), or expressions like `Sqrt[2]`.

The only robust solution is using `NumericQ[]` (`x_ ? NumericQ` in a pattern).  `NumericQ` will return `True` for anything that gives a number when `N[]` is applied to it.

There's another related function, `NumberQ[]`, which gives `True` only for objects with `Integer`, `Rational`, `Real` or `Complex`, but *not* for constant or expressions (`Pi` or `Sin[3]`).

Comment: This is such a common issue I suggested making a [tag:faq]-item out of it even before the site was launched.  It comes up every 10 days on MathGroup.

Comment: A small followup question: I've noticed that `fun[a_Real]` seems to work as well in my toy example (I hoped to make it faster that way, but it didn't have any significant effect). Are there cases for `NMinimize` where `a_Real` would fail, but `a_?NumericQ` wouldn't?

Comment: @celtschk See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was specific to `NMinimize`. It's clear to me that the function then will not work if given symbolic or exact arguments; however, it's not clear to me whether `NMinimize` will ever pass anything not matching `_Real` to the function.

Comment: @celtschk I can't tell you if it will ever pass an integer, but I wouldn't worry about performance differences.  `NumericQ` is well optimized.  I'll dig up a benchmark later.

Comment: Thank you. I was worried because one of the rules in [this answer about pattern efficiency](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/295/129) was "Avoid Condition and PatternTest whenever possible, and use syntactic patterns".

Comment: @celtschk I've got to run now, but [here's some discussion of argument checking efficiency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786389/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-check-that-a-list-is-a-list-of-numbers-in-argumen) (and links to other posts as well).  Not precisely the same, I know.  For your specific example with `NMinimize`/`NMaximize`: this is simply not an issue here because checking the pattern is much faster than (negligible compared to) the `NMinimize` *inside* the function.