# Strategies to avoid LessEqual::nord in NMinimize?

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

When using `NMinimize` on functions with complex intermediate expressions (but a real end result), quite often one gets the error `LessEqual::nord`. Example:

```
NMinimize[Abs[(a+I b)^(3/2)],{a,b}]
(*
LessEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with 0.306069 + 0. I attempted.

LessEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with 0.306069 + 0. I attempted.

LessEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with 0.306069 + 0. I attempted.

General::stop: Further output of LessEqual::nord
     will be suppressed during this calculation.

Less::nord: Invalid comparison with -0.0745302 + 0. I attempted.

NMinimize::cvmit: 
   Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100
     iterations.

{1.0635969220476164*^-12 + 0.*I, {a -> -8.71759358950322*^-9, b -> 5.707170335837908*^-9}}
*)
```

In some cases (not the one above; I didn't find a simple one where it happens) this also results in a clearly wrong result. Therefore it's desirable to remove the error messages.

Now the only way to get rid of this error is to change the expression in a way that it doesn't trigger the error. However the expressions are generally complicated enough that it's not feasible by hand. I've found that a combination of the following strategies works *sometimes:*

- Use `ComplexExpand` with the option `TargetFunctions->{Re,Im}`.
- Put the entire expression into an `Abs` or `Re` (despite it being known to be real from construction) and use `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` with appropriate constraints (and hope it finishes in reasonable time). (`Abs` of course only works if the result is also nonnegative)

However those strategies are not always sufficient. Therefore my question:

What are other good strategies to get the expression into a form suitable to `NMinimize`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have to do the same as in many [such cases](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/333/combined-numerical-minimization-and-maximization): protect your arguments to be strictly numerical:

```
f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := Abs[(a + I b)^(3/2)];
```

And  then no problems:

```
NMinimize[f[a,b],{a,b}]

(*
 ==>  {1.11868*10^-26,{a->3.9489*10^-18,b->3.07007*10^-18}}
*)
```

**Edit:**

The following function automatically packs the expression into a function with `_?NumericQ` pattern arguments:

```
NOptimize[optfunc_,expr_,vars_,options___]:=
  Module[{f,
          varlist=If[ListQ[vars],vars,{vars}],
          expression=If[ListQ[expr],First@expr,expr],
          conditions=If[ListQ[expr],Rest@expr,{}]},
    Evaluate[f@@(Pattern[#,_?NumericQ]&/@varlist)]=expression;
    optfunc[{f@@varlist}~Join~conditions,vars,options]]
```

It can be used as follows:

```
NOptimize[NMinimize, a^2, a, AccuracyGoal->0.01]
(*
--> {2.39829*10^-33,{a->4.89724*10^-17}}
*)
```

or with constraints:

```
NOptimize[NMinimize, {a^2, a>3}, a, AccuracyGoal->0.01]
(*
--> {9.,{a->3.}}
*)
```

The following shows that it indeed solves the problem with `LessEqual::Nord`:

```
NOptimize[NMinimize,Abs[(a+I b)^(3/2)],{a,b}]
(*
--> {9.06219*10^-27,{a->4.31982*10^-18,b->4.8223*10^-19}}
*)
```

Comment: `_?NumericQ` belongs at the top of the FAQ.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Agree.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's what I said here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/333/combined-numerical-minimization-and-maximization  .

Comment: @Leonid But to be honest, I really don't understand what's going on here and how symbolic evaluation can give this result.  Perhaps `NMinimize` symbolically pre-processes the argument.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, that's what is happening. The problem is that say `Complex[2.,0.]` does not get transformed to `2.` (unlike when real and imaginary parts are integers). You can `Trace` the evauation with `TraceInternal -> True`, but you don't really want to do that :)

Comment: Astonishing. I would never have guessed that it is caused by passing non-numerical values. From the error, I thought that the `+ 0.*I` was the problem. But with `_?NumericQ` it indeed works!

Comment: I've now written a little function which automatizes it. Now I think it would be interesting for others, too, therefore I'd like to post it here. However I'm not sure how: Add it to the question? Add it as new answer? Add it as a comment (if it happens to fit the character count limit ― I didn't check yet)? Or maybe make a new question "Can this be improved" or similar and add a link to that question here?

Comment: @celtschk I'd just edit my answer and add it as the *EDIT* section at the end. If you can't edit my post directly, send an edit request and I or other folks will approve. If you don't like the idea, you can also add this as another answer, but I think it'd be an overkill here.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Thanks, I'll do that. Should I mark the added text as mine (so that if the code is not up to your standard quality, people don't associate it with you?)

Comment: @celtschk You may mark that this is your contribution, if you like. This is totally up to you - I am sure your addition will be good, and  I can anyway edit it if I feel that something needs editing.

Answer (score 7):

(This is a bit too long for a comment.)

Compare with:

```
FindMinimum[Abs[(a + I b)^(3/2)], {{a, 1}, {b, 1}}]
{1.4576121587694715*^-12, {a -> -9.089664269711015*^-9, b -> -9.09099600216378*^-9}}
```

but as you have seen, the version with `NMinimize[]` doesn't work. A look at the functions' `Attributes[]` sheds some light:

```
Attributes[NMinimize]
{Protected, ReadProtected}

Attributes[FindMinimum]
{HoldAll, Protected}
```

That `HoldAll` in `FindMinimum[]` spells the difference. The `HoldAll` attribute allows for [nonstandard evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html) of the objective function within the internals of `FindMinimum[]`. `NMinimize[]`, on the other hand, sees the complex numbers within the objective function. Since part of what `NMinimize[]` does before the optimization is to start with the initial region $-1 \leq a,b \leq 1$ ([which it does in the absence of explicit constraints](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html#408968279)), there is inevitably the interaction of complex numbers with comparison operators, leading to the observed warning messages.

Comment: The more experienced users will understand the implications of `HoldAll`, but the less experienced users will not. Could you expand the answer a bit?

Comment: Sure.$\phantom{}$

Comment: Good references, +1.

Comment: The HoldAll attribute is the crux of the problem. See also Michael Trott's Numerics book, section 1.6: "No good excuse is available why NDSolve and NMinimize do not have the HoldAll attribute. Both functions have dummy variables that should be scoped from the surrounding."

Answer (score 3):

If I interpret your question as about getting rid of error messages ("it's desirable to remove the error messages"), you may use `Off`:

```
Off[LessEqual::nord];
Off[Less::nord];
NMinimize[Abs[(a + I b)^(3/2)], {a, b}]
(*
NMinimize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision 
within 100 iterations. 

{1.0636*10^-12 + 0. I, {a -> -8.71759->10^-9, b -> 5.70717->10^-9}}

*)
```

Comment: Well, I also wrote that the reason why I want to get rid of them is that it gives sometimes wrong results. Which clearly shows that I wanted to actually get rid of the error, not just the messages, because suppressing the messages doesn't fix the result.

Comment: Well, you actually wrote "In some cases this also results in a clearly wrong result. Therefore...", which I interpreted as "the result is obviously wrong, so I don't need messages cluttering up my display, I know it!". Stupid me :)

Comment: I wasn't aware that my text could be misinterpreted that way. Of course the main concern is that I might also get wrong results *without* noticing it.

Comment: @celtschk no, it was probably stupidity on my part. However, you could try this: `ClearAll[f];f[(a_)?NumericQ, (b_)?NumericQ] := (Sow[{a, b}]; Abs[(a + I*b)^(3/2)]); Select[Last[Last[Reap[NMinimize[f[a, b], {a, b}]]]], #1 ==Im[#1] & ]` to see that it never actually does get a complex input. Or `Trace` it, but the output of that is too large.

Comment: FWIW I too read that piece of the question as wanting to suppress the error messages, not necessarily get rid of the errors themselves. So I don't think you should blame stupidity, acl, just misinterpretation.

Comment: A shorter way: `Quiet[NMinimize[Abs[(a + I b)^(3/2)], {a, b}]]`. Or if you only have to turn off specific messages: `Quiet[NMinimize[Abs[(a + I b)^(3/2)], {a, b}], {LessEqual::nord, Less::nord}]`.