# Syntax highlighting for your own functions

Tags: front-end, syntax-highlighting

Mathematica has a useful feature that for functions and special constructs getting passed local variables (for example `Minimize` or `Block`), the affected variables are shown in a different colour. Now when writing your own functions of this type (like the `NOptimize` function found in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/499/129)), Mathematica of course doesn't know the meaning of the arguments and doesn't change the colours accordingly.

Is there a way to tell Mathematica that an argument is a set of variables to affect other arguments?

To make this post self-contained, here a small (admittedly silly) example:

```
SetAttributes[SequenceVars,HoldAll]
SequenceVars[vars_List,expr_]:=Block[vars,vars=Range@Length@vars;expr]
(* add syntax highlighting somehow *)

SequenceVars[{a,b,c},foo[a,b,c,d]]
(* here a, b and c, but not d, should appear in a different colour while typing *)
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

What you want is `SyntaxInformation`. With this, you can use every highlighting which already exists for things like `Table`, `Solve`, etc. for your own functions. You can specify the pattern of the arguments. With this you get the typical *red commas* if you use too many parameters. Or you can highlight locally used variables inside the function-arguments:

```
SetAttributes[SequenceVars, HoldAll]
SyntaxInformation[SequenceVars] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _}, 
   "LocalVariables" -> {"Solve", {1, 1}}};
SequenceVars[vars_List, expr_] := 
 Block[vars, vars = Range@Length@vars; expr]
```

It looks like this in the front-end:

[image]

The usage of the `"LocalVariables"` highlighting is as follows. First, you choose the general type of highlighting. For instance `"Solve"` provides simple `x` or lists like `{a,b}` while `"Plot"` provides highlighting for the first element in e.g. `{a,1,2}`.

You can use the following settings as templates

```
{"Table", "Solve", "Integrate", "Limit", "Plot", "Manipulate"}
```

Additionally, you need to specify at which places of your function call the local variable specifications can appear. Say you want a function where in the first argument is some expression and then can follow arbitrary many lists of local variables. The definition for that would look like

```
SyntaxInformation[f] = {"ArgumentPattern" -> {_, __},
  "LocalVariables" -> {"Solve", {2, Infinity}}}
```

This looks then like

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and should make clear how `"LocalVariables"` has to be used.

### Update

Since this function seems to be of unexpected interest, I should add one more important thing: `SyntaxInformation` can highlight wrong options. If you use `OptionsPattern` in your "ArgumentsPattern" option, all non-existent options will be highlighted in red

```
Options[f] = {a -> 1, b -> True};
f[x_] = Identity;
SyntaxInformation[f] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, OptionsPattern[]}};
```

Now using f with right/wrong options gives

[image]

Comment: Interesting! I had no idea that `SyntaxInformation` can handle local variables. Big +1.

Comment: Thx. I know this a long time, maybe since it was introduced, but I never ever managed to remember this functions name when I needed it. Now it's written down and I can look it up.

Comment: I should have done my homework. @Simon once added the highlighting to a function I developed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367932/generate-a-list-in-mathematica-with-a-conditional-tested-for-each-element/6368770#6368770, and I should have remembered this now, but I just didn't.

Comment: Works great except for one small detail: At least in 8.0, it's `"ArgumentsPattern"`, not `"ArgumentPattern"`.

Comment: @celtschk My mistake. Corrected.

Comment: Wow, 16 upvotes in 2 hours, I didn't know this information was scarce since it's in the docs. @halirutan, do you know if it can be used to simulate a With/Block/Module-like local with the equal sign lala[{x=8}, ...]?

Comment: Even though I regularly use `ArgumentsPattern` to be honest I've never really understood the `LocalVariables` syntax. I don't find the documentation very helpful.

Comment: `"ArgumentPattern"` works just fine too on version 7.  Does it fail in version 8?

Comment: @Rojo none of the given option-values for "LocalVariables" seems to fit for that. I would say it cannot be possible regarding the power of the highlighting in Block/Module/With. Consider the following two examples `Table[Table[i, {i, 5}], {i, 5}]` and `Block[{i = 3}, Block[{i = 3}, i]]`. There happens more parsing in Block/Module constructs than simple highlighting would be able to.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Sorry for the late reply; I only noticed your question just now. Yes, it fails with `"ArgumentPattern"` in Version 8 (at least in 8.0.0.0), but works with `"ArgumentsPattern"`.

Comment: @celtschk thanks

Answer (score 14):

*This answer is focussed at more experienced users, to provide a way for them to find out more information. I do not discuss how anything works.*

*Information in this answer corresponds to version 10.3*

Despite the fact that `PrintDefinitions@SyntaxInformation` gives nothing, we can still see how the function works, by doing

```
<< GeneralUtilites`
PrintDefinitions@System`Utilities`GetSystemSyntaxInformation
```

`` System`Utilities`GetSystemSyntaxInformation `` is pretty much equivalent to `SyntaxInformation`.

From the definition of `` System`Utilities`GetSystemSyntaxInformation ``, we see that the full list of "options of `SyntaxInformation`" is

```
(*sio is short for SyntaxInformation options*)
sio = {"ArgumentsPattern", "OptionNames", "LocalVariables", "ColorEqualSigns"}
```

Of these options `"OptionNames"` is undocumented (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98478/4330) for an example of use, credit to jkuczm)

The following procedure gives a list of basic template names

```
informationFile = 
  ToFileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Kernel", 
    "TextResources", $Language}, "FunctionInformation.m"];
(*sife is short for System Information File Expression*)
sife = If[FileType[informationFile] === File, 
   Get[informationFile], {}];
templatesWithNames=
Select[
sife[[1,2]]
,
Length@#>3&&#[[4]]=!= None&
][[All,{1,4}]];
DeleteDuplicates@templatesWithNames[[All,2,1]]
```

> ```
> {"Manipulate", "Solve", "Plot", "Table", "D", "Integrate", "Limit",
>  "SumSign", "IntegralSign"}
> ```

Of these, `{"D", "IntegralSign", "SumSign"}` do not appear in the docs.

I had forgotten about the `"Lexical"` modifier, but that is not undocumented, see [the details section of the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html#)). Here are some examples of templates that involve it and also one that does not.

```
manipulateTemplates = 
 Select[templatesWithNames, #[[2, 1]] == "Manipulate" &]
```

> ```
> {"Animate",{"Manipulate",{2,∞},"Lexical"}}
> {"ControllerManipulate",{"Manipulate",{2,∞},"Lexical"}}
> {"Manipulate",{"Manipulate",{2,∞},"Lexical"}}
> {"RepeatingElement",{"Manipulate",{2}}}
> ```

Also this is weird

```
"ArgumentsPattern" /. SyntaxInformation@EmbedCode
```

> ```
> {_, Optional["/Volumes/Jenkins/workspace/Documentation.Usage.English.release/scratch"], 
> _., OptionsPattern[]}
> ```

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this is possible for the `Input` - style cells, but it is certainly possible for the `Program`-style cells with the [syntax highlighter generator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/customizing-syntax-highlighting-for-private-cell-styles/1320#1320) I exposed in a recent answer. The work in that direction is underway, but I don't have a complete package at the moment. In fact, apart from code highlighting for languages like C, Java, etc, a strong motivation for that project for me was to create an extensible syntax highlighter for Mathematica based on it. I hope to have more to say on this soon.

Note that, in general, an implementation of the syntax highlighting of the type you mentioned requires context / semantic analysis of the program - lexical analysis is not enough.

Comment: A nice package, but since it didn't exactly answer my question, I've given an upvote on the linked answer instead.

Comment: @celtschk I think you made the right choice. If I knew that `SyntaxInformation` handles local variables, I would not bother suggesting this.  I expect however that the highlighter I may make based  on my package will be more flexible at the end, since I have full control over the way tokens are highlighted. Even now, it does paren-matching, braces and bracket - matching, and highlights them in different colors. I don't know how easy it is to enable this for `Input` cells, and how flexible it is. So, I will still keep this answer.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin:  Will your syntax highlighter be usable as a replacement for the built-in syntax highlighter from Wolfram for Input cells or is it restricted just to formatting/highlighting other programming languages in non-Input style cells?  Also what is the current status of the project?

Comment: @StackExchanger Yes, I plan to cover Mathematica as well. Potentially it will allow more than the built-in syntax highlighter. The current status of the project is that it is perfectly usable for someone to generate highlighters for any given language. In the attached notebook, I gave an example for C. I also did it for Java. It really takes just a few lines of code to write a spec for a given language, and a package for that language is generated automatically. The project needs some work though - I don't support comments yet, need to define this through styles, etc. Hope to address this soon

Comment: Leonid's syntax highlighter is incredible. I use it for Java, Scala, C#, Ocaml, and F# code. Just reading the code teaches you a lot about M.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke Thanks:) But it actually has to be rewritten. It has a number of design issues which I hope to address soon enough. In many places, the code is pretty ugly to my taste, also.

Comment: @Leonid: Still doesn't refute my ironclad claims that it's incredible and highly educational, just be reading the code. :)