# How to program a F::argx message?

Tags: function-construction, packages, syntax-highlighting, message-coding

How useful is it to program a user-built function in a package to produce a red warning message [`F::argx`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/General/argx.html) if you give the wrong number of arguments to that function? How do I do this?

Comment: have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1449/16)?

Answer (score 26):

*The large addendum on handling multiple messages as built-ins do has been moved to a separate post; please see the link below for advanced message handling options.*

- [How to check the style and number of arguments like the built-in functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85821/how-to-check-the-style-and-number-of-arguments-like-the-built-in-functions/86604#86604)

---

#### Macro package function `SetArgumentCount`

In recent versions there is an undocumented function `` Macros`SetArgumentCount `` that specifically automates creation of a definition for an argument Message.  Examples:

```
Macros`SetArgumentCount[foo, 2]

foo[1]
foo[1, 2, 3]
```

> foo::argr: foo called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected.
>
> foo::argrx: foo called with 3 arguments; 2 arguments are expected.

```
Macros`SetArgumentCount[foo, {2, 4}]

foo[1]
foo[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

> foo::argbu: foo called with 1 argument; between 2 and 4 arguments are expected. >>
>
> foo::argb: foo called with 5 arguments; between 2 and 4 arguments are expected. >>

(Returned input intentionally omitted.)

---

#### Available messages

The message `::argx` is one of the general messages intended for use with any function.  These have the special property of being called for any symbol used (placed left of `::`):

```
Message[foo::"argx", "foo", 2, 3]
```

> foo::argx: foo called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>

Use `Messages[General]` to see a list of these messages.

#### Synax highlighting

[`SyntaxInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html) can be used to create the red syntax highlighting present in many built-in functions.  For a full description please see:

- [Syntax highlighting for your own functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1446/121)

#### Basic usage

You may have noticed that the method shown in R.M's answer doesn't produce behavior that exactly matches internal functions such as `Plot`, which echo bad input:

```
Plot[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> Plot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of 4) beyond position 2 in Plot[1,2,3,4]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules. >>
>
> ```
> Plot[1, 2, 3, 4]
> ```

To get this you behavior you can generate the `Message` as a side-effect, as in `Condition`:

```
ClearAll@f
SyntaxInformation[f] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_}};
f[1] := True
f[_] := False
f[x___] /; Message[f::argx, "f", Length@{x}] := Null
```

Now:

```
f[1, 2, 3]
```

> f::argx: f called with 3 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>
>
> ```
> f[1, 2, 3]
> ```

The final no-match rule can also be written:

```
x_f /; Message[f::argx, "f", Length @ Unevaluated @ x] := Null
```

Comment: You said it didn't produce the same behaviour as in built-ins and that using condition was better... I just don't see it in the example

Comment: @rm-rf Oh.  Your catch definition actually *matches* and returns `Message[f::argx, "f", Length@{x} + 1]` or rather the `Null` it produces; my catch definition *does not match* and produces the message as a side-effect, and therefore the original input is returned.  This is how most internal definitions are written.

Comment: Ah, it keeps the input unevaluated. +1

Comment: btw, I just remembered why I _don't_ use this in my packages... if you have different messages being thrown based on the form of the input (as I often have), then throwing messages as a side-effect of not matching the form will result in _all_ messages being thrown.

Comment: @rm-rf please see my update and tell me if it makes sense as written.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm a little busy now, but will definitely read it later in the day

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you expose here a great summary of techniques, thank you for this.

Comment: @Faysal Thanks, and you're welcome.  It's been a while since I've used these methods in my own code so hopefully I didn't make too many mistakes here; please let me know if you find any.

Comment: Sidenote: `ArgumentCountQ` lets you be more declarative and takes care of selecting the message argx, argtu, argrx, according to the number of arguments required. E.g, ``f[i___] /; 
  ArgumentCountQ[f, 
   System`FEDump`NonOptionArgCount[{i}], {2, 5}] := Null``

Comment: Just read through your "fall-through" method. Clever.

Comment: I thought `func[___]?funcmsg` was clever before, I think `_func?funcmsg` is superior.

Comment: If I want to define a head f: `f[a_,b_*c_]:=... ;` `f[a_*b_,g[c_]]:=...; `How to define my syntax-checking function?

Comment: @WateSoyan I would need more information to properly answer that.  Why don't you post a new question explaining your function and what you wish to accomplish regarding syntax-checking and message generation?

Comment: Though my function here is fabricate , indeed I often have this need.

Comment: Dear Mr.Wizard, In the section *"Basic usage"*, `f[x___] /; Message[f::argx, "f", Length@{x}] := Null`, However, I cannot understand why `f[1,2,3]` gives the warning information. Could you help me to understand it? Thks:)

Comment: Accodrding the usage of `/;`  in *DOC*, `lhs:=rhs/;test`  is a definition to be used only if `test` yields `True`.

Comment: @ShutaoTang The `Message` expression is evaluated as part of the `Condition`.  `Message` itself returns `Null`, therefore the condition does not match, but by that time the message has already been printed.  The RHS is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: In addition , I cannot find the definition `HiddenOptions` in the auxiliary function `optCheck`

Comment: @ShutaoTang `hiddenOptions` is not really significant here; it holds internal options that are not intended to be set by the user.  In version 10.1.0 you can see these for `ArrayPlot` with ``DownValues[Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`hiddenOptions]``.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, In my V10.1, ``DownValues[Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`hiddenOptions]`` gives the result`{}`

Comment: Dear Mr.Wizard, Now I have a small request. Could you use the `Catch-all method` or `Fall-through method` to deal with [my qestion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85821/how-to-check-the-style-and-number-of-arguments-like-the-built-in-functions) like the `self-contained example` you give in the end of you answer. And make it has the effect like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpe3b.png)

Comment: @ShutaoTang I'll take another look at try to provide a useful example.

Comment: @ShutaoTang I am too sleepy to do this properly right now, and also this answer needs updating too.  I'll try to get around to it tomorrow.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, OK, but now it is day time in China:)

Answer (score 16):

As acl points out, [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1449) shows you how to setup error highlighting for invalid number of arguments. Coming to the actual error messages used, there are three built-in messages attached to `General`, that can be used for your own functions as well. These are `argx`, `argrx` and `argt`:

```
General::argx
(* "`1` called with `2` arguments; 1 argument is expected." *)

General::argrx
(* "`1` called with `2` arguments; `3` arguments are expected." *)

General::argt
(* "`1` called with `2` arguments; `3` or `4` arguments are expected." *)
```

You can attach these messages to your own functions (any message defined for `General` can be used for any other symbol) like in the following example (shown only for `argx`):

```
ClearAll@f
SyntaxInformation[f] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_}};
f[1] := True
f[_] := False
f[_, x__] := Message[f::argx, "f", Length@{x} + 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There's a nice internal method for this that has existed since at least 10.4: `` System`Private`ArgumentsWithRules ``.

You can use it to define a nicely handled function like so:

```
f[args___] :=
 With[
  {
   a =
    System`Private`ArgumentsWithRules[
     f[args](*function with args to gather from*), 
     {
      0(*min length*),
      1(*max length*)
      }, 
     Hold(*head to wrap on the lists*)
     ]
   },
  yourFunctionBody /; Length[a] > 0
  ]

f[1, 2]

f::argt: f called with 2 arguments; 0 or 1 arguments are expected.

f[1, 2]
```

Even better, if `f` has `Options` this detects it:

```
Options[f] = {"a" -> "b"};
f[1, 2]

f::nonopt: Options expected (instead of 2) beyond position 1 in f[1,2]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.

f[1, 2]
```

This makes it useful extension on `ArgumentCountQ`:

```
ArgumentCountQ[f, 3, 1, 2]

f::argt: f called with 3 arguments; 1 or 2 arguments are expected.

False
```

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between ``System`Private`Arguments`` and ``System`Private`ArgumentsWithRules``?  They seem to behave in the same way.  Also, it seems to color the `f` black in the front end just be calling it like ``System`Private`ArgumentsWithRules[f[a, b], {1, 2}, g]`` from a fresh kernel.

Comment: @QuantumDot `ArgumentsWithRules` provides options checking for us. See [this](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/tutorial/package-usage-and-development/higher-level-features/function-preparation.html) and [this](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/tutorial/reference-guides/undocumented-contexts/system-%2A.html)

Comment: Hmm.. it seems `Arguments` itself can provide option checking: ``Options[f] = {opt1 -> x};  System`Private`Arguments[f[a, b, c], {1, 2}, g]``

Comment: @QuantumDot ah hmm, I remember the difference being subtle. It might be just in the message or the return or something. Just pick one and be consistent I figure.

Answer (score 1):

Thats what I learned.
To see if my function has just 2 arguments, not 1 argument and no more the 2 arguments I did these steps:
Define the warnings

```
General::twoplus = "f called with to much arguments, 2 argument expected.";  
General::twominus = "f called with 1 argument, 2 arguments expected.";  
f[_, _, x__] := Message[f::twoplus, "f", Length@{x} + 1]  
f[x__] := Message[f::twominus, "f", Length@{x} + 1]
```

Define the function

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y + 1;
```

Call the function

```
f[1]  
f::twominus: f called with 1 argument, 2 arguments expected.  

f[1, 2]  
4  

f[1, 2, 3]  
f::twoplus: f called with to much arguments, 2 argument expected.
```

Comment: Some things to consider: (1) Your messages have no placeholders; nothing is being filled in from the second and following arguments of `Message`. You can use merely `Message[f::twominus]` if you want the message printed verbatim. (2) You may wish to define the message for `f` rather than for `General` unless you intend to use the same messages for other functions as well.