# Looking for feedback on this function

Tags: code-review

I'm not sure this is an appropriate question; if not, I'm sure someone will close it :)

I've got the following function, listed below; its job is to accept a graph (function) presented either as a single-variable function (e.g., `x^2`), or as a parametrized function (e.g. `{t Cos[t], t Sin[t]}`) and compute its curvature at some set of values of the variable:

```
SetAttributes[curvature,HoldAll];
SyntaxInformation[curvature]={"LocalVariables"->{"Table",{2,2}},
    "ArgumentsPattern"->{_,_}};
curvature[f_, pts_] := Block[{extvar,var,fn,i,res},
    extvar = ReleaseHold[Hold[pts]/.{x_,y__}:>HoldPattern[x]];
    fn = ReleaseHold[Hold[f]/.extvar:>var];
    If[!ListQ[fn], fn={var,fn}];
    res = Table[1/Sqrt[Total[D[fn,var]^2]]/.var->i,
                Evaluate[Join[{i},Rest[pts]]]];
    If[Length[res]==1,res=res[[1]]];res]
```

The second parameter is in "`Table`" form, and is interpreted as for `Table`. The first two lines of the function extract the formal variable used in `f` and substitute occurrences of it in `f` by a local variable. The third line converts a single-variable function to parametric form. The next line actually does the work, computing the relevant formula over the set of values defined by the second parameter. Finally, if the result is a singleton, it gets converted back to a scalar by the final line of the function.

So for example

```
curvature[ x^2, {x,3} ]
{1/Sqrt[5], 1/Sqrt[17], 1/Sqrt[37]}
```

I'm looking for feedback on the way this function is written. For example (but not only), have I properly extracted the formal parameter (`x` in the example above) and the function? Is there a better way to evaluate the formula at the values specified by the second parameter? Finally, how about the manipulation in the last line? Any other feedback is welcome as well.

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  I take it my suggestions helped?  Any follow-up questions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shotgun thoughts:

- You don't need the `Hold`/`ReleaseHold` pair; `Unevaluated` will do: `Unevaluated[f] /. rules`
- You can use direct [destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8399/121) to extract `extvar`: `curvature[f_, range : {var_, __}] :=`
- By extracting `var` as above you can `Block` it directly, simplifying everything.
- You can leave the `Table` variable out of the main `Block` as it is already localized.
- `res /. {z_} :> z` can replace the line `If[Length[res] == 1, res = res[[1]]]; res`
- In fact `res` can be eliminated and the rule applied to the `Table`
- You can pre-evaluate your `1/Sqrt[Total[D[fn,var]^2]]` expression; this should be faster, and also eliminates the need for the replacement inside the `Table`

Putting it together I would write:

```
SetAttributes[curvature, HoldAll];

curvature[f_, range : {var_, __}] :=
  Block[{var},
    Module[{fn},
      fn = If[ListQ[f], f, {var, f}];
      fn = 1/Sqrt[Total[D[fn, var]^2]];
      Table[fn, range] /. {z_} :> z
    ]
  ]
```

You will notice red highlighting of `var` signifying a *possible* conflict; this is *not* a problem and is in fact exactly what I desire: the sharing of `var` between the function, the `Block`, and the `Table`.

---

My answer originally had `fn` in the `Block` declaration.  This is bad because conceivably `fn` could appear in the function expression and this would conflict.  I have moved it to a `Module` now.

An alternative is to do without that symbol entirely by writing the lines of code as Functions:

```
curvature[f_, range : {var_, __}] :=
 Block[{var},
  Table[#, range] /. {z_} :> z &[
   1/Sqrt[Total[D[#, var]^2]] &[
    If[ListQ[f], f, {var, f}]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: @rogerl I just noticed something as I looked at this again; `fn` should be in a `Module` not `Block`, in case the symbol `fn` might appear in `f`; alternatively `fn` should be replaced with a Formal symbol.  I need to revise my answer.

Comment: I would go even as far as setting `var_` to `var_Symbol` to add an extra bit of protection, especially as your passing it into `Block`.

Comment: @rcollyer That's not a bad idea, however `curvature[foo, {1, 2, 3}]` produces `Block::lvsym: Local variable specification {1} contains 1, which is not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol. >>` and halts, which IMHO is also not a bad behavior; the problem is safely made clear without having to add such messages to `curvature` itself.  Do you disagree?

Comment: True. If this were production code, I'd consider co-opting the message text, and using raising it myself. There is no need for the user to know that `Block` is used in the implementation. If not production code, then I'd let it slide. Either way, +1.

Comment: @rcollyer Okay, we agree.  I had no intention of writing this rigorously.  I [do know how](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23356/121) to provide full testing and messages if required.

Comment: I never meant to suggest you didn't, but for the OPs edification ...

Comment: @rcollyer I didn't honestly infer that you were, but for the OPs edification I got to share a link.  How long shall we keep this up? :-)

Comment: I think we can get five or six more messages in. I'd ask how your family was, but I don't know any of those details, so I'll refrain. :)

Comment: @rcollyer [Archimedes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLI46yMdtmU) continues to laugh at me frequently. :o)

Answer (score 6):

The main problem, as I see it: your formula for the curvature is incorrect. Here is a derivation of the curvature using *Mathematica*:

```
Clear[x, y, t, vec, velocity, tangent, speed, curvature]

tangent[t_] = Simplify[velocity[t]/speed[t]];

curvature[t_] = 
  Sqrt[#.#] &@FullSimplify[D[tangent[t], t]/speed[t], speed[t] > 0];

vec[t_] = Through[{x, y}[t]]

(* ==> {x[t], y[t]} *)

velocity[t_] = D[vec[t], t];

speed[t_] = Sqrt[velocity[t].velocity[t]];

Simplify[curvature[t]]
```

> $$\sqrt{\frac{\left(x''(t) y'(t)-x'(t)
>    y''(t)\right)^2}{\left(x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2\right)^3}}$$

Comment: Ack. Thanks for catching this.