# Why evaluation doesn't fail if arguments are invalid?

Tags: functions, argument-patterns

Sorry for a noob question, but this is something that I wonder about each time I work with Mathematica.

Coming from standard programming languages (Python and Java), I expect my functions to fail loudly if I pass them a wrong set of arguments. However in Mathematica (and on the level of annoyances, this is second only to the insane undo), when Apply[Function, Arglist] is given a wrong shape of arguments, it does not fail but perform some obscure manipulation without giving out any warning or error. Resulting bugs are often hard to detect and take up time and effort in development to get rid of.

So my question is two-fold:

1. What are the reasons for such behavior?
2. What can be done in the function definition to cause failure instead of a silent bug?

Comment: While I voted to close as a dupe, one clarification here is that Mathematica is a symbolic environment, and there are (almost) no real functions. Most of what you think of as functions are actually global replacement rules. When no rule matches, the expression is simply returned back - which makes sense in a symbolic environment, and is *not* a bug or an error. I recommend reading [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node17.html) and [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/chapterNode5.html), and also relevant sections of books by David Wagner and Roman Maeder, for more.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Thanks for the rapid answer. However it is not exactly what I was looking for. My problem is not that I supply Strings instead of Integers or leave the field void, but rater supplying to the function {{x_},{x'_},{x''_}} instead of {x_, y_}.

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please also see: [(23345)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23345), [(85821)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85821/121)

Answer (score 6):

You can make your code very defensive in *Mathematica* if you are willing put in the effort it takes. When writing code that I expect will get a lot of use over a long period, both by me and others, I take pains to make the exposed function reasonably fool-proof.

When I'm worried about being passed invalid arguments, I almost always take one of two routes.

1. Give my function the `HoldAll` attribute and validate the arguments myself int the function body. This is the method of choice when I want complete control over the error messages issued. I am likely to explicitly return $Failure after issuing an error message.
2. Require the given arguments to match stringent argument patterns. This let's me draw on *Mathematica*'s powerful pattern matching language to protect my function from bad calls.

Here are examples drawn from a turtle graphics package I have written. They mainly use the second approach, but the first one also does some internal validation because it processes options that use string tags to identify the option chosen.

```
turtleGraphics::"badargs" = "`1` doesn't know what to do with `2`";
turtleGraphics::"badopt" = "`1` isn't a valid `2`";

Options[draw] = {"graphics" -> True, "reset" -> True};

draw[t_Symbol, opts : OptionsPattern[{draw, Graphics}]] :=
 Module[{clrF, postF},
   clrF =
     If[OptionValue["reset"],
       clearTrack,
       Identity,
       Message[turtleGraphics::"badopt", 
         Style[{"reset" -> OptionValue["reset"]}, "SBO"], "drawing option"];
       Return @ $Failed];
   Switch[postF = OptionValue["graphics"],
     True | Graphics, 
       Graphics[render[t, clrF], Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics]]]],
     False | Identity, render[t, clrF],
     _Symbol | _Function, postF @ render[t, clrF],
     _, Message[turtleGraphics::"badopt", 
          Style[{"graphics" -> OptionValue["graphics"]}, "SBO"], "drawing option"]; 
        $Failed]]

draw[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := draw[$turtle, opts]

draw[args : __] :=
  Message[turtleGraphics::"badargs", "draw", Style[Defer @ {args}, "SBO"]]
```

This second example taken from the same package uses a fairly fussy pattern to reject invalid color specifications.

```
validColor = (_RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue);

pc[t_Symbol, c : validColor] :=
  (If[isTurtle[t],
     setColor[t, colorToRGB[c]],
     Message[turtleGraphics::"notsymb", "pc"]];)

pc[c_] := pc[$turtle, c]

pc[args : ___] :=
  Message[turtleGraphics::"badargs", "pc", Style[Defer @ {args}, "SBO"]]
```

Sorry that I couldn't come up simpler examples, but functions thst need this kind argument or option validation tend more than a couple of lines. Note that `draw` expends more code on validation than on doing "real" work. It hands off the work to `render` which doesn't do validation because it was implemented under the expectation that any needed validation has already been done. `render` is not exposed for public use.

#### update

Here is a quotation from turtle graphics documentation. I add to make `draw` option processing more clear.

---

`draw` returns a turtle's track as a graphics object or as a list of graphics primitives. What is returned is controlled by the option `"graphics"`.

- `"graphics" -> True` or `"graphics" -> Graphics`. When either of these options is given, a graphics object is returned; this is the default. In this case, `draw` will also accept any options accepted by `Graphics` and pass them on when it calls `Graphics`. In those cases, when the `"graphics"` option is used to turn off this behavior, any graphics options will be ignored.
- `"graphics" -> False` or `"graphics" -> Identity`. When either of these options is given, a list of graphics primitives is returned. This second option is useful when the intent is to combine the turtle track with other graphics primitives as part as a larger graphics object. n this case, `draw` will not accept any further options.
- `"graphics" -> f_Symbol` or `"graphics" -> f_Function`. When an option of one of these two forms is given, the output of `draw` will be `f[render[...]]`. It should be clear that `f` must evaluate to a function of one variable.

  This third option form is supplied strictly for convenience; there is nothing that can be accomplished by using this form that can't be accomplished by post-processing the list returned when "graphics" -> False is given.

Side effects. If the turtle's pen is down when `draw` is called, the turtle's pen is raised and this has additional effects (see `pu`).

`draw` has an additional option, `"reset"`, with the default value, `True`, meaning the turtle's track will be cleared when `draw` completes; when the alternative value, `False`, is given, the track will be preserved.