# Options for a function I define that can be passed to functions I call in the definition

Tags: functions, options

I know, this is very close to [Functions with Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/353/functions-with-options) and/or [Function with custom Options and modified Options for built-in Symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20470/function-with-custom-options-and-modified-options-for-built-in-symbols), but I don't get it.

My function looks like this one:

```
myPlot[data1_, data2_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{Rescaled, dataRescaled},
  Rescaled[x_, commonZero_: False] :=
   If[commonZero,
    (* for an common zero line *)
    x - 5,
    (* normal *)
    x
    ];
  dataRescaled = Rescaled[data2];
  ListLinePlot[{data1, dataRescaled},
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListLinePlot]],
   PlotLegends -> {"should not", "be the legend"}]
  ]
```

And this is how I want to call it:

```
myPlot[
 Sin[Range[51, 100, .1]],
 Cos[Range[51, 100, .1]] + 5,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

But how can I add an option "CommonZero->True"?

**EDIT:**

I edited my function this way

```
myPlot[data1_, data2_, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[{ListLinePlot, Rescaled}]] :=
 Module[{Rescaled, dataRescaled},
  Options[Rescaled] = {CommonZero -> False};
  Rescaled[x_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
   If[OptionValue[CommonZero],
    (* for an common zero line *)
    x - 5,
    (* normal *)
    x
    ];
  dataRescaled = 
   Rescaled[data2, CommonZero -> OptionValue[CommonZero]];

  ListLinePlot[{data1, dataRescaled},
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListLinePlot]],
   PlotLegends -> {"should not", "be the legend"}]
  ]
```

But I doubt this is the right or a nice way to do.

Comment: `Options[myPlot] = Sort[Append[Options[Plot], "CommonZero" -> True]]` and use `OptionValue[]` and `FilterRules[]` as necessary.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Is the edited solution what you meant?

Comment: If you'll pardon me for being frank, your implementation looks a bit more fragile (unless this is a toy example and your actual routine has good reasons for having a function definition within a function definition). Maybe separate out `Rescaled`, and set up an option default list the way I did in my previous comment.

Comment: I gave [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48217/3066)  to illustrate a different issue, but it is a pretty good example of handling options in a function definition.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I don't mind you being frank, on contrary. As I would call myself still a beginner in Mathematica, I'm thankful for every suggestion for improvement. But yes, it's just a toy function :-) But I was not aware one should not define functions in functions (if they should be 'private'). So I guess building a own package would be a good way?! Or is there another way to have private functions?

Comment: "should not" is a bit stronger than what I wanted to say; my only point was that this style looks to be difficult to maintain and can be easily broken during modification. The package is the classical way of having a few public functions that use private subroutines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can pull the function `Rescaled` outside of `myPlot`, as [Guess who it is](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/guess-who-it-is) suggests, then it can be done in a fairly straightforward way.  (If `Rescaled` is to depend on the arguments to `myPlot`, perhaps `Rescaled` can be written so that any needed parameters can be passed to it through the function call instead coded in its definition.  Then the following method could be used.)

```
ClearAll[Rescaled, myPlot];
Options[Rescaled] = {"CommonZero" -> False};
Rescaled[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  If[TrueQ@OptionValue["CommonZero"],  (*for an common zero line*)
   x - 5,                              (*normal*)
   x];
myPlot[data1_, data2_, opts : OptionsPattern[{ListLinePlot, Rescaled}]] := 
 Module[{dataRescaled},
  dataRescaled = Rescaled[data2, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Rescaled]]];
  ListLinePlot[{data1, dataRescaled}, 
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListLinePlot]], 
   PlotLegends -> {"should not", "be the legend"}]
  ]

myPlot[Sin[Range[51, 100, .1]], Cos[Range[51, 100, .1]] + 5, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, "CommonZero" -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: My idea with the neasted function was to have a kind of a 'private' function because I dont want to have a lot userdefined functions around.

Comment: @Phab (1) The way *Mathematica* does that for its own functions is usually through [Contexts](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html).  Use ``foo`Rescaled`` instead of just `Rescaled`, where `foo` is a name you choose. (2) Otherwise you can move the Rescaled defs (both Options and Rescaled) inside the module (without change) and add `Options[myPlot] = Join[Options[ListLinePlot], {"CommonZero" -> False}];` before the definition of `myPlot`. (3) If it's truly a lot of functions, consider [Packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ContextsAndPackages.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I follow this, the central issue is how to have the main function accept a list of options that need to be separately dispersed to different functions internally.

After messing around a good bit, I've given up on even using `OptionsPattern` for the main input

```
myf[a_, opts : OptionsPattern[commonZero -> 42]] :=
    Print[Row[{"myf option is ", OptionValue[commonZero]}]]
f[fn_, opts_List: {}] := (
    myf[0, Evaluate[
          Cases[ opts , x_Rule /; MemberQ[{commonZero}, First@x]]]];
    Plot[fn, {x, 0, 1}, 
         Evaluate[
           Cases[ opts , 
              x_Rule /; MemberQ[First /@ Options[Plot], First@x]]]])

f[x]
f[Sqrt[x] + 1/2, {PlotRange -> {1/2, 3/2}, commonZero -> 1}]
```

[image]

This obviously needs work to make robust (A single option must be in `{}` for one thing ).