# Writing my own error and warning messages

Tags: message-coding, upvalues, assignment

**Question:**

How is message handling implemented in Mathematica when applying `Set` to unprotected global variables such as `$TimeZone` in the `System` context?

**Exercise:**

The documentation indicates that `Set` can be used with arguments such as `Integer`, `Real`, or a time zone `String` (e.g. `"Asia/Hong_Kong"`), and so if I set `$TimeZone` to something I know not to exist such as `$TimeZone = "America/Agloe"` or anything not supported for that matter, I receive the following message:

[image: $TimeZone::tzset error message]

I suspect this functionality has been implemented using a low-level or undocumented version of something similar to `$Pre` or its close cousin `$PreRead`.  As these are both also global variables defined in the `System` context it appears this functionality is not implemented using them.

**Problem Motivating the Question:**

I would like to implement in one of my own packages a similar behavior for some exported global variables that will hold package settings as state variables but without having to define one or more `setGlobalVariable[...]` functions and avoiding protecting these global variables.  This would more easily open up the possibilty to override these global variables with the `Block[{$MyGlobalVariable = MySettingForGlobalVariable},...]` construct.

Comment: Look up [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html) and [`MessageName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MessageName.html) in the Documentation Center. Also, see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48217/3066) for an example of how these functions are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
$tz::tzset = 
  "Unable to set $tz to `1`. Time zone should be 
       an integer, real number, a string, or an Entity object.";

$tz /: Set[$tz, x_] := 
 If[Internal`PossibleTimeZoneQ[x], OwnValues[$tz] = {HoldPattern[$tz] -> x}; x, 
  Message[$tz::tzset, x, False]]
```

```
$tz = 1
```

$\ $`1`

and

```
$tz = "America/Agloe"
```

[image: Message]

```
$tz
```

$\ $`1`

Comment: How does `$TimeZone` avoid showing something other than `{}` for `UpValues` in the case of `UpValues[$TimeZone]`?

Comment: @rfrasier-mlp My answer only mimics the behavior of `$TimeZone` in a limited way. `$TimeZone` probably doesn't use `UpVales`. Try for example `OwnValues[$TimeZone] = {HoldPattern[$TimeZone] -> "test"};
?? $TimeZone` and then `$TimeZone; ?? $TimeZone`.

Comment: @rfrasier-mlp You could use `Attributes[$tz] = {ReadProtected}` to hide the `UpValues`, when `?? $tz` is used.