# How to force error on pattern match failure?

Tags: programming

For example, suppose that `foo` is defined like this.

```
foo[x_Integer, y_Integer] := x + y;
```

Then, any expression with head `foo` that does *not* match the pattern given above will remain "unevaluated".  E.g., `foo[3]` "evaluates" to `foo[3]`.

Although I recognize that there are situations where one may want precisely this behavior, in most of my programming I don't.  Quite the contrary: I want expressions like `foo[3]` to be treated as *malformed*, IOW, as *errors*, and therefore to result in a loud, unequivocal failure whenever they are evaluated.

Hence, I find myself writing a lot of code of the form

```
foo[x_Integer, y_Integer] := x + y;
foo[___] := Abort[];
```

(Actually, I use a slightly embellished version of `Abort[]`.)

But including a line like

```
foo[___] := Abort[];
```

for every function one defines adds up to a lot of hard-to-maintain clutter-code.

Does *Mathematica* have some other way to achieve the same thing with less clutter?

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48208/3066

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29321/12

Comment: The practice of adding a definition of the form `foo[___] := ...` is pretty much the standard idiom. I have never found that it produced any code maintenance problems.

Comment: `Abort` is a rather drastic measure, and IMO not really the right solution for a reusable functions ...  Unfortunately there's no one consistent way to deal with failures in Mathematica.  Typical ways are: keep unevaluated *and* issue a message.  Return `$Failed`, with or without a message.  Return `Failure[...]`.  In functions internal to your package: use `Throw` maybe.

Comment: The common practice is to make a call to `Message` and print an informative error message.

Comment: As m_goldberg notes, adding an explicit definition for "everything else" is standard practice (look at the code in the standard add-on packages, for instance).

Comment: @J.M.: If what you write is true (and I have no reason to doubt it is) then this means that *Mathematica* requires excessive amounts of boilerplate code to deal with an extremely common use-case; in my book, this is a sign of incompetent design.  (I guess I expected better from *Mathematica*.)  In Haskell, for example, which uses pattern-matching extensively in function definitions, any expression that does not match a pattern known to the compiler results in an error; there's no need to explicitly define a catch-all case to emit the error.

Comment: That's only if you want the "catch-all" case to do something (e.g. emit a `Message`) aside from coming out unevaluated; for instance, if you have a definition like `f[n_Integer] := n!` and you try to evaluate `f[0.5]`, the expression is returned as is.

Comment: @J.M.:I realize that `f[0.5]` is returned as is.  My whole point is that, in my coding at least (and apparently, per your earlier comment, in a lot of the *Mathematica* standard library) such way of handling `f[0.5]` is **not** desirable, thus necessitating the explicit catch-all case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `foo[___] := Abort[]` try this

```
LHS_foo := RuleCondition[Developer`CheckArgumentCount[LHS, 2, 2]; Fail];
```

It uses lots of undocumented functions, so it might not be to your taste.

It accomplishes @m_goldberg 's suggestion in the comments.