# How to check the option value?

Tags: programming, options, message-coding

Given that I have a function `func` as follow:

To check the value of options, I using the step-by-step method `If[]`

```
Options[func] = {Method -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, Order->2};

func::badval = "`1` is not a valid value of option `2`";

func[arg1_,arg2_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{method, prec, order},
  method = Method /. {opts} /. Options[func];
  prec= WorkingPrecision/. {opts} /. Options[func];
  order= Order/. {opts} /. Options[func];
  (*Check the value of the options*)
  If[
   ! MemberQ[
    {{"Euler", 2}, {"Midpoint", 2}, {"Heun", 2}, {"Heun", 3},
     {"Kutta", 3}, {"RK", 4}, {"Gill", 4}, Automatic}, method],
    Message[func::badval, method, Method]; Return[$Failed]];

  If[
   ! (prec === MachinePrecision || NumericQ[prec]),
   Message[func::badval, prec, WorkingPrecision]; Return[$Failed]];

  If[
   ! (Head[order] ===Integer&& order >= 1),
   Message[func::badval, order, Order]; Return[$Failed]];

  (*main implementation*)
  arg1 + arg2
 ]
```

#### Test

```
func[1, 2, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecisio, Order -> 1., Method -> Automati]
```

> func::badval: Automati is not a valid value of option Method

However, I hope the warning information should like this or like the `Plot`(see below)

> func::badval: Automati is not a valid value of option Method
>
> func::badval: MachinePrecisiois not a valid value of option WorkingPrecision
>
> func::badval: 1.is not a valid value of option Order

**The built-in throw the warning information**

```
Plot[2 Sin[x] + x, {x, 0, 15}, 
 PlotRange -> {a, c}, Filling -> bb, 
 Mesh -> pp, Axes -> Fals, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecisi]
```

> General::prng: Value of option PlotRange -> {a,c} is not All, Full, Automatic, a positive machine number, or an appropriate list of range specifications.
>
> Plot::wprec: Value of option WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecisi is not a positive machine-sized real or integer. >>
>
> Mesh::ilevels: pp is not a valid mesh specification. >>

#### Question

- How to check the value of options like the *built-in* functions, especially when the function have many options(the option number of `Plot` is `60`)?

---

As said by *Mr.Wizard* in the comment, I hope that the `func` executes the following operation:

(1) Multiple messages are issued

(2) Using default option values.

Comment: Just add a module variable `fail=False`, change the `Return[$Failed]` to `fail=True`, after all checks, add `If[fail,Return[$Failed]]`.

Comment: What is your reason for preferring `method/.{opts}/.Options[func]` over `OptionValue[method]`?

Comment: In your `Plot` example (1) multiple messages are issued and (2) the plot is still rendered using default option values.  Are both these behaviors something you wish to duplicate?

Comment: Okay.  That is an old manual, and while it is still an authoritative reference *for its time* there are newer methods available.  This is such a case.  `OptionValue` is now the preferred method in most cases and I intend to use it where applicable.  I suggest you read:  [(355)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/355/121)

Comment: I am waiting for you to answer my question about the behaviors you wish to emulate before I start on an answer.  Better yet update your question to include a *specific* description of what you mean by *"like the built-in functions."*

Comment: Okay.  Again it would be best if you include that in your Question to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the simplest change to your code is to replace the `Return[$Failed]` expressions with Sets that restore the default values of the options:

```
ClearAll[func]

Options[func] = {Method -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, Order -> 2};

func::badval = "`1` is not a valid value of option `2`";

func[arg1_, arg2_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{method, prec, order},
  method = OptionValue[Method];
  prec = OptionValue[WorkingPrecision];
  order = OptionValue[Order];
  (*Check the value of the options*)
  If[! MemberQ[{{"Euler", 2}, {"Midpoint", 2}, {"Heun", 2}, {"Heun", 3}, {"Kutta", 
       3}, {"RK", 4}, {"Gill", 4}, Automatic}, method], 
   Message[func::badval, method, Method]; method = Method /. Options[func]];
  If[! (prec === MachinePrecision || NumericQ[prec]), 
   Message[func::badval, prec, WorkingPrecision]; 
   prec = WorkingPrecision /. Options[func]];
  If[! (Head[order] === Integer && order >= 1), Message[func::badval, order, Order]; 
   order = Order /. Options[func]];
  (*main implementation*){arg1 + arg2, {method, prec, order}}]
```

Now:

```
func[1, 2, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecisio, Order -> 1., Method -> Automati]
```

> func::badval: Automati is not a valid value of option Method
>
> func::badval: MachinePrecisio is not a valid value of option WorkingPrecision
>
> func::badval: 1.` is not a valid value of option Order
>
> General::stop: Further output of func::badval will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> ```
> {3, {Automatic, MachinePrecision, 2}}
> ```

(Note that I included the option values explicitly in the output for visibility.)

This does make the assumption that the `Options` settings are never wrong.  A more robust method would be to keep a separate set of known safe option values as hidden defaults, e.g.:

```
$defaultOptions[func] =
   {Method -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, Order -> 2};
```

Then in the function body use:

```
Method /. $defaultOptions[func]
```

This will protect against an invalid `SetOptions[func, . . .]` usage as well.

Comment: That's a good way - perhaps add the fact default is restored to msg.  +1