# how to manipulate pattern-matched lists for replacements

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, warning-messages

Consider the following simplified code snippet:

```
line=Line[{#, 2 #} & /@ Range[10]]  (* arbitrary line *)
line /. {Line[x_List] -> Line[Most@x]}
```

Mathematica reports of the second line that

> Most::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Most[x].

- Please explain why I get this warning.  Is my approach incorrect?
- Can I do this replacement without raising a warning?
- Why does this code still provide the desired output, despite the warning?

Comment: You should use [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) (i.e. `:>`) instead of a simple `Rule` (i.e. `->`) to delay evaluation of the right-hand-side of your replacement rule until a value has been assigned to `x`. Otherwise `Most` will be applied to `x` when this doesn't have a value, and will return the error you saw.

Comment: @MarcoB Ah of course. Thanks.  But now I am puzzled why the substitution I used did in fact work ...

Comment: Alan, rather than mark your question as a duplicate I chose to answer the implied question *why does the substitution still work despite the warning?*  May I edit your question to include that in the bulleted points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is partially a duplicate of [Unexpected behavior of rule matching a pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22917/121) but I would like to focus on the third point, i.e.

> Ah of course. Thanks.  But now I am puzzled why the substitution I used did in fact work ...

Your replacement `line /. {Line[x_List] -> Line[Most@x]}` *works*, despite issuing a warning, so long as `x` is unassigned, because like most *Mathematica* functions `Most` returns its unevaluated form in the case of bad input.

```
Most["foo"]
```

> Most::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Most[foo]. >>
>
> ```
> Most["foo"]
> ```

If this expression is later transformed into valid input the function will operate as normal:

```
% /. "foo" -> {1, 2, 3}
```

> ```
> {1, 2}
> ```

In this example (using `%`, shorthand for [`Out`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html)) no [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html) is issued as once the unevaluated form is returned it is not evaluated again until it is modified; this is to prevent infinite recursion.

If `x` is assigned a value the code breaks:

```
x = 7;
{1, 2, 3} /. x_List -> Most[x]
```

> Most::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Most[7]. >>
>
> ```
> Most[7]
> ```

If `x` is non-zero-length you get seemingly errant output without even a warning message:

```
x = {7, 8};

{1, 2, 3} /. x_List -> Most[x]
```

> ```
> {7}
> ```

This evaluation sequence where evaluation will continue if possible even after an "error" is both a strength of and a danger in *Mathematica*.   A savvy programmer can understand these *warning messages* as what they are and may even intentionally write code that would issue them if not for the application of [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html).  However it also means that coding mistakes unravel in a strange and seemingly unpredictable way sometimes.

Incidentally you may wish to provide such warning messages for your own functions rather than explicitly returning [`$Failed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Failed.html) on any bad input.  For an approach to this please see:

- [How to check the style and number of arguments like the built-in functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85821/121)