# Creating an advance If statement nest with /; as conditions

Tags: functions, function-construction, homework

Create a slightly more advanced version that does not use nested If statements, but instead uses the conditional /; to determine whether the function is evaluated at all. If the data are not ordered pairs, or the {min, max} are not in range, the function should just echo back what you initially typed into it.

This is what I have so far. I'm not sure what to modify:

```
function8[data : {{_, _} ..}, min_, max_] := 
  Mean [data[[All, 2]] /; min <= #[[1]] <= max &];
function8[data : {{_, _} ..}, min_, max_] := 
  InputForm["Not data within range!"] /; min >= #[[1]] >= max &;
```

Answer (score 3):

> If the data are not ordered pairs, or the {min, max} are not in range, the function should just echo back what you initially typed into it.

This requires that *no definition* match under the given condition.  For example

```
foo[data : {{_, _} ..}, min_, max_] /; max >= min := "some action"
```

Now if any part of this pattern including the [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) does not match the input is returned:

```
foo[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 5, 2]

foo[{1, 2, 3}, 3, 5]
```

> ```
> foo[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 5, 2]
>
> foo[{1, 2, 3}, 3, 5]
> ```

A valid input evaluates:

```
foo[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 3, 8]
```

> ```
> "some action"
> ```

If your condition depends on the output of the function then you need [a very specific use of `Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html#123)

> **lhs := Module[{vars}, rhs /; test]** allows local variables to be shared
>   between test and rhs. You can use the same construction with Block and
>   With.

So maybe you want something like this:

```
Clear[foo]

foo[data : {{_, _} ..}, min_, max_] :=
  Module[{mean},
    mean = Mean[ data[[All, 2]] ];
    mean /; min <= mean <= max
  ]
```

Now:

```
foo[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 1, 5]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

But:

```
foo[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 5, 7]
```

> ```
> foo[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 5, 7]
> ```

And any other bad input is returned as-is:

```
foo["not good data", 5, 7]
```

> ```
> foo["not good data", 5, 7]
> ```

Additional reading:

- [How to check the style and number of arguments like the built-in functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85821/121)

Comment: nice and simple +1

Answer (score 2):

You only need to make one conditional definition, and leave the "error handling" to a default definition that will apply in those cases in which the condition fails to match:

```
ClearAll[function8]

(* Conditional definition; a "special case" *)
function8[data : {{_, _} ..}, min_, max_] /; 
  min <= Min[data[[All, 2]]] && max >= Max[data[[All, 2]]] := 
 Mean[data[[All, 2]]]

(* Catch-all definition: all other cases *)
function8[data : {{_, _} ..}, min_, max_] := "No data within range!"

function8[{{1, -2}, {2, -1}, {3, 5}, {4, 10}}, -4, 15]
(* Out: 3 *)

function8[{{1, -2}, {2, -1}, {3, 5}, {4, 10}}, 40, 50]
(* Out: "No data within range!" *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function8[data : {{_, _} ..}, min_,max_] := (Mean[data[[All, 2]]] /; 
AnyTrue[{Min[data], Max[data]}, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{min, max}], #] &])

function8[data : {{_, _} ..}, min_, max_] := "No data in range"
```