# How can we create functions like Mathematica does?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Simple question. How can we construct functions like Mathematica does?

For example, let's say that we want to create our own `D` function.

The `D` function works like:

```
In[1]:= D[x^2, x]
Out[1]= 2 x
```

where we can put a function in `x` and the function will treat this internally in a correct way.

How can we create our `D1` function with the same behavior?

Attempts:

```
In[1]:= D1[f_, x_] := Limit[(-f[x] + f[x + a])/a, a -> 0]


In[2]:= D1[x^2, x]

Out[2]= Limit[(-(x^2)[x] + (x^2)[a + x])/a, a -> 0]


In[3]:= D1[Function[x, x^2], x]

Out[3]= 2 x


In[4]:= D1[#^2 &, x]

Out[4]= 2 x
```

As we can see, the second and third example work, but I'd like to create a function that would work like in the first example and like the `D` function.

How can we do this?

Comment: Such function would consist with a large set of rules: how to treat constants, sums, products, power functions, etc.

Comment: It is not necessary to have all behavior. It is more about how to use the arguments without using Function[x, ...] or #...&.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[D1]

D1[f : _Function | _Symbol, x_] := Block[{a}, Limit[(-f[x] + f[x + a])/a, a -> 0]]

D1[f_, x_] := D1[Function[x, f], x]
```

Now these all return `2 x`:

```
D1[x^2, x]

D1[#^2 &, x]

fun[z_] := z^2; D1[fun, x]

D1[fun[x], x]
```

Comment: This solution is very interesting, indeed. Is it possible to solve the problem pointed by @yarchik? `D1[x^3,x^2]`

Comment: @GarouDan Pardon me, I'm not familiar with this syntax.  `D[x^3, x^2]` yields `General::ivar: x^2 is not a valid variable. >>`

Comment: Yes, it should give an error in this case. That is what it does.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:**

Based on the suggestion by Bob Hanlon, this code should be better as it isolates `a` from the context of the notebook.

```
D1[f_, x_] := Module[{a}, Limit[(-f + (f /. {x -> (x + a)}))/a, a -> 0]]
```

---

I've tried this on a few functions and it seems to return the same as `D`, but there are probably edge cases I haven't considered.

```
D1[f_, x_] := Limit[(-f + (f /. {x -> (x + a)}))/a, a -> 0]
D1[x^2, x]
D1[3 x^3 + y^2, x]
D1[3 Sin[2 x] y^2 + 14, x]
```

> $2x$
>
> $9x^2$
>
> $6y^2\cos{2x}$

Comment: Cool, this seems to be what I was looking for. I'll give it a try and return.

Comment: I would use `Module[{a}, Limit[ ... ]]` to isolate `a` from the `Global` context.

Comment: @BobHanlon Great idea, thank you!

Comment: The second argument needs to be a valid variable. Current version gives zero for `D1[x^3,x^2]`.

Comment: @yarchik I guess it should be set to fail and issue a warning message like `D[x^3, x^2]` does. Do you think `D1[f_, x_Symbol]:=...` would be sufficient?

Comment: Right, something along this line.

Comment: I tried the `x_Symbol`. It doesn't work.

Comment: I've seen now that after killing the kernel it seems to work. But without any error message. I wasn't able to find a way to raise the correct validation error.

Comment: @GarouDan `Message[General::ivar, x^2]` will give the message.  Regarding error handling see [(85821)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85821/121) for some options.