# Why isn't Table iterator value inserted in failed NIntegrate arguments?

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation, list-manipulation, warning-messages

Consider this simplest example:

```
Table[{z, NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, z}]}, {z, {1}}]
```

Here `f` is not defined, so `NIntegrate` is expected to fail, which it does:

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand f[x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. >>

But what happens additionally is quite a strange error message:

> NIntegrate::nlim: x = z is not a valid limit of integration. >>

When I look at the resulting table, I see

```
{{1, NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, z}]}}
```

So, for some reason `z` appears in the `NIntegrate` arguments not substituted by its value of `1`, although it is substituted by `1` in `%[[1,1]]` element.

What happened? Why does the resulting expression not know the value of iterator? How do I force it to, so that the result would have `{x,0,1}` instead of `{x,0,z}`?

Comment: The function NIntegrate has attribute HoldAll, so its arguments remain unevaluated at the function call. Wrap {x,0,z} in Evaluate  (assuming that x does not have a value) to force evaluation.

Comment: @FredSimons great, this could be made an answer.

Comment: I have nothing to add to the excellent answer of Mr. Wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Fred Simons](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/20253/fred-simons) comments [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) has the [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute but alone that does not explain this behavior.  With the literal assignment `z = 1` no `NIntegrate::nlim` message prints:

```
z = 1;

NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, z}]
```

[`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) normally works by the same mechanism as [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html), and indeed we see the same behavior from `Block`:

```
ClearAll[f, x, z]

Block[{z = 1}, NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, z}]]
```

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand f[x] has evaluated to non-numerical
>   values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. >>
>
> NIntegrate::nlim: x = z is not a valid limit of integration. >>

What is happening is that the unevaluated form of the failed `NIntegrate` expression is returned *outside* that construct and re-evaluated in that environment where `z` has no value.  To make this more explicit consider:

```
z = "outside Block";

Table[NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, z}], {z, {"inside Block"}}]
```

> NIntegrate::nlim: x = inside Block is not a valid limit of
>   integration. >>
>
> NIntegrate::nlim: x = outside Block is not a valid limit of
>   integration. >>

---

#### Attempt at clarification

For the function (e.g. `NIntegerate`) to return unevaluated from `Table` or `Block` it must have a hold attribute and be written such that a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) or [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) fails.  Understand that messages may be generated even when a condition fails; for detailed examples see my answer to [How to program a F::argx message?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23345/how-to-program-a-fargx-message/23356#23356)  As a simplified example for the purpose of this answer consider:

```
Attributes[foo] = {HoldAll};

foo[x_, y_] /; x < 5 || Print[x, " not less than five"] := x^y
```

This definition has a `Condition` which contains a `Print` expression (a proxy for `Message` for this example) -- if `x` is not a numeric quantity less than five a message will be printed *and* the condition will fail as `Print` returns `Null`, not `True`.  Because no definition for `foo` matches the input is returned without further evaluation:

```
foo[9, 3]
```

> 9 not less than five
>
> ```
> foo[9, 3]
> ```

If this takes place inside `Block` the unevaluated form is returned from `Block` to the global environment:

```
Block[{bar = 7}, foo[bar, 2]]
```

> 7 not less than five
>
> bar not less than five
>
> ```
> foo[bar, 2]
> ```

Note that one message is printed for the value of `bar` inside the `Block` and another is printed for the evaluation that takes place afterward where `bar` has no value.  If `bar` is given a global value it will be used:

```
bar = 4;

Block[{bar = 7}, foo[bar, 2]]
```

> 7 not less than five
>
> ```
> 16
> ```

Comment: Hmm, so does this mean that the unevaluated form is returned by `Table` as a specially handled thing, not as a result of evaluation? I.e. if we had `noIntegrate[z]`, it'd be returned as `noIntegrate["inside Block"]` for undefined `noIntegrate`, while if `noIntegrate` call were to fail, it'd be returned as `noIntegrate[z]`, right?

Comment: @Ruslan only if `noIntegrate` is written that way.  Let me think about this and attempt to add clarifying examples.

Comment: @Ruslan I updated the answer.  I hope it is more clear now.  Please let me know.

Comment: Great, this makes it clear, thanks.