# Treating expressions as symbols

Tags: syntax, core-language

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
test = {x, y};
With[{test[[1]] = 3}, x/y]
```

However, the following error is printed:

> With::lvset: "Local variable specification {test[[1]]=3} contains test[[1]]=3, which is an assignment to test[[1]]; only assignments to symbols are allowed"

I'm assuming this is because Mathematica treats the list elements as expressions and not as symbols correct? Setting `x` directly works, but I need the index for a loop functionality. Any hint on how to force *Mathematica* to interpret `test[[1]]` as a symbol?

Comment: You could use  a rule replacement  x /. x -> 3

Comment: `With[{# = 3}, x/y] &[test[[1]]]` if `x` has no value.

Comment: related: [83126](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83126/5478)

Comment: thanks, that did the trick! any insight on why my method does not work? trying to avoid these kinds of mistakes in the future..

Comment: `With` has attribute `HoldAll` hence `test[[1]]` isn't evaluated to `x` prior to trying to make the assignment.

Comment: @BobHanlon not only `With` is the problem. Set is `HoldFirst` too.

Comment: Ok, this is complex issue, I think you should read this [28610](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28610/5478) (probably duplicate) topic and linked/related ones.