# Table not working with Plot

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

Because `NIntegrate[]` does not support parallel computation out of the box, I'm doing a simplified version by breaking the integration limit into pieces and using `ParallelTable[]`. The following code is just a minimum working example in which I used `Sinc[]` as the integrated function.

```
iser[x_] := NIntegrate[Sinc[t + x], {t, 0, 100}];

ipar[x_] := Total[ParallelTable[
             With[{xx = x}, NIntegrate[Sinc[t + xx], {t, ii*25, ii*25 + 25}]
             ], {ii, 0, 3}]
            ];
```

where `iser[]` is the usual serialize version, and `ipar[]` is the parallel version. Then I do  `DistributeDefinitions[ipar]`. Passing a value to `iser[]` and `ipar[]` and **both give the correct answer**:

```
In[28]:= ipar[3]

Out[28]= -0.270322
```

But, when I try to run `Plot[ipar[x], {x, 0, 10}] // Timing` I get error messages that says

```
 NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Sinc[t+x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,25}}.

 NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Sinc[t+x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{50,75}}.

 NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Sinc[t+x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{75,100}}.

 NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Sinc[t+x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{25,50}}.

 NIntegrate::nlim: t = 25. ii is not a valid limit of integration.


 General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::nlim will be suppressed during this calculation.

 $Aborted
```

I know I can just generate a table of values and use `ListPlot[]` instead, but it's not easy to do adaptive sampling as `Plot[]` does. How can this be fixed?

Comment: `ipar[x_?NumberQ] := ...`

Comment: @wxffles Thanks. That solves it. Bit strange that `ipar[3]` returns the correct value without the query `?NumberQ`

Comment: Please read this for a full explanation: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820

Comment: @davidsedai please rename your post to Table not working with Plot as the problem has nothing to do with Parallel in practice. And change the tag?

Comment: @Searke Thanks for the link

Comment: @chris The title and tag have been changed. Thanks.

Comment: @Searke perhaps post your comment as an answer along with an executive summary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using a condition for the arguments of `ipar` and `iser` is needed.

A broader discussion of how and when to implement this solution is found [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/336/7167).