# Mathematica, nested optmization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to use the solution of `Maximize`, defined as a function, in another function. Here's an example:

```
f1[y_] := x /. Last[Maximize[{Sin[x y], Abs[x] <= y}, x]]  (* or any other function *)
```

This definition is fine, for example if I give `f1[4]`, I get the answer `-((3 \[Pi])/8)`.

The problem is that when I want to use it in another function I get an error. For example:

```
FindRoot[f1[y] == Pi/4, {y, 1}]
```

Gives me the following error:

> ReplaceAll::reps: {x} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a
>   valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
>
> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {-0.785398+(x/.x)} is not a list
>   of numbers with dimensions {1} at {y} = {1.}. >>

I've been struggling with this for several days now! Any comment, idea, help, ... is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Try evaluating `f[y]` alone and you'll see that the function `f`, a you defined it, simply isn't compatible with symbolic arguments.

Comment: Actually I'd say duplicate of this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/333/12  The answer I gave there explains the issue and the solution more clearly.

Comment: Also see here: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820