# nminimize or findminimum with findroot

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I have a problem with form similar to the following:

I have a set of equations that is `f(x, y) = 0`. For each `x`, I can use `FindRoot` to find a value of `y`. Suppose I want to select the `x` such that the implied value of `y` is minimises something like `(y- y*)^2`.

I feel like I want to combine `NMinimize` or `FindMinimum` with `FindRoot` but have difficulty achieving this.

Comment: Similar (combining numeric functions): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/333. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037.

Answer (score 3):

Without information about `y*` you could solve your problem in one step using NMinimize:

```
NMinimize[{(y-ystar)^2,f[x,y]==0},{x,y}]
```