# Find the equidistance curve between two curves

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, intersection, distance

I have three function $f(x)=x^x$, $g(x)=\ln(x)^{\ln(x)}$, $h(x)=\ln(x)^2$ and I want to find (numerically) $C$ the center of the circle tangent to the three curves.

[image]
I think that one way is to find two [equidistance curves](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/equidistance/equidistance.shtml). Let's say $E_1$ the equidistance curve between $f(x)$ and $h(x)$, and $E_2$ the equidistance curve between $g(x)$ and $h(x)$. Then the point of intersection between $E_1$ and $E_2$ would be $C$ at the same Euclidean distance from the three curves.
[image]

I'm new to Mathematica, what are the methods to do so? Does the equidistance curve need to be traced point by point? If so how can I find such points?

To start I tried the following in order to find just one point in $E_1$ but it doesn't work because the first argument in NMinimize is not a number...

```
f[x_] := x^x;
h[x_] := Log[x]^2;
NSolve[First@NMinimize[EuclideanDistance[{0.9,y}, {x,f[x]}], x] == First@NMinimize[EuclideanDistance[{0.9,y}, {x,h[x]}], x], y]
```

Comment: Regarding my attempt that doesn't work, to those who face a similar situation, [this is the proper way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/333/combined-numerical-minimization-and-maximization) to handle an optimization nested inside another one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
f[x_] := x^x
g[x_] := Log[x]^Log[x]
h[x_] := Log[x]^2

plot = Plot[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, {x, 0, E}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Extract the three lines from `plot` and use them to construct three `RegionDistance` functions:

```
{linef, lineg, lineh} = Cases[plot, _Line, All];

{rdf, rdg, rdh} = RegionDistance /@ {linef, lineg, lineh};
```

`ContourPlot` to get the lines where `rdf[{x, y}] == rdh[{x, y}]` and `rdg[{x, y}] == rdh[{x, y}]`:

```
cp = ContourPlot[{ConditionalExpression[rdf[{x, y}] - rdh[{x, y}], 
      y <= f[x]] == 0, rdg[{x, y}] - rdh[{x, y}] == 0}, 
 {x, 0.434, 2.5}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourStyle -> {Red, Green}];

Show[plot, cp]
```

[image]

Find the intersection of the two contour lines:

```
center = First @ Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections @ cp
```

> ```
> {0.912936, 0.468359}
> ```

The distances to the three curves are

```
Through[{rdf, rdg, rdh} @ center]
```

> ```
>  {0.374443, 0.374455, 0.374516}
> ```

Display the curves with the circle found, points of tangency and normals:

```
{ptf, ptg, pth} = RegionNearest[#, center] & /@ {linef, lineg, lineh};

Show[plot, Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], Thick, 
   Red, Circle[intersection, rdf@center],
   Dashed, ColorData[97]@1, 
   InfiniteLine[{ptf, ptf + Cross @ {1, f'[ptf[[1]]]}}],
   ColorData[97]@2, InfiniteLine[{ptg, ptg + Cross @ {1, g'[ptg[[1]]]}}],
   ColorData[97]@3, InfiniteLine[{pth, pth + Cross @ {1, h'[pth[[1]]]}}],
   Black, Point@intersection, Black, Point @ {ptf, ptg, pth}}],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

A slower alternative: extract the two contourlines and find their intersection using `RegionIntersection`:

```
edlines = Cases[Normal @ cp, _Line, All];

center = (RegionIntersection @@ edlines)[[1, 1]]
```

> ```
>  {0.912936, 0.468359}
> ```

**An aside:** To find the largest circle enclosed within the region (without the constraint that the circle touches all three curves) we can do

```
pw[x_] := Piecewise[{{f[x], x <= 1}}, g[x]];

plot = Plot[{f[x], g[x], h[x], pw[x], Min[pw[x], h[x]]}, {x, 0, E}, 
  Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
  Filling -> {4 -> {{3}, {None, Yellow}}}]
```

[image]

Extract the polygon from `plot`:

```
poly = First @ Cases[Normal[plot], _Polygon, All];
```

Use [`SignedRegionDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SignedRegionDistance.html) with `poly` to get an objective function to be used with [`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html):

```
srd[{x_, y_}]:= SignedRegionDistance[poly][{x, y}]
```

Find the coordinates within `poly` that maximizes the distance to the boundary of `poly`:

```
sol = NMinimize[{srd[{x, y}], {x, y} ∈ poly}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {-0.394924,{x->0.991457,y->0.395402}}
> ```

Process to get the radius and center of largest circle within `poly`:

```
{radius, center} = {Abs @ #, {x, y} /. #2} & @@ sol
```

> ```
>  {0.394924,{0.991457,0.395402}}
> ```

Display:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Yellow, poly, Red, Circle[center, radius]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, there are so many new things for me to learn from your answer! Also, how would you increase the precision of the solution?

Answer (score 18):

Here we manual create the normal line of the three differentiable curves.

```
f[x_] := x^x;
g[x_] := Log[x]^Log[x]
h[x_] := Log[x]^2
eq1 = {x1, f[x1]} + t*Normalize[{-f'[x1], 1}];
eq2 = {x2, g[x2]} + t*Normalize[{-g'[x2], 1}];
eq3 = {x3, h[x3]} - t*Normalize[{-h'[x3], 1}];
sol = NMinimize[{0, (eq1 - eq2)^2 + (eq2 - eq3)^2 + (eq3 - eq1)^2 == 
    0}, {x1, x2, x3, t}]
disk = Disk[eq1, Abs[t]] /. Last[sol];
plot = Plot[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 3}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All];
Show[plot, Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[Cyan], disk}]]
```

> `{0., {x1 -> 0.733078, x2 -> 1.13371, x3 -> 0.583456, t -> -0.374512}}`

[image]

Comment: Very clean and straightforward method! This is how I thought of doing it in the first place, but didn't know the full power of NMinimize to "converge" the three normal lines

Comment: Can you explain why NMinimize has to be "tricked" that way, can't we create a proper function to be minimized?

Comment: @DomenicoModica Yes,I am trying to do this for general three parametric curves. Maybe need more times to do this. The difficult come from how to determine the inside or outside of region. Here we use `+t`,`+t` and `-t` indicate the inside or outside of the normal vector.

Comment: Oh, I'm interested in a general approach! By the way I've noted that if `EuclideanDistance[eq1,eq2]+(*...*)==0` is used instead of `(eq1-eq2)^2+(*...*) == 0` the solutions are very much different. The one obtained with EuclideanDistance has increasingly secure decimal digits with higher precision whereas the other can't secure not even the seventh decimal digit with WorkingPrecision 100

Comment: @DomenicoModica The definition of `EuclideanDistance` or `Norm` or  `Normalize` is use the Complex Function `Abs` instead of `RealAbs`,so  I always trying to avoid use them.

Comment: Regarding the general problem, this is a particular case in which the three FUNCTIONS intersect each other. In this scenario I've realized that determining which normal vector has to be of the opposite sign it's the analogous problem of determining which integral should be of the opposite sign to find the area enclosed by the 3 curves. The three intersection points can be ordered with respect to x. The curve that does not individuate the "middle one" is the discordant curve.

Comment: But more in general (parametric function, not knowing how many intersections there are) I think it's very difficult to tackle the problem without looking at the equidistance curves.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a slightly more general attempt to solve the problem with `NMinimize` without "tricks".
It is based on the  idea used in @cvgmt interesting answer.

Because the "sign" of the normal directions isn't known one has to introduce three parameters `t1,t2,t3` instead of `t`, all having the same absolut value:

```
f[x_] := x^x;
g[x_] := Log[x]^Log[x]
h[x_] := Log[x]^2
eq1 = {x1, f[x1]} + t1*Normalize[{-f'[x1], 1}];
eq2 = {x2, g[x2]} + t2*Normalize[{-g'[x2], 1}];
eq3 = {x3, h[x3]} + t3*Normalize[{-h'[x3], 1}];

sol = NMinimize[{  ((t1^2 - t2^2)^2 + (t2^2 - t3^2)^2 + (t3^2 -t1^2)^2),
eq1 == eq2 , eq3 == eq2 ,  eq1 == eq3 }, {x1, x2,x3, t1 , t2 , t3 } 
, Method ->"DifferentialEvolution" ]  
(*{1.63224*10^-13, {x1 -> 0.732916, x2 -> 1.13392, x3 -> 0.58397, 
t1 -> -0.374526, t2 -> -0.374526, t3 -> 0.374526}}*)
```

The result agrees with @cvgmt`s, perhaps the approach is a little bit more straighforward!

Comment: Nice! But it seems that increasing working precision with DifferentialEvolution, messes up the result...

Comment: @ DomenicoModica Yes, 'til now I didn't understand, why NMinimize- "Automatic"-modus doesn't work.  Perhaps there exists a more robust formulation of the minimization problem?

Answer (score 4):

For general parametric curves, `NMinimize` sometimes work. Here we give an example.

We change the sign of `{t1,t2,t3}`, for example `t1 < 0, t2 < 0, t3 > 0`.

But there still a result is not correct,that is `t1 < 0, t2 < 0, t3 < 0` can not work,in this case, the result should be a large circle which just contain all the three circles.(The minimal circle contain all the circles).

And I have test some `Method` such as

```
Method ->Automatic;
Method -> "RandomSearch";
Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"
Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing";
Method -> "NelderMead"
```

```
f[s_] = {2 + Cos[s], 2 + Sin[s]};
g[s_] = {3 + Cos[s], 2 + Sin[s]};
h[s_] = {2 + Cos[s], 1 + Sin[s]};
eq1 = f[s1] + t1*Cross@Normalize[f'[s1], Sqrt[#.#] &];
eq2 = g[s2] + t2*Cross@Normalize[g'[s2], Sqrt[#.#] &];
eq3 = h[s3] + t3*Cross@Normalize[h'[s3], Sqrt[#.#] &];
sol = NMinimize[{0, Total[(eq1 - eq2)^2] == 0, 
    Total[(eq2 - eq3)^2] == 0, Total[(eq3 - eq1)^2] == 0, 
    t1^2 == t2^2 == t3^2, 0 <= s1 <= 2 π, 0 <= s2 <= 2 π, 
    0 <= s3 <= 
     2 π, {Sign[t1], Sign[t2], Sign[t3]} == {-1, -1, 1}}, {s1, s2,
     s3, t1, t2, t3}, Method -> Automatic];
disk = Disk[eq1, Abs[t1]] /. Last[sol];
plot = ParametricPlot[{f[s], g[s], h[s]}, {s, 0, 2 π}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 4}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
Show[plot, 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[Cyan], Opacity[0.2], disk}]]
```

[image]

```
With[{sign = #}, f[s_] = {2 + Cos[s], 2 + Sin[s]};
   g[s_] = {3 + Cos[s], 2 + Sin[s]};
   h[s_] = {2 + Cos[s], 1 + Sin[s]};
   eq1 = f[s1] + t1*Cross@Normalize[f'[s1], Sqrt[#.#] &];
   eq2 = g[s2] + t2*Cross@Normalize[g'[s2], Sqrt[#.#] &];
   eq3 = h[s3] + t3*Cross@Normalize[h'[s3], Sqrt[#.#] &];
   sol = NMinimize[{0, Total[(eq1 - eq2)^2] == 0, 
      Total[(eq2 - eq3)^2] == 0, Total[(eq3 - eq1)^2] == 0, 
      t1^2 == t2^2 == t3^2, 0 <= s1 <= 2 π, 0 <= s2 <= 2 π, 
      0 <= s3 <= 2 π, {Sign[t1], Sign[t2], Sign[t3]} == 
       sign}, {s1, s2, s3, t1, t2, t3}, Method -> Automatic];
   disk = Disk[eq1, Abs[t1]] /. Last[sol];
   plot = 
    ParametricPlot[{f[s], g[s], h[s]}, {s, 0, 2 π}, 
     PlotRange -> {0, 4}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
   Show[plot, 
    Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[Cyan], Opacity[0.2], 
      disk}]]] & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3]
```

[image]

Another example.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice! I went fancy and I'm working on a program that creates fractals finding the circle in every new area that gets create, see [Apollonian gasket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket). Maybe next we can accorpate the two together!

Comment: For the case that can't work, it would be a second case of `t1 > 0, t2 > 0, t3 > 0`, because the engulfing circumference radius would traverse the three and not be outside.

Comment: @DomenicoModica  Thanks for your advice. I  will keep on study this question.