# Optimization: list manipulation

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, replacement

I have a list of 3 pairs of integers, for each pair `i` I want to replace the one having the smallest absolute value with `xi` and the other one with its sign. Like this:

```
In: {{-5, 1}, {7, -3}, {4, 4}}
Out: {{-1, x2}, {1, x3}, {x4, 1}} (*for the last one {1, x4} would be fine as well*)
```

My attempt is this, I fear it's a bit too convoluted:

```
list = {{-5,1},{7,-3},{4,4}}
list = MapThread[#1 /. #2 -> #3 &, {list, If[Total[#] > 0, Min[#], Max[#]] & /@ list, {x1, x2, x3}}];
list = Map[If[NumericQ[#], Sign[#], #] &, list, {2}];
```

I'm using this in a fractal related problem, so what's the most optimized way?

Comment: Man, this just SCREAMS [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/) :-) *Why* do you need to do this and what would you like to accomplish with it ultimately?

Comment: :D @MarcoB Yes, you're right, [take a glimpse at this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235971/find-the-equidistance-curve-between-two-curves/236125?noredirect=1#comment596463_236125) I'm now trying to take that idea further and find the tangent circumference in every area that shows up, a fractal. NMinimize is the core function that actually finds centers and radii. Basically the 3 pairs of integers in this question are slope vector, they are parameterized with `x1, x2, x3` normalized and feeded to NMinimize. They tell in which half plane to look for the next circle

Comment: I've just learned that the circle tangent to 3 mutually tangent circles (being a solved problem) [can be calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147028/how-do-i-calculate-the-inner-soddy-centre-point-in-cartesian-coordinate-form)... So technically I won't use this procedure in that case. But I'll need anyway for the area between 2 circle and one curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = MapIndexed[If[LessEqual @@ Abs @ #,
  {Symbol["x" <> ToString[#2[[1]]]],  Sign @ Last @ #}, 
  {Sign @ First @ #,  Symbol["x" <> ToString[#2[[1]]]]}] &];

list = {{-5, 1}, {7, -3}, {4, 4}}; 

f @ list
```

> ```
> {{-1, x1}, {1, x2}, {x3, 1}}
> ```

Also

```
symbolpositions = MapIndexed[Flatten[{#2, #}] &][2 - Boole[LessEqual @@@ Abs[list]]];

symbols = Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[Length@list];

ReplacePart[Sign@list, Thread[symbolpositions -> symbols]]
```

> ```
>  {{-1, x1}, {1, x2}, {x3, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

[`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) should be the suitable function working at the overall level. A version slightly different from that of @kglr 's, with [`OrderingBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderingBy.html), [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html), and [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html)

```
symbol = ToExpression[StringTemplate["x``"] @@ #] &;
func = If[Greater @@ OrderingBy[#, Abs],
    {Sign[#[[1]]], symbol[#2]}, 
    {symbol[#2], Sign[#[[2]]]}
] &;
list = {{-5, 1}, {7, -3}, {4, 4}};
MapIndexed[func][list]
```

> ```
> {{-1, x1}, {1, x2}, {x3, 1}}
> ```