# How to find optimizers with computer in this kind of minimax problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization, programming, game

I have a minimax problem of the form $$\max_{\substack{u_1,\dots,u_n \ge 0 \\ u_1+\dots+u_n = 1}} \min_{\substack{v_1,\dots,v_m \ge 0 \\ v_1+\dots+v_m = 1 \\ v_{j_1} \le v_{j_2} \hspace{1mm} \forall (j_1,j_2) \in J}} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m c_{i,j} u_i v_j,$$ where $J$ is some (given) subset of $[m]\times[m]$ and each $c_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$ (is given).

So it's a normal kind of minimax problem, except we have some inequalities amongst the $v_j$'s.

By the minimax theorem, there are $u^* = (u_i^*)_{i=1}^n, v^* = (v_j^*)_{j=1}^m$ that are ``best responses" to one another.

Let's assume our problem is such that there is only one such $u^*$.

**Question**: How can I quickly (in practice, on a computer) find $u^*$?

The values of $n$ and $m$ I am working with are actually very small (e.g. $n \le 7, m \le 14$). However, Mathematica seemingly takes forever to compute the minimax, even with $n=2,m=4$.

Using Mathematica, I can find (some) $v^*$ rather quickly by interchanging the max and the min, and then noting that the max of the double sum over the possible $(u_i)_{i=1}^n$'s is simply a max of the double sum over the $n$ tuples $(u_i)_{i=1}^n$ with exactly one $1$ (and the rest $0$). However, this doesn't help me find $u^*$.

I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: Here's the code for the example that seemingly takes forever. Apologies if it is very stupid.

Maximize[{Minimize[{u0*(v1 + v3) + u1*(v2 + v3), v0 >= 0, v1 >= 0, 
     v2 >= 0, v3 >= 0, v0 <= v1, v0 <= v2, v1 <= v3, v2 <= v3, 
     v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 == 1}, {v0, v1, v2, v3}][[1]], u0 >= 0, 
  u1 >= 0, u0 + u1 == 1}, {u0, u1}]

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152922/755, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/270651/40712.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  Which site do you think is most appropriate for this question?

Comment: Check [this MSE thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/333/combined-numerical-minimization-and-maximization) or any of several others that can be found by searching for "bilevel optimization".

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks a lot! Adding a separate function with the "?NumericQ" helped! The only issue now is that, with that separate function successfully defined with Minimize (not NMinize), I can only do NMaximize of that function instead of Maximize. Is there any way to do Maximize? I want to find the optimal maximizer, not just a numeric approximation. Thanks.

Comment: Kindly include the code you have in your question, instead of leaving it in the comments.

Comment: I believe it will not be possible to do this directly and fast using exact methods.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you.

Comment: If $J$ was the empty set, then it appears this is equivalent to computing Nash equilibria, which has an efficient algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium#Computing_Nash_equilibria.  Can that be adapted to your situation?