# Implementing a function which generalizes the merging step in merge sort

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, programming

One of the key steps in [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is the merging step.  Given two sorted lists

```
sorted1={2,6,10,13,16,17,19};
sorted2={1,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,14,15,18,20};
```

of integers, we want to produce a new list as follows:

1. Start with an empty list `acc`.
2. Compare the first elements of `sorted1` and `sorted2`.  Append the smaller one to `acc`.
3. Remove the element used in step 2 from either `sorted1` or `sorted2`.
4. If neither `sorted1` nor `sorted2` is empty, go to step 2.  Otherwise append the remaining list to `acc` and output the value of `acc`.

Applying this process to `sorted1` and `sorted2`, we get

```
acc={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}
```

*Added in response to Rojo's question: We can carry out this procedure even if the two lists are not pre-sorted.  So `list1` and `list2` below are not assumed to be sorted.*

If there were a built-in function `MergeList` which carries out this process, it would probably take three arguments `list1`, `list2`, and `f`.  Here `f` is a Boolean function of two arguments used to decide which element to pick.  In the case of merge sort, `f = LessEqual`.  I feel that `MergeList` is a fundamental list operation, so

**Question 1:  Is there such a built-in function or one very close to that?**

If I were to write such a function in Scheme, I would use a recursive definition equivalent to the following:

```
MergeList[list1_,{},f_,acc_:{}]:=Join[acc,list1];
MergeList[{},list2_,f_,acc_:{}]:=Join[acc,list2];
MergeList[list1_,list2_,f_,acc_:{}]:=
 If[
  f@@First/@{list1,list2},
  MergeList[Rest[list1],list2,f,Append[acc,First[list1]]],
  MergeList[list1,Rest[list2],f,Append[acc,First[list2]]]
 ]
```

*Sample output with unsorted lists:*

```
In[2]:= MergeList[{2,5,1},{3,6,4},LessEqual]
Out[2]= {2,3,5,1,6,4}
```

My impression is that recursive solutions tend to be inefficient in Mathematica, so

**Question 2:  What would be a better way to implement `MergeList`?**

If you have tips about converting loops into their functional equivalents, feel free to mention them as well.

Comment: So you want a function that returns the same result as `Sort[Join[#1, #2], #3]&`?

Comment: @Rojo For `MergeList`, the two lists need not be sorted.  For example, `MergeList[{2, 5, 1}, {3, 4}, LessEqual]` evaluates to `{2, 3, 4, 5, 1}`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I'll write something up.

Comment: @Rojo Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity.  I edited the question.

Comment: If you care for efficiency a bit as you seem to, and you will use it for numeric quantities, this is one of those cases where it's probably very worth it to go with `Compile` and a procedural solution

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Preamble

Since I agree that it would be nice to have a generic function of this type, I will provide a general implementation. First, I will give a generic one based on linked lists, then I will add a JIT-compiled one for special numeric types, and lastly, I will bring it all together.

### Top-level implementation based on linked lists

Here is a reasonably efficient implementation based on linked lists:

```
ClearAll[toLinkedList, ll];
SetAttributes[ll, HoldAllComplete];
toLinkedList[s_List] := Fold[ll[#2, #1] &, ll[], Reverse[s]];
```

and the main function:

```
ClearAll[merge];
merge[a_ll, ll[], s_, _] := List @@ Flatten[ll[s, a], Infinity, ll];
merge[ll[], b_ll, s_, _] := List @@ Flatten[ll[s, b], Infinity, ll];
merge[ll[a1_, atail_], b : ll[b1_, _], s_, f_: LessEqual] /;f[a1, b1] :=
    merge[atail, b, ll[s, a1], f];
merge[a : ll[a1_, _], ll[b1_, brest_], s_, f_: LessEqual] :=
    merge[a, brest, ll[s, b1], f];
merge[a_List, b_List, f_: LessEqual] :=
    merge[toLinkedList@a, toLinkedList@b, ll[], f];
```

For example:

```
merge[{2,5,1},{3,6,4},LessEqual]
```

> ```
>  {2,3,5,1,6,4}
> ```

```
merge[{2,5,1},{3,6,4},Greater]
```

> ```
>  {3,6,4,2,5,1}
> ```

And also for large lists:

```
large1 = RandomInteger[100, 10000];
large2 = RandomInteger[100, 10000];

Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity},
   merge[large1,large2,LessEqual]]//Short//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0751953,{70,54,78,84,11,21,41,49,78,93,90,70,19,
>       <<19975>>,42,2,10,40,53,12,2,47,89,40,2,80}}
> ```

For a complete implementation of merge sort algorithm based on linked lists, see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-can-i-ensure-that-i-am-constructing-patterns-in-the-most-efficient-way-possi/295#295) (the difference there is that I used repeated rule application instead of recursion. Originally, the goal of that example was to show that `ReplaceRepeated` is not necessarily slow if the patterns are constructed efficiently).

### Full implementation including JIT-compilation

I'd like to show here how one could implement a fairly complete function which would automatically dispatch to an efficient JIT-compiled code when the arguments are appropriate. Compilation will work not just for numeric lists, but for lists of tensors in general, as long as they are of the same shape.

#### JIT - compilation

First comes the JIT-compiled version, done along the lines discussed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/metaprogramming-in-mathematica/2352#2352), section "Making JIT-compiled functions"

```
ClearAll[mergeJIT];
mergeJIT[pred_, listType_, target : ("MVM" | "C") : "MVM"] :=
  mergeJIT[pred, Verbatim[listType], target] =
    Block[{fst, sec},
      With[{decl = {Prepend[listType, fst], Prepend[listType, sec]}},
       Compile @@
         Hold[decl,
           Module[{result = Table[0, {Length[fst] + Length[sec]}], i = 0, 
                fctr = 1, sctr = 1},
             While[fctr <= Length[fst] && sctr <= Length[sec],
               If[pred[fst[[fctr]], sec[[sctr]]],
                   result[[++i]] = fst[[fctr++]],
                   (* else *)
                   result[[++i]] = sec[[sctr++]]
               ]
             ];
             If[fctr > Length[fst],
               result[[i + 1 ;; -1]] = sec[[sctr ;; -1]],
               (* else *)
               result[[i + 1 ;; -1]] = fst[[fctr ;; -1]]
             ];
             result
           ],
           CompilationTarget -> target
         ]]];
```

You can use this in isolation:

```
mergeJIT[LessEqual,{_Integer,1},"MVM"][{2,5,1},{3,6,4}]
```

> ```
>  {2,3,5,1,6,4}
> ```

but it is much better to use as a part of the generic function, which would figure out the types for you automatically.

#### Generic function implementation

This is a function to find the type of our lists:

```
Clear[getType, $useCompile];
getType[arg_List] /; $useCompile && ArrayQ[arg, _, IntegerQ] := 
    {_Integer, Length@Dimensions@arg};
getType[arg_List] /; $useCompile && ArrayQ[arg, _, NumericQ] && 
     Re[arg] == arg := 
        {_Real, Length@Dimensions@arg};
getType[_] := General;
```

This is a function to dispatch to a right type:

```
Clear[mergeDispatch];
SetAttributes[mergeDispatch, Orderless];
mergeDispatch[{Verbatim[_Integer], n_}, {Verbatim[_Real], n_}, pred_] :=
    mergeDispatch[{Verbatim[_Real], n}, {Verbatim[_Real], n}, pred];

mergeDispatch[f : {Verbatim[_Real], n_}, {Verbatim[_Real], n_}, pred_] :=
    mergeJIT[pred, f, $target];

mergeDispatch[f : {Verbatim[_Integer], n_}, {Verbatim[_Integer], n_}, pred_] :=
    mergeJIT[pred, f, $target];

mergeDispatch[_, _, pred_] :=
    Function[{fst, sec},
      Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity},
         merge[fst, sec, pred]]];
```

and this is a function to bring it all together:

```
ClearAll[mergeList];
Options[mergeList] = 
 {
    CompileToC -> False,
    Compiled -> True
 };
mergeList[f_, s_, pred_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{
       $target = If[TrueQ[OptionValue[CompileToC]], "C", "MVM"],
       $useCompile = TrueQ[OptionValue[Compiled]]
    },
    mergeDispatch[getType@f, getType@s, pred][f, s]
  ];
```

Finally, a helper function to clear the cache of `mergeJIT`, if that would be desired:

```
ClearAll[clearMergeJITCache];
clearMergeJITCache[] :=
   DownValues[mergeJIT] = {Last@DownValues[mergeJIT]};
```

#### Benchmarks and tests

First, create test data:

```
clearMergeJITCache[];
huge1 = RandomInteger[1000,1000000];
huge2 = RandomInteger[1000,1000000];
```

A first call to the function with C compilation target is expensive:

```
mergeList[huge1,huge2,Less,CompileToC -> True]//Short//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {3.8652344,{267,461,66,607,797,116,197,474,852,805,135,
>      <<1999978>>,266,667,799,280,261,930,241,83,594,904,894}}
> ```

But then, for the same types of lists, it will pay off for huge lists:

```
mergeList[huge1,huge2,Less,CompileToC -> True]//Short//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.0468750,{267,461,66,607,797,116,197,474,852,805,135,
>        <<1999978>>,266,667,799,280,261,930,241,83,594,904,894}}
> ```

On the other hand, the call with MVM target is fast out of the box, but not as fast as the one with the C target after the "warm-up":

```
mergeList[huge1,huge2,Less]//Short//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.2138672,{267,461,66,607,797,116,197,474,852,805,135,
>        <<1999978>>,266,667,799,280,261,930,241,83,594,904,894}}
> ```

The call to generic one is general but comparatively very slow:

```
mergeList[huge1,huge2,Less,Compiled->False]//Short//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {5.015,{267,461,66,607,797,116,197,474,852,805,135,
>        <<1999978>>,266,667,799,280,261,930,241,83,594,904,894}}
> ```

Comment: The difference in performance is astounding: 0.12s vs 1.23s for lists of lengths 10000 and 1.13s vs **146.60s** for lists of length 100000.  I find it reassuring that even without making significant changes to the straightforward recursion, I can get major performance boost by switching to linked lists.  Perhaps reading *The Little Schemer* did not cause too much harm.

Comment: @MichaelWijaya Check out my new addition :). And yes, linked lists are great and under-appreciated in Mathematica data srtucture. I intend to make a blog post on this topic once we have a blog.

Comment: You evaluated `mergeList[huge1,huge2,Less,CompileToC -> True]//Short//AbsoluteTiming` twice at the beginning of the Benchmarks section, but the timing results are significantly different.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think I know what is going on now.  There is some caching going on in the previous section, thus the comment on `clearMergeJITCache`.

Comment: I was showing that, when you use the JIT-version with the compilation to C, the first call for arguments of a given type takes a while since we have to inslude the time to compile to C. All subsequent calls are instant, because the compiled function is cached.

Answer (score 16):

Here's another approach.

```
mergeLists[lista_, listb_, crit_: LessEqual] :=
 Module[{merge},
  merge[list1_, list2_] /; crit[First[list1], First[list2]] :=

   With[{part = TakeWhile[list1, crit[#, First[list2]] &]},
    Sow[part];
    If[Length[part] == Length[list1],
     Sow[list2],
     merge[list1[[Length[part] + 1 ;;]], list2]]];

  merge[list2_, list1_] /; crit[First[list1], First[list2]] := 
   merge[list1, list2];

  merge[list1_, list2_] := With[
    {part = TakeWhile[list1, Not[crit[First[list2], #]] &]},
    Sow[part];
    If[Length[part] == Length[list1],
     Sow[list2],
     merge[list1[[Length[part] + 1 ;;]], list2]]];

  Flatten[Reap[merge[lista, listb];][[2]]]]
```

It does give slightly different results from Leonid's code though. For example for

```
list1 = {1, 4, 3};
list2 = {2, 3, 4};
```

I get with my code

```
mergeLists[{1, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, LessEqual]

(* out: {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3} *)
```

whereas with Leonid's code I get

```
Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity}, merge[{1, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, LessEqual]]

(* out: {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4} *)
```

If I take `Less` instead of `LessEqual` I get the same result for  both codes, so I expect that it has to do with a different treatment of border cases where the two sublists start with the same element.

Taking this issue aside, my code does seem to be faster than Leonid's solution. Consider for example (I'm choosing `large1` and `large2` such that their intersection is empty to avoid the issue above)

```
{large1, large2} = Partition[RandomSample[Range[20000]], 10000];
```

then with Leonid's code I get

```
Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity}, merge[large1, large2, LessEqual]] // Short // 
  AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.070483,{9941,7246,4261,11184,10148,1867,12324,
    <<19986>>,6927,17973,10762,9165,19379,11449,7735}} *)
```

and with my code

```
mergeLists[large1, large2, LessEqual] // Short // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.039470,{9941,7246,4261,11184,10148,1867,12324,
    <<19986>>,6927,17973,10762,9165,19379,11449,7735}} *)
```

Comment: Actually, your code is remarkably fast, I can only beat it when I enable the compilation to C, and it is more compact, since what I do explicitly with type-identification and `Dispatch`, is done implicitly by `LengthWhile` here. I was initially suspecting that your version might be slower because typically rule-based varsions not using linked lists are slow due to excessive copying of elements. But in your case, for some reason which I don't yet understand this only becomes noticable for truly huge lists, and is not dominating the running time in any case. Will have to think more about it.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Statistically, the purely random data is such that very soon you get the number close to a maximal, so your function does not perform many recursive steps. This will be a killer though: `ls1 = Flatten[RandomSample /@ Partition[Range[100000], 5]];
ls2 = Flatten[RandomSample /@ Partition[Range[100000], 5]];Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, 
   mergeLists[ls1, ls2, Less]]; // AbsoluteTiming` (Note that you have to lift the `$RecursionLimit` in general - which was another thing I initially did not understand - how could you avoid that with your function not being tail-recursive).

Comment: Heike, I did not have a motivation to kill your code, really. I just could not understand why it worked so fast on the rather large data I tried. Also, **make sure you don't have anything worth saving in the session when trying my test code from the previous comment** - it eats up my 8Gb of RAM very quickly and then quits the kernel.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I didn't take it that way. I was a bit surprised by the speed myself so I suspected that there was catch somewhere anyway.

Comment: You can easily cure your solution by passing just the starting positions from where to read the lists, and using `Do` loops instead of `LengthWhile` to read elements - so that you will never copy lists but always read from the same `lista` and `listb`. One other thing though would be to make the function tail-recursive, but I think this is also doable, given that it anyway works by side-effects.

Answer (score 11):

Forget Leonid and Heike's recursive stuff (okay, actually I upvoted both as they are both good responses). But here is a simple, direct version. Note that it will not sort, so if the inputs are unsorted the result will be as well.

```
mergeSortedLists[lista_, listb_, crit_: LessEqual] := Module[
  {result, len1 = Length[lista], len2 = Length[listb], i = 1, 
   j = 1},
  result = Reap[While[i <= len1 && j <= len2,
      If[TrueQ[crit[lista[[i]], listb[[j]]]],
        Sow[lista[[i]]]; i++,
        Sow[listb[[j]]]; j++];
      ]][[2, 1]];
  If[i <= len1, result = Join[result, lista[[i ;; -1]]], 
   If[j <= len2, result = Join[result, listb[[j ;; -1]]]]];
  result]
```

Here is Heike's example modified slightly:

```
{large1, large2} = 
  Partition[Sort[RandomSample[Range[100000]]], 50000];
In[2236]:= Timing[ml = mergeSortedLists[large1, large2, LessEqual];]
ml === Range[100000]

Out[2236]= {0.21, Null}

Out[2237]= True
```

Comment: +1, a fine solution. I retained recursion because this was closer to the original one in the question, and bacause I find it elegant. But note that on tests `ls1 = Flatten[RandomSample /@ Partition[Range[100000], 5]];
ls2 = Flatten[RandomSample /@ Partition[Range[100000], 5]];`, my compiled version is about 20 times faster on my machine (`mergeList[ls1, ls2, LessEqual]`), the one with C target is about 50 times faster (after warm-up), `mergeList[ls1, ls2, LessEqual, CompileToC -> True]`, and even recursive one is about 20 percent faster: `mergeList[ls1, ls2, LessEqual, Compiled -> False]`.

Comment: But if I would go for `Reap` and `Sow`, then (for what it's worth) I'd do that just like you did here, rather than use recursion like Heike did, bacause recursion is IMO ill-suited for non-linked lists, since it leads to excessive copying of lists as a part of parameter-passing, and requires extra effort to make a function tail-recursive (both issues can be well seen in Heike-s answer - which actually serves as a good example to illustrate those - as per my comments there).

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin Mine is definitely not "top in class" in terms of speed. One could probably do better by filling in a Table. Also using Compile, if/when appropriate, would make it faster. Whether it would then become competitive I do not know.

Comment: I actually was expecting an even much larger overhead of explicit list indexing in the top-level code, than what your code exhibits. Your code is definitely  better suited for compilation than the recursive one, which can not be compiled at all (at least my version), because it uses linked lists.

Answer (score 6):

Not to different to Heike's I think, because I haven't followed it line by line. Please let me know if it's too similar to be a separate answer

```
merge[l1_, l2_, f_] := Block[{mergeAux},
  mergeAux[list1_, list2_] := 
   mergeAux[list2, 
    Function[fr, 
      Drop[list1, Length@Sow[TakeWhile[list1, f[#, fr] &]]]][
     First@list2]];
  mergeAux[{}, l_] := Sow[l];
  mergeAux[l_, {}] := Sow[l];
  Flatten[Reap[mergeAux[l1, l2]][[2, 1]], 1]
]
```

**EDIT**
Same idea but with a custom `takeWhile` that allows for setting from what position to start counting. Given that,

```
lengthWhile[l_, cond_, from_] := 
 If[# === Null, Length[l] - from + 1, #] &[
  Do[If[! cond@l[[c]], Return[c - from, Do]], {c, from, Length[l]}]]
takeWhile[l_, cond_, from_] := 
 l[[from ;; from - 1 + lengthWhile[l, cond, from]]]

ClearAll[merge];
merge[l1_, l2_, f_] := Block[{mergeAux},
  mergeAux[list1_, list2_, in1_, in2_] := 
   mergeAux[list2, list1, in2, in1 +
     Function[fr,
       Length@Sow@takeWhile[list1, f[#, fr] &, in1]][list2[[in2]]]];
  mergeAux[_, l_, Length[l1] + 1, i_] := Sow[l[[i ;;]] ];
  mergeAux[l_, _, i_, Length[l2] + 1] := Sow[l[[i ;;]]];
  Flatten[Reap[mergeAux[l1, l2, 1, 1]][[2, 1]], 1]]
```

Comment: It is certainly different from Heike-s answer, because it is tail-recursive, so that one has only to lift `$IterationLimit` rather than `$RecursionLimit`. Your solution still suffers from quadratic complexity when you have a large number of flips, but at least it finishes in finite time: `ls1 = Flatten[RandomSample /@ Partition[Range[100000], 5]];
ls2 = Flatten[RandomSample /@ Partition[Range[100000], 5]];Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity}, 
   mergeRojo[ls1, ls2, LessEqual]]; // AbsoluteTiming` (takes about 9 secs on my machine), while her code leads to a disaster in such cases.

Comment: In fact, in her case, this is so for a subtle reason: because her function is not tail-recursive, the allocated memory for partial lists she constructs can not be claimed by the garbage-collector, because it is referenced from the function calls (expressions) on expression (call) stack. This leads to a memory exhaustion faster than to a stack blowing, so kernel quits for the lack of memory rather than crashes (don't know which is worse). Anyways, your code is better in this respect, but still sub-optimal performance for this type of data, so, sorry, no upvote this time. But, please do keep it!

Comment: I am still developing my feel for efficient programs, so it helps to look at other implementations even if they are not the fastest possible.  Leonid's commentary also adds value to your answer.  +1

Comment: @MichaelWijaya then let's keep this going :). I just edited

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, feel free to check out the edit and comment on it. It's still not the fastest possible, but have I avoided the quadratic complexity?

Comment: @Rojo Yes, you did, because you no longer pass partial lists. In fact, you implemented exactly my suggestion in my last comment below Heike's answer. +1 this time.

Comment: @Rojo Note also that you don't have to pass lists - since your `mergeAux` is an inner function, it can simply refer to the original arguments `l1`, `l2`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, actually, it would take a little code modification because I swap the lists around in each call