# A fast, robust DropWhile

Tags: programming, performance-tuning

For reasons that have never been entirely clear to me, *Mathematica* has had a built-in [`TakeWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TakeWhile.html) function since version 6.0, but has no equivalent `DropWhile` function. This means that I find myself periodically writing my own. Since this is a function that I use fairly frequently, I'd like to have a version that is both fast and robust. It's also the kind of function that you can write in a bunch of ways; I've tested variants that depend on `While` loops, on using `Scan` and `Throw`, and on using `Position`.

Of these, a version using `Position` is the fastest I've found:

```
DropWhile[list_, test_] := 
 With[{pos = 
   Position[list, elt_ /; ! TrueQ@test[elt], {1}, 1, Heads -> False]},
  pos /. {
    {} -> {},
    {{fail_}} :> Drop[list, fail - 1]
   }];
```

The `TrueQ` slows things down a bit, but is there to match the observed behavior of `TakeWhile`, which takes elements only as long as the test function returns `True`. Are there good ways to make this function work faster?

Comment: Did you try `DropWhile[{2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3}, EvenQ]`? I'm getting `{1,2,3}` as the answer...

Comment: @RodLm Yes, that's the correct behavior. The function should drop elements until it finds one that doesn't satisfy the test.

Comment: Oh, I see... Interesting question! +1

Comment: Related: [Where is DropWhile in Mathematica?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5577959/618728)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Simple solution

Why not just

```
dropWhile[list_, test_] := Drop[list, LengthWhile[list, test]]
```

?

### Fast JIT-based solution with automatic type identification / dispatch

Here I will show a solution that is potentially much faster on packed arrays. The code is directly modeled after [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6931/implementing-a-function-which-generalizes-the-merging-step-in-merge-sort/6933#6933), so I refer to some additional details there.

#### JIT version with type memoization

Here is the first ingredient: the specialized JIT version

```
ClearAll[dropWhileJIT];
dropWhileJIT[pred_,listType_,target:"MVM"|"C":"MVM"]:=
   dropWhileJIT[pred,Verbatim[listType],target]=
      Block[{l},
         With[{decl={Prepend[listType,l]}},
            Compile@@
               Hold[                      
                  decl,
                  Module[{pos=1},
                     While[pred[l[[pos]]],pos++];Drop[l,pos-1]
                  ],
                  CompilationTarget->target
               ]
         ]
      ]
```

which can be tested as

```
dropWhileJIT[# < 99999 &, {_Integer, 1}, "C"][Range[100000]] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {5.481445, {99999, 100000}} *)
```

The second and subsequent times this will be blazingly fast:

```
dropWhileJIT[# < 99999 &, {_Integer, 1}, "C"][Range[100000]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.000977, {99999, 100000}} *)
```

Here, we also should have a function to clear the cache:

```
ClearAll[clearDropWhileCache];
clearDropWhileCache[]:=
   DownValues[dropWhileJIT]={Last[DownValues[dropWhileJIT]]};
```

which can be used to remove the memoized definitions.

#### Automatic type identification and dispatch

Here we will use the following functions:

```
Clear[getType,$useCompile];
getType[arg_List]/;$useCompile&&ArrayQ[arg,_,IntegerQ]:=
   {_Integer,Length[Dimensions[arg]]};
getType[arg_List]/;$useCompile&&ArrayQ[arg,_,NumericQ]&&Re[arg]==arg:=
   {_Real,Length[Dimensions[arg]]};
getType[_]:=
   General;
```

and

```
Clear[dropWhileDispatch];
dropWhileDispatch[
   t:{Verbatim[_Integer]|Verbatim[_Real]|Verbatim[_Complex],n_},pred_
]:=
   dropWhileJIT[pred,t,$target];

dropWhileDispatch[_,pred_]:=
   dropWhileGeneric[#1,pred]&;
```

#### Final functions

Here is our previous generic implementation (I changed the name):

```
ClearAll[dropWhileGeneric];
dropWhileGeneric[list_,test_]:=
   Drop[list,LengthWhile[list,test]]
```

and here is a final function:

```
ClearAll[dropWhile];
Options[dropWhile]={CompileToC->False,Compiled->True};
dropWhile[lst_List,pred_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
   Block[
   {          
      $target=If[TrueQ[OptionValue[CompileToC]],"C","MVM"],
      $useCompile=TrueQ[OptionValue[Compiled]]
   },
      dropWhileDispatch[getType[lst],pred][lst]
   ];
```

#### Benchmarks

JIT-compilation to MVM is really fast:

```
clearDropWhileCache[];
dropWhile[Range[100000], # < 99999 &] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.007813, {99999, 100000}} *)
```

The second time is faster still, since we don't have to recompile:

```
dropWhile[Range[100000], # < 99999 &] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.006836, {99999, 100000}} *)
```

The compilation to `C` is quite slow:

```
dropWhile[Range[100000], # < 99999 &,CompileToC -> True] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {4.640625, {99999, 100000}} *)
```

But gives a considerable further speedup:

```
dropWhile[Range[100000], # < 99999 &,CompileToC -> True] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.001953, {99999, 100000}} *)
```

Here is what we get from the generic implementation:

```
dropWhile[Range[100000], # < 99999 &, Compiled -> False] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.157226, {99999, 100000}} *)
```

It is not as bad as it could have been, since `LengthWhile` by itself is optimized on packed arrays, but it does not compare with the JIT versions.

#### The complete code

```
ClearAll[dropWhileJIT];
dropWhileJIT[pred_,listType_,target:"MVM"|"C":"MVM"]:=
   dropWhileJIT[pred,Verbatim[listType],target]=
      Block[{l},
         With[{decl={Prepend[listType,l]}},
            Compile@@
               Hold[                      
                  decl,
                  Module[{pos=1},
                     While[pred[l[[pos]]],pos++];Drop[l,pos-1]
                  ],
                  CompilationTarget->target
               ]
         ]
      ]


Clear[getType,$useCompile];
getType[arg_List]/;$useCompile&&ArrayQ[arg,_,IntegerQ]:=
   {_Integer,Length[Dimensions[arg]]};
getType[arg_List]/;$useCompile&&ArrayQ[arg,_,NumericQ]&&Re[arg]==arg:=
   {_Real,Length[Dimensions[arg]]};
getType[_]:=
   General;

Clear[dropWhileDispatch];
dropWhileDispatch[
   t:{Verbatim[_Integer]|Verbatim[_Real]|Verbatim[_Complex],n_},pred_
]:=
   dropWhileJIT[pred,t,$target];

dropWhileDispatch[_,pred_]:=
   dropWhileGeneric[#1,pred]&;


ClearAll[dropWhileGeneric];
dropWhileGeneric[list_,test_]:=
   Drop[list,LengthWhile[list,test]]


ClearAll[dropWhile];
Options[dropWhile]={CompileToC->False,Compiled->True};
dropWhile[lst_List,pred_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
   Block[
   {          
      $target=If[TrueQ[OptionValue[CompileToC]],"C","MVM"],
      $useCompile=TrueQ[OptionValue[Compiled]]
   },
      dropWhileDispatch[getType[lst],pred][lst]
   ];


ClearAll[clearDropWhileCache];
clearDropWhileCache[]:=
   DownValues[dropWhileJIT]={Last[DownValues[dropWhileJIT]]};
```

Comment: That's... a good question. This is somewhat faster than my version, and it's *much* simpler.

Comment: @Pillsy See my edit.

Comment: By the way, it just crossed my mind that a better design would have been to optimize `LengthWhile` and then always use the simple solution with that optimized `lengthWhile` - this way we get `LengthWhile` (and potentially also `TakeWhile`) optimizations for free.