# Bad performance of LengthWhile?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

**The performance of `LengthWhile` has been improved in *v11.1*, now the `lengthwhile` below is no longer faster.**

---

A friend of mine showed me this example, it's a test comparing `LengthWhile` to a self-made `lengthwhile` written in a direct and conventional way:

```
lengthwhile[x_, t_] := Module[{i = 0, l = Length@x}, While[i < l && t@x[[i + 1]], i++]; i]

lst = RandomInteger[{-2, 2}, {10^4, 10}];
rst1 = LengthWhile[#, # >= 0 &] & /@ lst; // AbsoluteTiming
rst2 = lengthwhile[#, # >= 0 &] & /@ lst; // AbsoluteTiming
rst1 == rst2
```

> ```
> {3.941000, Null}
> {0.474000, Null}
> True
> ```

`LengthWhile` is much slower than the reinvented wheel! Why? Simply a bad performance of `LengthWhile`? Or `LengthWhile` isn't used in a proper way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several reasons. Firstly the built-in function has some minor overhead to check the arguments and call the appropriate internal function depending on whether the first argument is a list, a sparse array or an association.

Secondly, with a packed array, `LengthWhile` uses compilation in an attempt to increase performance. There is some overhead in evaluating `Compile`, which is especially noticeable for your example with many small lists. (Note that if you do `` lst2 = Developer`FromPackedArray[lst] `` the built-in `LengthWhile` is faster than it is on the packed list.)

Finally, there appears to be a bug in the implementation of the compilation, such that the compiled function calls back to the main evaluator for the predicate function. You can see this by capturing the `CompiledFunction` from a `Trace` and examining it with `CompilePrint`:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];

CompilePrint @@ Cases[Trace[LengthWhile[lst[[1]], # >= 0 &]], _CompiledFunction, -1, 1]
```

> ```
> blah...
> 7 B2 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Statistics`TakeWhileDump`predfun$42706][I5]]
> blah...
> ```

The internal function calling `Compile` is `` Statistics`TakeWhileDump`findLastPosition ``. It appears that the predicate function is not being inlined as we would desire (despite "InlineExternalDefinitions" being used). I'm not sure what the rules are about inlining external definitions, so I'm not sure if this is due to a change in `Compile` or bad code in `` Statistics`TakeWhileDump`findLastPosition ``.

Comment: There is line `predfun[arg_] := pred[arg];` in `findLastPosition`. Then `Compile` is called with `predfun`. It causes uncompiled evaluation (why?). If I change ``...predfun[Compile`GetElement[...`` to ``...pred[Compile`GetElement[...`` it works as desired.

Comment: @ybeltukov Just dug out the definition of `Statistics\`TakeWhileDump\`findLastPosition` with `??` and modified all the `predfun` part, the `AbsoluteTiming` changed from 3.7s to 2.7s in my computer.

Comment: @xzczd What test did you try? Your test have a big overhead due to the compilation.

Comment: @ybeltukov I tested the code in my question. After deleting the definition of `predfun` and replacing all the `predfun` with `pred`, I got 1 second speed up.

Comment: @xzczd You will obtain bigger speedup for my test. When you apply `/@` for a big set of short lists you compile over and over again.

Comment: @ybeltukov BTW it's indeed strange that the `predfun` is defined inside `findLastPosition`, it only causes the side-effect: function definitions based on pattern-matching can't be inlined. (There seems to be no specific post for the issue, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/705/1871) is a related one, also notice the comments below. )

Comment: Response from Wolfram company: _……Thank you for your message and the link of the post.
I have filed a report on this performance issue of LengthWhile and thank you for bringing it to our attention.……_

Answer (score 14):

Your test is quite synthetic: you take only few first elements. If you you have longer sequence of positive elements then build-in `LengthWhile` is faster

```
lst = RandomInteger[{-1, 30000}, 100000];
rst1 = LengthWhile[lst, # >= 0 &]; // AbsoluteTiming
rst2 = lengthwhile[lst, # >= 0 &]; // AbsoluteTiming
rst1 == rst2
(* {0.096340, Null} *)
(* {0.166603, Null} *)
(* True *)
```

*Update:*

Amazingly, the compiled version is considerably faster then `LengthWhile`.

```
cLengthWhile = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}, {thr, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{i = 0, l = Length@x}, 
    While[i < l && (x[[i + 1]] >= thr), i++]; i], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

rst3 = cLengthWhile[lst, 0]; // AbsoluteTiming
rst1 == rst3
(* {0.000138, Null} *)
(* True *)
```

*Update 2:*

For your set of short lists there is quite fast uncompiled function

```
lengthwhile[x_, t_] := 
 Module[{i = 0, l = Length@x}, While[i < l && t@x[[i + 1]], i++]; i]
lengthWhile2[x_, thr_] := 
 Dimensions[x][[2]] - Total@Unitize@Accumulate[Transpose@UnitStep[x - thr] - 1]

lst = RandomInteger[{-2, 2}, {10^4, 10}];
rst1 = LengthWhile[#, # >= 0 &] & /@ lst; // AbsoluteTiming
rst2 = lengthwhile[#, # >= 0 &] & /@ lst; // AbsoluteTiming
rst3 = lengthWhile2[lst, 0]; // AbsoluteTiming
rst4 = cLengthWhile[lst, 0]; // AbsoluteTiming
rst1 == rst2 == rst3 == rst4
(* {3.990231, Null} *)
(* {0.307152, Null} *)
(* {0.004986, Null} *)
(* {0.001347, Null} *)
(* True *)
```

Comment: +1. Have a look also [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27974/a-fast-robust-dropwhile/27975#27975), it is closely related to your comment on compiled version (also my comment to that answer).

Comment: @xzczd, see my recent update concerning your case exactly.