# Performance of Nest vs. Do

Tags: performance-tuning, pure-function

When I am iterating the logistic function using a pure function, comparing [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) and [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html):

```
x = 0.1; Do[x = 3 x (1 - x), 300] // RepeatedTiming
Nest[3 # (1 - #) &, .1, 300] // RepeatedTiming
```

> `0.00026`
>
> `7.8*10^-6`

Tremendous speed advantage when using `Nest`.

However, when I define a function first, then

```
lf[x_] := 3 x (1 - x)
x = 0.1; Do[x = lf[x], 300] // RepeatedTiming // First
Nest[lf[#] &, .1, 300] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> `0.00043`
>
> `0.00045`

Now `Nest` is actually slower oftentimes!

I can improve it by not using the [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)

```
Nest[lf, .1, 300] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

But it still is slow:

> `0.000342`

Why? How can it be improved?

Comment: Little hint: `NestCompileLength` is 100 by default.

Comment: Also `RepeatedTiming` can be misleading.

Comment: @Karsten7. Well, compiling it with `Compile[{}, Nest[lf, .1, 300]]` doesn't change much -- still `0.000382` even with increased `NestCompileLength`. Can you elaborate on misleading of `RepeatedTiming`? What is better then?

Comment: If the function being nested refers to a symbol, then most likely the compiled form would evaluate the symbol via `MainEvaluate[]`, and diminish or destroy any advantage in compiling.  So probably neither `lf` nor `lf[#] &` is compiled, but `3 # (1 - #) &` is.

Comment: @Karsten7. No, the true reason is function definition based on pattern-matching cannot be compiled. This question is strongly related (if not a duplicate) to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/705/1871). Also, see the 3rd rule in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871).

Comment: @MichaelE2 "Refers to a symbol" isn't a problem, if the function inside the symbol is a pure function, _Mathematica_ is still able to compile it via `"InlineExternalDefinitions"`. (BTW, though `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` has been used quite a bit in this site. It's actually not that clear what can be inlined by this option, see [this unanswered question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145991/what-can-be-inlined-by-inlineexternaldefinitions-true) for more information.

Comment: @xzczd I guess your no is referring to my comment. I think we had the same cause in mind. Please check my answer and leave a comment if I'm missing something.

Comment: In this context `RepeatedTiming` can be misleading, as it is able to reuse an autocompiled function for multiple runs of the same code. It is comparable to using the last result of `Table[
 First@AbsoluteTiming[
    Do[
     Nest[3 # (1 - #) &, .1, 300],
     n]]/n,
 {n, 1, 5}]`.

Comment: @Karsten7. Sorry the last comment is a bit rough. (The net here is rather unstable today and I don't know when I'll be off line. ) By "no" I mean though the issue is related to auto-compilation, I'm afraid it's not related to `NestCompileLength`, because the 3rd argument is `300` in all the sample so `Nest` has tried compiling in all of them. The key point is, when the 1st argument of `Nest` is a pure function, `Nest` will be able to fully compile it, while it'll not when `lf` is a function relationship defined by pattern-matching. As to the `RepeatedTiming` part, I actually agree that…

Comment: …the result is misleading. "Not using `Slot`" doesn't improve the performance of the last `Nest`. If one increases `300` to e.g. `300000`, it'll be just as slow as the `Nest[lf[#]&, …`

Comment: @xzczd Yes, "symbol" was too broad. Constants are inlined by the autocompiler. -- Not sure what you have in mind when you say, "the function inside the symbol is a pure function." Do you mean `fn = 3 # (1 - #) &`? -- Any example that shows you can pass `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` with to the autocompiler in `Nest`? Perhaps it already uses it, though, since constants are inlined.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It can actually be a bit more general, for example `lf = 3 # (1 - #) &; Nest[lf[#] &, .1, 3 10^5] // AbsoluteTiming`. The timing is the same as `Nest[3 # (1 - #) &, .1, 3 10^5] // AbsoluteTiming`, which suggests `"InlineExternalDefinitions"->True` has already been set. (I admit it's just circumstantial evidence, but I think it's quite plausible. ) Another circumstantail evidence can be found in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61510/1871). (This one probably no longer exists in _v11.1_. )

Comment: Oh… "if the function inside the symbol is a pure function, _Mathematica_ is still able to compile it via `"InlineExternalDefinitions"`" I think should modify it to "if what's inside the symbol can be inlined by `"InlineExternalDefinitions"->True`, then it'll be fully compiled" 囧

Comment: @Karsten7. Thank you `RepeatedTiming` explanation -- I wasn't aware of reusing the autocompiled code. Looks like a strange way to get an average result. I won't use it anymore for performance comparison.

Comment: @xzczd Great explanations and thank you for the links to the compilation related questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main reason why

```
x = 0.1; Do[x = 3 x (1 - x), 300] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> `0.000393629`

and

```
lf[x_] := 3 x (1 - x)
x = 0.1; Do[x = lf[x], 300] // AbsoluteTiming // First
Nest[lf[#] &, .1, 300] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.000643239
>       0.000691691

are slower than

```
Nest[3 # (1 - #) &, .1, 300] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> `0.000161729`

is the fact, that the last `Nest` can and does make use of autocompilation.
The default `NestCompileLength` is 100:

```
SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "NestCompileLength"]
```

> `{"CompileOptions" -> {"NestCompileLength" -> 100}}`

Autocompilation can be switched off for `Nest` by setting its compile length to `Infinity`.

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "NestCompileLength" -> Infinity]
```

Now

```
Nest[3 # (1 - #) &, .1, 300] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> `0.000461127`

is much slower and has a performance similar to the first `Do`.

---

By using a precompiled version of `lf` a performance that is even better than the pure function with `Nest`'s autocompilation can be achieved:

```
clf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}}, 3 x (1 - x)];
Nest[clf, .1, 300] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> `0.000128982`

However, if the time needed for compiling is included

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  clf2 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}}, 3 x (1 - x)];
  Nest[clf2, .1, 300]
  ]
```

> `0.000187792`

one can see that this uses more time in total than the pure function with autocompilation, as calling `clf2` for every evaluation adds an additional overhead.

After switching autocompilation back on

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "NestCompileLength" -> 1];
```

`Nest` does need some extra time, because it tries to autocompile `clf` now

```
Nest[clf, .1, 300] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> `0.000188127`

Comment: You don't need `clf[#] &` -- `clf` is already a function.  +1 however for addressing compilation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll remeasure my timings, as that added an additional overhead.

Answer (score 5):

I get results that differ form yours more than can be accounted form by my computer system being slower than yours. Here is what I'm seeing.

```
(x = 0.1; Do[x = 3 x (1 - x), 300];x) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.000406, 0.653113}`

```
 Nest[3 # (1 - #) &, .1, 300] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.000177, 0.653113}`

```
f[x_] := 3 x (1 - x)

func = Function[Evaluate[f[#]]]
```

> `3 (1 - #1) #1 &`

```
(x = 0.1; Do[x = f[x], 300]; x) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.000712, 0.653113}`

```
Nest[f, .1, 300] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.000586, 0.653113}`

```
Nest[func, .1, 300] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.000177, 0.653113}`

This last version is exactly the same internally as the 2nd version and, not surprisingly, gives the same results.

Conclusions

- `Nest` is alway faster than `Do`.
- `Nest` is optimized for pure functions.
- When you want to iterate over user defined function, when feasible it is best to convert it into a pure function and iterate over the pure function.

Comment: Do you have any insight or references as to why or how pure functions work so much better?  +1

Comment: Your timings are slower, because you are using `AbsoluteTiming` instead of the `RepeatedTiming` used in the question. You can compare `With[{func = Function[Evaluate@lf[#]]},
   Nest[func, .1, 300]
   ] // AbsoluteTiming // First` with `With[{func = Function[Evaluate@lf[#]]},
   Nest[func, .1, 300]
   ] // RepeatedTiming // First`. On my PC the output of the former one is a factor 10 bigger. `RepeatedTiming` does reuse the autocompiled function multiple times.

Comment: @jjc385 Using pure functions allows autocompiling to create an efficient, properly compiled function, as it is not capable of inlining external definitions (as far as I know; check [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompilationOptions.html#207754129) for details about inlining.

Comment: @jjc385 Also check the [comment by xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147545/performance-of-nest-vs-do#comment396404_147545) and the links therein for why the other approaches don't autocompile properly.

Comment: Thank you! Your last bullet point is a great rule! It should probably be added [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)