# Understanding performance: graph connected components

Tags: graphs-and-networks, performance-tuning

I need to analyze directed graphs with 10M edges, 1M vertices, and 300K strongly connected components, so that the largest one contains 400K vertices.

I read some explanations of [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica/29351#29351), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6931/implementing-a-function-which-generalizes-the-merging-step-in-merge-sort) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481301/tail-call-optimization-in-mathematica). Although I don't quite understand why his code `merge` is so blazingly fast, I learned two things: no recursions only iterations, linked lists are cool. Trying to mimic his approach, I prepared two function for finding strongly connected components. The first one is Kosaraju's algorithm:

```
 ClearAll[readEdge, SowDFS, DFS, kosaraju]

 readEdge[{a_, b_}] := (adjOut[a] = q[b, adjOut[a]]; adjIn[b] = q[a, adjIn[b]]);

 (* Sow as a postvisit vertex function *)
 SowDFS[q[v_?newQ, rest_]] := SowDFS[newQ[v] = False; adjIn[v] /. q[] -> q[Sow[v], rest]];
 SowDFS[q[v_, rest_]] := SowDFS[rest];

 (* deep first scan *)
 DFS[q[v_?newQ, rest_]] := DFS[Sow[v, tag]; newQ[v] = False; adjOut[v] /. q[] -> rest];
 DFS[q[v_, rest_]] := DFS[rest];

 (* finding connected components *)
 kosaraju[graphList_] := Block[{adjOut, adjIn, order, newQ, q, tag = 1, $IterationLimit = Infinity},
 (* construction of adjacency lists *)
 adjOut[v_] = q[]; adjIn[v_] = q[]; Scan[readEdge, graphList];
 SetAttributes[q, HoldAllComplete];
 (* the first scan: topological sort of the reverse graph *)
 newQ[v_] = True;
 order = Reverse[Reap[Scan[SowDFS[q[#, q[]]] &, DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[graphList]]][[2, 1]]];
 (* the second scan: finding components *)
 Clear[adjIn, newQ]; newQ[v_] = True;
 Last@Reap[Scan[(tag++; DFS[q[#, q[]]]) &, order], _, #2 &]
 ]
```

The second one is based on Tarjan's algorithm, as it is described in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm). I only adapted it in non-recursive way:

```
 (* reading edge *)
 readOut[{a_, b_}] := (adj[a] = q[b, adj[a]]);

 (* test to start component *)
 strongQ[v_] := index[v] == link[v];

 (* pop from stack *)
 pop[v_, q[v_, rest_]] := (inQ[Sow[v, v]] = False; rest);
 pop[v_, q[a_, rest_]] := pop[v, inQ[Sow[a, v]] = False; rest];

 (* deep first scan with two stacks *)
 biDFS[q[v_?newQ, rest_], stack_] := biDFS[
    (* previsit function *)
    newQ[v] = False; index[v] = link[v] = ++idx; {p[v], root} = {root, v};
    adj[v] /. q[] -> q[h[v], rest], inQ[v] = True; q[v, stack]];

 biDFS[q[h[v_?strongQ], rest_], stack_] := biDFS[rest, pop[v, stack]];
 biDFS[q[v_?inQ, rest_], stack_] := biDFS[link[root] = Min[link[root], index[v]]; rest, stack];
 biDFS[q[v_, rest_], stack_] := biDFS[rest, stack]

 (* postvisit vertex function *)
 h[a_] := (root = p[a]; link[root] = Min[link[root], link[a]]; a);

 (* start scan *)
 start[v_?newQ] := Block[{p, root = v, inQ, link, index, idx = 0},
 (* p is for parent *)p[a_] := a; inQ[a_] = False;
 biDFS[q[v, q[]], q[]]]

(* finding connected components *)
tarjan[graphList_] := Block[{adj, newQ, q, $IterationLimit = Infinity},
(* construction of adjacency out-lists *)
adj[v_] = q[]; Scan[readOut, graphList]; SetAttributes[q, HoldAllComplete];
(* finding components *)
newQ[v_] = True;
Last@Reap[Scan[start, DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[graphList]], _, #2 &]
]
```

I try not to use WM build in functions for graph analysis in order to have a clear comparison.

To test the performance I chose Google+ graphs from [Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/). The renamed version of one of them is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2-RvPgwoOKEb0hEWnN5WmlvMTQ/edit?usp=sharing).

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
graphList = Import["edges.dat"];
```

This graph contains 5126172 edges but only 16405 vertices. The structure of SCC is not completely trivial: a single connected component with 11064 vertices, another one — 11 vertices, one more — 5 vertices, three ones — 3 vertices each, ten components with 2 vertices, and 5296 vertices which are not strongly connected.

On the one hand, WM somehow requires a lot of time to form the graph:

```
result2 = ConnectedComponents[
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ graphList]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {139.523577, Null} *)
```

and only half of a second to find the strongly connected components.

On the other hand, reading the graph takes 29 seconds in my function `tarjan`, and 12 seconds to find the components, thus 42 second in total:

```
result1 = tarjan[graphList]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {42.207118, Null} *)
```

Hence, my question is it possible to speed up the `tarjan` function so that it will be at least 10 times slower than the built-in function `ConnectedComponents`?

My nb-file is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2-RvPgwoOKEcF9XSGE0UTVUOTQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: The `merge` function is fast because it is type-specialized on numerical lists, on which it gets compiled. No time to look at your code in detail right now, but any top-level code with some sort of iteration will likely be much slower than the built-in function. You may want to check out my answer [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Nov/msg00321.html), for a semi-compiled implementation of connected components which might rival a built-in one, and actually the entire thread to which it belongs, for some extra context / ideas.

Comment: If you don't want to restrict yourself to *Mathematica* you can take a look [here](http://graphlab.org/projects/graphchi.html) and [here](http://graphlab.org/files/osdi2012-kyrola-blelloch-guestrin.pdf)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks for the quick response. Sure, I will read the thread, but at a glance it is about connected components of an undirected graph, that is a bit easier.

Comment: @Sektor looks interesting, but I have a problem for one time only. I use it to learn something new about *Mathematica.*

Comment: There might be methods of interest [at this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/PcovYoczMrs/SXLP3sCMChIJ). My guess is mostly they will be too slow though (except maybe the built-in `ConnectedComponents`).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Sorry, I deleted my stupid comment. But the original problem you give a link is as follows: for a given undirected graph with edges *prlist*, find a subgraph with vertices *list* and then find connected components of the subgraph. Are you agree? It is not related to directed graphs.

Comment: [I deleted my orphaned comment as well.] If I recall correctly the thread I linked to did in fact work with undirected rather than directed graphs. But I think the idea was to find connected components thereof. Maybe I'm mistaken but I thought similar methods could be applied to find connected components of directed graphs.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The idea I kept in mind asking the question is as follows: *Mathematica* requires a lot of time to form a graph. It means *Mathematica* organizes graph into a special data structure in order to make functions like `FindShortestPath`, `GraphDistance` etc. to be blazingly fast. Maybe this structure is too surplus for a single problem like finding connected components? I thought maybe adjacency lists organized as linked lists are enough. But actually, now I think that my function `tarjan` is simply stupid (completely not optimal).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau In any case the function SparseArray`StronglyConnectedComponents is really cool, so thank you for sharing.

Comment: I agree that the `Graph` internals can be relatively slow to construct, for exactly the reasons you state (efficiency of later computations). And it is possibly excessive for the specific purpose of finding connected components-- I do not know for certain.