# What's the time / space complexity of pattern matching?

Tags: performance-tuning, pattern-matching, computational-complexity

For example, in `ReplaceAll[expression, pattern]`, what are the main algorithms used internally? How does the asymptotic time / space complexity scale with the length / complexity of `expression` and `pattern` used above?

Comment: It really depends on the type of pattern. Patterns that require lots of backtracking (e.g., non-trivial combinations of `Longest`, `Shortest`, `Repeated` and/or `OrderlessPatternSequence`) will be much more expensive than simple ones that just check a head (e.g., `_Integer`).

Comment: [Related Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-can-i-ensure-that-i-am-constructing-patterns-in-the-most-efficient-way-possi)