# How to reduce the InterpolatingFunction building overhead?

Tags: performance-tuning, interpolation

I want a linear interpolation from the following example list:

```
list = {{0.0005023, 22.24}, {0.01457, 21.47}, {0.04922, 19.79}, 
      {0.07484, 18.7}, {0.104, 17.55}, {0.1331, 16.52}, {0.1632, 15.49},
      {0.1888, 14.52}, {0.2215, 13.31}, {0.2506, 12.16}, {0.3024, 10.01}, 
      {0.3435, 8.304}, {0.3943, 6.036}, {0.4098, 5.329}, {0.4726, 2.384}};
```

The easiest way is to use:

```
Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

but my `list` will be changing a lot, and the `InterpolatingFunction` takes a lot of time to build:

```
Timing[
   Table[Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 1][q], {q, 
     0.0006, 0.4, 0.00001}];]
```

is 10× slower than:

```
test=Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Timing[Table[test[q], {q, 0.0006, 0.4, 0.00001}];]
```

How can I remove the overhead?

---

**EDIT** (following JxB comment)

This compiled version is 5 times faster than the original version, but I don't think `Partition` is compiling (it appears between all the `List`s when I use `FullForm`); and there's also a `CopyTensor` that *doesn't look good*:

```
Compile[{{list, _Real, 2}, {value, _Real, 0}},
 Module[{temp},
  temp = Select[
     Partition[list, 2, 1], #[[1, 1]] <= value && #[[2, 1]] > value &][[1]
   ];
  temp[[1, 2]] +
   (value - temp[[1, 1]])/(temp[[2, 1]] - temp[[1, 1]])*(temp[[2, 2]] - temp[[1, 2]])
  ]
 ]
```

Any suggestions? (I don't want to compile to C.)

Comment: Perhaps **Timing[Table[
   Evaluate@Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 1][q], {q, 
    0.0006, 0.4, 0.00001}];]** ?

Comment: Since you are using linear interpolation, it might be straightforward to build your own compiled version of an interpolating function.

Comment: Do your x-value remain the same from list to list?

Comment: @rcollyer my x-value also changes

Comment: Opps... from the answers and comments I see that apparently I didn't explain myself correctly. The `Table` was there just to raise the timing to readable measurements (I should have used `Do`...). The calls to "`test`" will be made almost for one `q` at a time, and in-between `list` may change.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use binary search with `Compile`. I failed inlining (`Compile` was complaining endlessly about types mismatch), so I included a binary search directly into `Compile`-d function. The code for binary search itself corresponds to the `bsearchMin` function from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/finding-elements-in-a-sorted-list/2371#2371).

```
Clear[linterp];
linterp =
   Compile[{{lst, _Real, 2}, {pt, _Real}},
     Module[{pos  = -1 , x = lst[[All, 1]], y = lst[[All, 2]], n0 = 1, 
          n1 = Length[lst], m = 0},
      While[n0 <= n1, m = Floor[(n0 + n1)/2];
        If[x[[m]] == pt,
          While[x[[m]] == pt  && m < Length[lst], m++];
          pos = If[m == Length[lst], m, m - 1];
          Break[];
        ];
        If[x[[m]] < pt, n0 = m + 1, n1 = m - 1]
      ];
      If[pos == -1, pos = If[x[[m]] < pt, m, m - 1]];
      Which[
        pos == 0,
           y[[1]],
        pos == Length[x],
           y[[-1]],
        True,
        y[[pos]] + (y[[pos + 1]] - y[[pos]])/(x[[pos + 1]] - 
              x[[pos]])*(pt - x[[pos]])
      ]],
      CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

This is about 20 times faster, on my benchamrks:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
   Table[Interpolation[list,InterpolationOrder->1][q],{q,0.0006,0.4,0.00001}];
]
```

> `{1.453,Null}`

```
AbsoluteTiming[
   Table[linterp[list,q],{q,0.0006,0.4,0.00001}];
]
```

> `{0.063,Null}`

Comment: I just realized the OP specifically said "I don't want to compile to C."  What timings do you get on v8 using WVM?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's about twice slower. The difference is not so dramatic, because the complexity itself is only logarithmic.

Comment: Using WVM I'm getting the same time as the prebuild InterpolatingFunction solution, that is, half the speed of the C compilation. This is already very good. Thank you!

Comment: @P.Fonseca Any particular reason for not compiling to C?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I'm placing the function in a package, and so, either I also distribute the compiled dll (it's a very simple package, and I want to keep it simple), or the user needs to have the compiler. And now that I think of, another alternative would be to have the dll compressed inside the package, and generate/save/unload the dll file at the moment of the package load (is this doable?).

Comment: @P.Fonseca It is, but it is a hassle. You will need to do this for all platforms (since shared libs are platform-dependent), and you will have to dispatch to a right one depending on the platform. Nothing too complicated though, and sounds like a very good project (since this is a general problem). I think, a general module for serialization of compiled functions would be very useful. The problem would be, that to use it on a single machine, one would need all cross-compilers to other platforms installed. Macs seem best equipped for that, but it would still be some work to set that up.

Comment: @P.Fonseca Since in this particular case the speed-up is only twofold, I would not bother, unless this is the most critical part of your code, and you really need this factor of two speed increase.

Comment: @P.Fonseca if you are precompiling, then sure, I can understand only using WVM. However, if you load ``CCompilerDriver` `` the function `DefaultCCompiler[]` will generate the message `CreateLibrary::nocomp` and return `$Failed` if no default compiler was set. Personally, I'd `Quiet` the message and test for `$Failed` directly, as there is less chance of the message escaping. Using that info, you can choose your compilation target.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin do you see any speed improvements if you specialize `linterp` to a particular list? In other words, have `linterp[list]` return a compiled function that already contains the pre-built binary tree. Although, that may be counter productive with the OPs purpose ...

Comment: @rcollyer do you mean a mixture of the memorization answer and the binary search compiled answer?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I'm going with the C compiler presence test, followed by the correct choice of compiler, as you said. Thank you.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin doesn't work for linterp[list, list[[-1, 1]]]

Comment: @P.Fonseca Yes, you are right. There was a bug there - this is an edge case. Fixed now.

Comment: @rcollyer "that may be counter productive with the OPs purpose" - this is exactly the reason why I did not go there. Inlining a list would make sense when the list doesn't change, which is not the case OP is interested in.

Comment: @P.Fonseca no, that's not what I meant. Leonid's code currently rebuilds the search tree for every `q`; it is impressive that it is still faster. What I was referring to was pre-building the tree, so it can be used multiple times. But, in your case, that is likely not helpful.

Comment: @rcollyer I am not really building a search tree. This is a plain binary search, not a binary search tree. I assume that the list is already sorted. Binary search tree would be useful if one also would like insertions of nodes to be fast (`log N`). But here, I am taking as a given that modification of the list in between calls to `linterp` is done efficiently - so my code is not concerned with that. So, `linterp` runs in logarithmic time, this is why it is fast (and this is why compilation to C gives only a moderate speedup w.r.t. MVM target).

Comment: Good job. It is still 15 x slower than Matlab's interp1. Any idea why?

Comment: @n3rd This may be due to the top-level overhead of `Table`, and the `list` in the example is pretty small. For large lists, it should be pretty fast - this is a rather basic code compiled directly to C. It may be that Matlab uses some different and highly-optimized method though.

Answer (score 7):

Combinatorica functions are often not well optimized, so there may very well be a faster binary search algorithm.  If that can be found, this might be effective:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]

f[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}][x_] := b + (d - b)/(c - a) (x - a)

list[[Floor@{#, # + 1}]] & @ BinarySearch[list[[All, 1]], 0.33]

f[%][0.33]
```

> ```
> 8.86436
> ```

Check:

```
Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 1][0.33]
```

> ```
> 8.86436
> ```

Comment: I was fighting with inlining in `Compile` (and lost), and was beaten to it by you, as a result (so lost again). +1.

Comment: @Leonid if I had taken the time to look up the faster binary search (which I believe you posted before) you'd have been first. +1 to you as well. :-)

Comment: It seems you don't need to load Combinatorica anymore; you can use ``GeometricFunctions`BinarySearch[]`` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a linear interpolation routine that uses binary search with a few refinements (in particular, the binary search is skipped in the case of equispaced abscissas), as well as a stabilized version of the linear interpolation formula:

```
lerp = Compile[{{dat, _Real, 2}, {x, _Real}},
  Module[{n = Length[dat], k = 1, l, m, r, xa, ya},
         {xa, ya} = Transpose[dat];
         l = Min[Max[2, 1 + Quotient[x - First[xa],
                                     (Last[xa] - First[xa])/(n - 1)]], n - 1];

         If[xa[[l]] <= x,
            r = l + 1;
            While[r < n && xa[[r]] <= x,
                  l = r; k *= 2; r = Min[l + k, n]],
            {l, r} = {l - 1, l};
            While[1 < l && x < xa[[l]],
                  r = l; k *= 2; l = Max[1, r - k]]];

         While[r - l > 1,
               m = Quotient[l + r, 2];
               If[x < xa[[m]], r = m, l = m]];

         ({xa[[r]] - x, x - xa[[l]]}/(xa[[r]] - xa[[l]])).ya[[{l, r}]]],
         RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Even without the compilation to C, the method is quite fast on my box:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Table[Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1][q],
                     {q, 0.0006, 0.4, 0.00001}];][[1]]
   15.206078

AbsoluteTiming[Table[lerp[data, q], {q, 0.0006, 0.4, 0.00001}];][[1]]
   0.693506
```

Answer (score 4):

Something with memory ?

```
myTest[alist_] :=  myTest[alist] = Interpolation[alist, InterpolationOrder -> 1]

Timing[Table[myTest[list][q], {q, 0.0006, 0.4, 0.00001}];]

(* {0.187,Null} *)

test=Interpolation[list,InterpolationOrder->1];
Timing[Table[test[q],{q,0.0006,0.4,0.00001}];]

(* {0.172,Null} *)
```

Comment: This might work. It builds the `InterpolatingFunction` just once for each new list. I don't think I will have more than a couple thousands lists during a session, and so, I believe still manageable. Do you see a way to purge the memorization (memory or quantity) if it passes over a certain value (obvious, without too much overhead…)?

Comment: @P.Fonseca Do you mean remove the previous definitions if they exceed a certain memory usage ? If so, sorry I don't.

Comment: Yes. If the total myTest definitions exceed a certain quantity or memory usage