# Linear interpolation over 2 variables

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, interpolation, compile

I'm tuning a function to data over 4-5 variables using Differential Evolution. The objective function calls frequently interpolation function. I came to a point, where compiling the objective function should make things much faster. But interpolation function cannot be compiled.

Is there compilable implementation of linear interpolation function over 2 variables that is faster or of similar speed with uncompilable internal interpolation function?

---

EDIT

looks like this is working solution:

[How to reduce the InterpolatingFunction building overhead?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4994/how-to-reduce-the-interpolatingfunction-building-overhead)

Comment: It's hard to give suggestions without a specific code sample, can you add one?

Comment: no code is necessary, it is simple linear interpolation with 2 arguments on a regular grid

Comment: All the functions in the thread you linked to are for the univariate case. I presume you want *bilinear* interpolation? Some more work will then be needed.

Comment: I meant that for your specific problem someone might found a way for speeding up which is not "writing a compilable interpolating function" :)