# Is there a built-in function to do binary search?

Tags: functions, searching

Is there a built-in function to do binary search?
Say, given a list (sorted) and a number, find the position which keeps the listed sorted when the number is inserted.

I know that `LengthWhile` could manage that, but it's slow.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5022/12) might be relevant.  See also Mr. W's answer there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is some built-in binary search code but not in the core language as far as I know.

- There is [`BinarySearch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/BinarySearch.html) from the *Combinatorica* package, which is still the function I use most often despite the fact that that package is now deprecated and loading it causes shadowing of some Symbols.
- There is the undocumented `` GeometricFunctions`BinarySearch `` but this function does not appear to perform particularly well.

When I need greater performance I typically use [a compiled form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30122/121) of Leonid's code from:

- [Finding all elements within a certain range in a sorted list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/finding-all-elements-within-a-certain-range-in-a-sorted-list/2371#2371)

Answer (score 6):

It seems that since 2021 there is a [ResourceFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BinarySearch/) that does this.

Example:

```
ResourceFunction["BinarySearch"][{1, 2, 5, 5, 7, 12}, 6]
```

I looked at the definition of the resource function: it seems to mainly add error handling to `` GeometricFunctions`BinarySearch `` which, according to @Mr.Wizard's answer, "does not appear to perform particularly well."

The documentation for the resource function mentions under "Properties and Relations" that:

> BinarySearch can be considerably faster for packed arrays

with the example

```
packed = Sort[RandomReal[{0, 100}, 100000]];
RepeatedTiming[ResourceFunction["BinarySearch"][packed, 50]]
```

Here are some comparisons:

```
AbsoluteTiming[LengthWhile[packed, #<50&]] 

{0.016084, 50113}

bsearchResource = ResourceFunction["BinarySearch"]
AbsoluteTiming[bsearchResource[packed, 50]]

(* {0.000474, 50113} *)
```

Here's `BinarySearch` from the Combinatorica package mentioned in Mr.Wizard's answer. The package is deprecated and the user has to load the package beforehand with `` Needs["Combinatorica`"] ``:

```
AbsoluteTiming[BinarySearch[packed,50]]

{0.000183, 100227/2}
```

Then the `bsearch` function in the link by Mr.Wizard. This is the version that is not compiled:

```
AbsoluteTiming[bsearchMinNoCompile[packed, 50]]

{0.000159, 50113}
```

The C compiled version of `bsearch` (I changed the original complex type to real):

```
AbsoluteTiming[bsearchMinCompile[packed, 50]]

{0.000042, 50113}
```

Now looking at the difference between `bsearchMinNoCompile` and the resource function by increasing the length of packed by a factor of 100:

```
packed = Sort[RandomReal[{0, 100}, 10000000]];

RepeatedTiming[bsearchMinNoCompile[packed, 50]]

{0.0000492547, 4998443}

RepeatedTiming[bsearchResource[packed, 50]]

{0.0000291153, 4998443}
```

**Summary**: At least from the example provided by the resource function, it seems that `ResourceFunction["BinarySearch"]` provides a convenient method to obtain results quickly when the lists are sorted. The function also has some error handling.

Answer (score 4):

There are two relevant functions at Wolfram Function Repository (WFR) submitted by "Wolfram Staff":

- [`BinarySearch`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BinarySearch/)
- [`BinarySearchBy`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BinarySearchBy/)

---

Of course, one can see or follow the examples in the WFR pages. Nevertheless, here are examples that demonstrate the speed of `BinarySearch`.

```mathematica
SeedRandom[32];
packed = Sort[RandomReal[{0, 100}, 100000]];

s = packed[[1332]]

(* 1.35978 *)

ResourceFunction["BinarySearch"][packed, s]

(* 1332 *)
```

Timings comparison:

````mathematica
AbsoluteTiming[
 Do[ResourceFunction["BinarySearch"][packed, s], 1000]]

(* {0.194593, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Do[Position[packed, s], 1000]]

(* {4.6829, Null} *)
```
````

Comment: For a packed array of up to 140-150K elements, a full linear search `Pick[Range@Length@packed, Unitize[packed - s], 0]` is just as fast or faster. And finds duplicates. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Interesting and good to know -- thanks! (You can write to WFR staff suggesting to enhance `BinarySearch` with that code.)