# Find first position satisfying condition, which is true after a certain element

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, filtering

Can we find the first position of elements of a list satisfying a condition, with good performance, if the conditions is a **tail condition** of the list.

What is **tail condition** ? (the term is informal, personal.)
I will explain with an examples.

**Ex1)** Let `L={12,14,16,18,17,15,13}` and `Cond=OddQ`, then `Cond` is a tail condition of `L`.
Because, the first odd number seen in the list is the 5-th element `17`, any element after `17` is also odd.
For Ex1), `Earliest[L,Cond]` becomes `5`.

**Ex2)** Let `L={12,14,17,18,16,15,13}` and `Cond=OddQ`, then `Cond` is **not** a tail condition of `L`.
Because, the first odd number seen in the list is the 3-th element `17`, but there is an element that comes after `17`, which is not odd. Like `18` or `16`.
For Ex2), `Earliest[L,Cond]` becomes `6`. (At present stage, you can't know why it becomes `6`.)
Note that the first odd element is 3-th, not 6-th. But complaining about this is doesn't make sense, because `Earliest` is designed to work properly only if `Cond` is a tail condition of `L`.

**Ex3)** Let `L={12,14,17,18,16,15,13}` and `Cond=#>10&`, then `Cond` is a tail condition of `L`. Because every element is bigger then `10`.
For Ex3), `Earliest[L,Cond]` becomes `1`.

**Ex4)** Let `L={12,14,17,18,16,15,13}` and `Cond=#>20&`, then `Cond` is a tail condition of `L`. Because there is no element bigger then `20`.
For Ex4), `Earliest[L,Cond]` becomes `Missing["NotFound"]`.

Comment: What about [`FirstPosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstPosition.html)?

Comment: What is your question? This is a Q&A site, so you should split this post in two, resulting in a question that explains the requirements you have for your function, with sample inputs and outputs, and then a self-answer showing your current implementation.

Comment: @MacroB, I understood. I'll split the post in two, thank you.

Comment: If ```r``` is the result, a way to do some level of verification after the fact about having a tail condition to begin with would be to run Earliest on part ```;;r-1``` and on part ```r;; ```. The result should be ```{Missing[Not Found],1}```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you mean [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). If you plan to compile, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4994) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30122/121).

```
earliest[list_,cond_] := Module[{L,R,M},
    L=0;R=Length[list]+1;While[L<R-1,M=Quotient[L+R,2];If[cond[list[[M]]],R=M,L=M];];
    If[R<=Length[list],R,Missing["NotFound"]]];
```

Comment: I verified that your `earliest`  behaves correctly just as mine! I intended to avoid computation like `addition`, `Quotient[#,2]`, for better performance. But come to think of it now,  such consideration will not make notable improvement of performance.  And your code is much shorter.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a function called `Earliest`

So what is `Earliest` function ?

```
Earliest[a list_, a condition_]:=
```

It finds the first position of elements of a list satisfying the condition, **if the condition is a tail condition of the list.**
`Earliest` has a good *performance*.

What is **tail condition** ? (the term is informal, personal.)
I will explain with an examples.

**Ex1)** Let `L={12,14,16,18,17,15,13}` and `Cond=OddQ`, then `Cond` is a tail condition of `L`.
Because, the first odd number seen in the list is the 5-th element `17`, any element after `17` is also odd.
For Ex1), `Earliest[L,Cond]` becomes `5`.

**Ex2)** Let `L={12,14,17,18,16,15,13}` and `Cond=OddQ`, then `Cond` is **not** a tail condition of `L`.
Because, the first odd number seen in the list is the 3-th element `17`, but there is an element that comes after `17`, which is not odd. Like `18` or `16`.
For Ex2), `Earliest[L,Cond]` becomes `6`. (At present stage, you can't know why it becomes `6`.)
Note that the first odd element is 3-th, not 6-th. But complaining about this is doesn't make sense, because `Earliest` is designed to work properly only if `Cond` is a tail condition of `L`.

**Ex3)** Let `L={12,14,17,18,16,15,13}` and `Cond=#>10&`, then `Cond` is a tail condition of `L`. Because every element is bigger then `10`.
For Ex3), `Earliest[L,Cond]` becomes `1`.

**Ex4)** Let `L={12,14,17,18,16,15,13}` and `Cond=#>20&`, then `Cond` is a tail condition of `L`. Because there is no element bigger then `20`.
For Ex4), `Earliest[L,Cond]` becomes `Missing["NotFound"]`.

**The advantage of `Earliest` is the speed!**
Below is the code for `Earliest`

```
Earliest[L_, Cond_] := If[
  Length[L] == 0 || ! Cond[L[[-1]]],
  
  Missing["NotFound"],
  
  Module[{x = {BitLength[Length[L]] - 1}, 
    condi = (# > Length[L] || Cond[L[[#]]] &), final},
   While[x[[-1]] != 0, 
    If[condi[Total[2^x]], (x[[-1]] = x[[-1]] - 1; x), 
     x = Append[x, x[[-1]] - 1]]];
   final = 
    If[condi[Total[2^x]], x, 
     Module[{n = 1}, While[n <= Length[x] && (n - 1 == x[[-n]]), n++];
      Append[x[[;; Length[x] - (n - 1)]], n - 1]]];
   Total[2^final]]
  ]
```

To test `Earliest`, I've made a function `parrot` :

```
parrot[a_, b_] := (Earliest[Join[ConstantArray[0, a], Prime[Range[b]]], 
    PrimeQ[#] &] == If[b == 0, Missing["NotFound"], a + 1])
```

Now lets test :

```
Table[parrot[a, b], {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

You can check that it gives `True` for all cases.

To compare the performance of `Earliest` and method using the built-in functions, you can try :

```
SeedRandom[1000]; tibis = Accumulate[RandomInteger[10, 100000000]];
SelectFirst[tibis, # > 250000000 &] // Timing
Position[tibis, _?(# > 250000000 &), {1}, 1] // Timing
Earliest[tibis, # > 250000000 &] // Timing
```

Finally, this is a related screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am probably confused, but I can't explain the following. Here is a list of 100 integers.

```
rr = RandomInteger[1000, 100]

(* {235,40,513,519,487,552,7,634,608,527,458,695,70,54,557,665,801,\
205,18,99,235,908,615,268,391,228,124,301,257,743,321,910,415,793,217,\
660,81,81,465,278,192,128,148,1,37,327,836,485,379,988,661,942,142,\
778,704,897,629,777,693,4,474,540,602,584,36,82,979,511,287,312,565,\
65,845,650,448,235,823,323,518,257,463,423,623,608,946,894,823,87,186,\
543,705,482,591,214,892,830,749,848,590,612} *)
```

If my condition is integer > 500:

```
Earliest[rr, # > 500 &]

(* 3 *)
```

It seems to me that the answer should be 95, the position of value 892, **if** I undertsand what Earliest is supposed to do. For example, the following code returns 95 (it also returns 0 if there is no match).

```
i = 0; l = Length[rr];
While[i < l, If[rr[[l - i]] > 500, i++; Continue[], Break[]]];
If[i == 0, 0, l - i + 1]
```

Comment: The condition `# > 500 &` is NOT a tail condition of `rr`. In short, `Earliest` is meaningless  in your example. If `rr` were any list of monotonic increasing sequence, then  `# > 500 &` would be a tail condition of `rr`.

Comment: I see. So a tail condition exists if the first element matching the condition is the first element of the tail... and Earliest assumes, but does not verify, that the given condition is a tail condition.

Comment: Yes, use `Earliest` only when we `already know` the condition is a tail condition of L