# Find time since last 0 in list

Tags: functions, distance

When I have a list of data (measured per day), is it possible to define a function that gives the nr of days since the data has been 0? I tried working with`Position`to find the 0's but that did not really help me to create a function.

**Simplified example:**

```
data = {{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}};
ListPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, AxesLabel -> {"time(day)", "data(mm)"}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

**Result I want:** ( I now entered it myself, but I want to do this for large amounts of data, which makes typing it very time consuming ;))

```
result = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {4,0}, {5, 0}, {6, 1}};
ListPlot[result, AxesLabel -> {"time(day)", "days since last 0"}, 
   Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Your first Plot has an `InterpolationOrder->0` the other one does not have. `Length@data` gives 6 and `Length@result` gives 7. I don't really get what you want.., am I the only one?

Comment: The first one has `InterpolationOrder ->0` as the data the graph represents is assumed to be constant over the day. For the results, I want to know the time that has passed since the last time data=0. So in this case I want a lineair function. `Length@data` and `Length@results` are not equal because I needed to specify two points at time 4 to let the graph drop to 0 directly (as from time 4 on, it has been 0 days again since the last 0)

Comment: In other terms you want to know the length of gap between `{2,0}` and `{4,0}` in the `result` set of data? _*Still confused*_

Comment: Not completely. I want to know the gap between the 0's in `data`. But then given in a list, showing (per day) the time since the last 0. - Maybe the `result` I put in is a bit confusing. Result is not what I want, its what I have constructed myself to show the plot I want as a result.

Comment: First `Position[data, {_, 0}]` and then `Differences@Flatten@%-1`?

Comment: This is what I (sort of) tried myself. But can I use this to create a `function[time,value]` again? Like the way data looks, but then not with data but with time since 0?

Comment: You asked for a function, but the result you are hoping for is apparently not a function. An input of 4 has 2 values, namely 2 and zero. Please clarify.

Comment: user9022 It's not yet clear to me what you want.  I interpreted this question as seeking a *function* to produce the plot shown, not the data itself that you gave to `ListPlot`.  What is your actual use?

Comment: Mr. Wizard is right. That's what I need. I need to use it in another function, were t needs to go up lineairy but is reseted to 0 during the periods that the `data =  0`. But  I think I can do that with your solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Basic distance function

I believe we can use a binary search as I did for:
[How can the behavior of InterpolationOrder->0 be controlled?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30055/how-can-the-behavior-of-interpolationorder-0-be-controlled/30122#30122)

We start by extracting the zeros from your data:

```
zeros = Cases[Sort @ data, {x_, 0} :> x]
```

> {1, 4, 6}

- If `data` is always sorted you can omit `Sort`.
- If your zeros may not always have head `Integer` use the rule `{x_, n_ /; n==0} :> x`

I'll use the `` Combinatorica`BinarySearch `` function and `Floor` for simplicity; use a compiled version of Leonid's [bsearchMin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2371/121) if you need greater speed.

Now:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]

distanceFromLast[lst_List][val_?NumericQ] :=
  val - lst[[ Floor @ BinarySearch[lst, val] ]]

Plot[distanceFromLast[zeros][x], {x, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Or equivalently:

```
distanceFromLast[zeros] /@ Range[0, 10, 0.1] // ListLinePlot
```

### Extension and generalization

The output above doesn't quite match what question requested: the function should start climbing from zero where it does in `ListPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0]` rather than immediately after a zero.  If the data is regular as shown (sequential, evenly spaced indexes) this is simply a matter of an offset and threshold which may be done with `Max[0, value - 1]`:

```
Plot[Max[0, #-1]& @ distanceFromLast[zeros][x], {x, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Generalizing this to arbitrary $(x, y)$ data is more involved because the gaps vary in size.  I chose to use [`SplitBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SplitBy.html) as a foundation.  I will show the use of several functions and include the code for them below.

First I generate some data:

```
n = 40;
SeedRandom[1]
data = {Sort @ RandomReal[14, n], RandomInteger[4, n]}\[Transpose];
```

It looks like this:

```
p0 = ListLinePlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Then I create a distance function using my `makeDistFun`, plot it, and [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html) the two:

```
f1 = makeDistFun[data];

p1 = Plot[f1[x], {x, 0, 14},
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red, Dashed],
      PlotRange -> All];

Show[p0, p1, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

If you merely wish to draw the line it will be more efficient to use the `draw` function I provide:

```
p2 = draw[data, Green];

Show[p0, p2, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

#### Code

Note: I again use the Combinatorica `BinarySearch` function for brevity, and again `bsearchMin` or similar will be faster if it matters in practice.

```
breaks[data : {{_, _} ..}] :=
  Module[{d2, split},
    d2 = Append[data, Last[data] {1, 0}];
    split = SplitBy[d2, Unitize @ #[[2]] &][[All, 1, 1]];
    Partition[If[d2[[1, 2]] == 0, Rest@#, #] &[split], 2]
  ]

Needs["Combinatorica`"]
makeDistFun[data : {{_, _} ..}] := 
  Module[{starts, ends},
    {starts, ends} = breaks[data]\[Transpose];
    With[{n = Floor @ BinarySearch[starts, #]},
      If[# < ends[[n]], # - starts[[n]], 0]
    ] &
  ]

draw[data : {{_, _} ..}, {dir__} | dir__, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Graphics[{dir,
   Line @ Flatten[{{#, 0}, {#2, #2 - #}, {#2, 0}} & @@@ breaks[data], 1]
   }, opts
 ]
```

Comment: Do you have any experience about the speed difference between `Case[]` and `Flatten@Position[]` ?

Comment: @Öskå It really depends on the operation; usually they are reasonably comparable.  If you are thinking of `Flatten @ Position[data, {_, 0}]` I did not use that here because I did not assume that the indexes would always be 1 through *n*; with my method I extract the actual *x* values from the data.

Comment: Ok it makes sense indeed, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I wanted. However, I want the time to start counting since `data != 0`. For example `data=0` for `t>=1` to `t<2`. This means I want the `distanceFromLast` 0 to start counting from `t>=2 ` to `t<4`

Comment: @user9022 I think I understand but I'm not certain; please try using `distanceFromLast[lst_List][val_?NumericQ] := 
 Max[0, val - 1 - lst[[Floor@BinarySearch[lst, val]]]]` and tell me if it works as desired; if so I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes this works! Thanks

Comment: @user9022 I finally got around to updating my answer; please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe :

```
data = {{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}};  

counter = 0;
result = Flatten[
                  If[ #[[2]] == 0,
                      {{#[[1]], counter}, {#[[1]], counter = 0}},
                      {{#[[1]], counter++}}
                    ] & /@ data
                ,1]

ListPlot[result, AxesLabel -> {"time(day)", "days since last 0"}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

> {{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {6, 1}, {6, 0}}

[image]

The length of result is not the same as the length of data. It is also the case in your example.
Here, each time the counter is reset there is one more data : `Length[result]`
gives 9 (instead of 7 in your example)

Comment: That's an interpretation of the question I quite overlooked.  I *assumed* that he wanted a function and not the actual list.

Comment: Mr Wizard is right. I don't see any simple modification of my answer that make it fit the question. I will probably delete the answer.

Comment: andre No, don't delete it.  It's quite relevant.  It also made me think about this problem in a different way which I'll post soon if I have time. +1

Comment: It took me a while to return to it but if you're interested in my solution see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

What follows is an alternative visualization of the zeros in your data.

Let's try to separate the property of your data that you seem to be interested in from your display.

Some data...

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 3}, 100]
```

> {0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 
>   1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
>   0, 3, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 
>   1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 
>   1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0}

All that really matters is the positions of the zeros. `Unitize` is unnecessary but it helps hide noise in the data.

```
 Unitize@data /. {0 -> Style[0, 24]}
 p=Position[data, 0] // Flatten
```

[image: krea]

{1, 6, 14, 16, 21, 26, 27, 39, 47, 51, 64, 66, 67, 89, 92, 95, 100}

```
 Differences@%
```

> {5, 8, 2, 5, 5, 1, 12, 8, 4, 13, 2, 1, 22, 3, 3, 5}

The differences are only counted from the first occurrence of zero.

To visualize the gaps, you might use something like this...

```
BarChart[%,  ChartLabels -> Rest@p]
```

The labels on the x-axis refer to the position in which the second, third, fourth...nth zero occurred. The height represents the number of non-zero elements that preceded each respective occurrence.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`FoldList` can be used to keep track of how long ago the previous 0 occurred.

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 3}, 20]

   ==> {1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3}

daysSince = Rest[FoldList[If[#2 == 0, 0, #1 + 1] &, 0, data]]

   ==> {1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}
```

(Of course the first entry in the output list is arbitrary since we don't really know when the previous 0 occurred before the data started.)

Comment: mef, I'm giving you a vote because this is an excellent way to approach the basic question.  However, it doesn't quite match what the OP requested.