# Plotting jump function without vertical lines

Tags: plotting

Consider this list plot:

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {6, 0}}]
```

I want to draw a jump function in this list plot such that for each point I get a line to the right until the next point occurs. I do not want to see the vertical lines (as is done automatically by `ListLinePlot`)! How can I achieve that?

Equivalently, how can I get rid of the vertical lines of a jump function in a `ListLinePlot`?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10502/193

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8576/193

Comment: Exclusions is an option for Plot, not for ListLinePlot or ListPlot. In my case my jumps are very close to each other, so when I try to somehow convert the data into a Piecewise function then I don't see all the jumps (the mash must be variable). Or is it possible to convert a ListLinePlot to Plot?

Comment: Vaguely related: [(30438)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30438/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is what you want?

```
ListLinePlot[
  {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {6, 0}},
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  Frame -> True
] /. Line[x : {{_, _} ..}] :> (Line /@ Partition[x, 2])
```

[image]

Post-processing of the [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) expression generated by [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) is used in the form of [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html).  The [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html) is split into pairs of points using [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html), avoiding the drawing of vertical connecting segments.

---

Post-processing is a quick way to hack out a solution to a lot of plotting problems and it lets you work with the full range of e.g. `ListLinePlot` options.  However it can also be slow and fragile.  In the case above *every* `Line` expression is modified whether it originates from the plot itself or for example an [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) option.  I do in practice use post-processing and at times it *can* be the best solution.  However often it is more robust and performs better to construct your own plotting function using `Graphics` directly.  Here is a simple example:

```
myPlot[dat : {{_, _} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[Graphics]] := 
  Module[{rhold},
    rhold[{{x_, y_}, {X_, Y_}}] := {{x, y}, {X, y}};
    Graphics[Line[ rhold /@ Partition[dat, 2, 1] ], opts]
  ]
```

And its use:

```
myPlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {6, 0}},
  BaseStyle -> {Red, AbsoluteThickness[2]},
  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

You can create custom Options for your plot function to further customize its syntax.  See:

- [Functions with Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/353/functions-with-options/358#358)

Comment: Exactly! Thanks! I tried to get rid of the vertical lines generated by ListLinePlot as you afterwards, but with the conventional for-loop, which created some trouble with indexing. Your functional solution is much nicer!

Comment: @yadaddy You're welcome.  Now that I confirmed what you want I'll give you another way to generate it.  Look for an update in a few minutes.

Comment: @yadaddy Update complete.  By the way, welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange!

Comment: Thanks again. I understood the goal of the construction. Quite strange that this naturally appearing plot is not directly built in into Mathematica.

Comment: @yadaddy FYI: I modified `myPlot` to use only a single `Line` expression; this speeds rendering in the Front End.

Answer (score 6):

If you just wrap your data with `TemporalData`, you can `Plot` or `DiscretePlot` the `"PathFunction"`. In either case, there is no need for additional post- or pre-processing of the data to deal with jumps.

```
data = {{0, .5}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {6, 1}}; 
td = TemporalData[data];
```

**Using Plot and the  Exclusions option:**

```
Plot[Quiet@td["PathFunction"][x], {x, 0, 7}, PlotRange -> {0, 5},
 Exclusions -> td["Times"][[1]], PlotStyle -> Directive[{Red, Thick}]]
```

[image]

Note:  On v10.0.1 (Mac) you need to use `td["Times"]` instead of `td["Times"][[1]]` (Thanks: @BobHanlon)

**Using DiscretePlot and the  Extentsize option:**

```
DiscretePlot[Quiet@td["PathFunction"][x], {x, 0, 7}, PlotRange -> {0, 5},
 ExtentSize -> Right, Filling -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[{Red, Thick}]]
```

[image]

**Update:** In both cases, adding the option

```
Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[.02], Point[td["Path"]]}
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to post-processing the plot, you can pre-process the data.

```
data = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {6, 0}};

func[x_] = Total[Partition[data, 2, 1] /.
    {{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}} :>
     y1*(UnitStep[x - x1] - UnitStep[x - x2])] //
  Simplify
```

> Piecewise[{{2, Inequality[1, LessEqual, x, Less, 3] || 
>            Inequality[4, LessEqual, x, Less, 6]}, 
>        {4, Inequality[3, LessEqual, x, Less, 4]}}, 0]

```
Plot[func[x],
 {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[data]},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: This solution is a little bit slower when dealing with thousands of cases.

Comment: @yadaddy I am curious why you switched the Accept to this answer.  Is it not similar to my `myPlot` approach?  However using `Plot` is not as efficient as drawing `Line`s directly.  If there is a problem with my code please let me know and I shall try to correct it.

Comment: Didn't know that I can accept only one answer. All of the three answers give me an acceptable solution. Plot is slower, but for around 1000 cases the speed is still acceptable.

Comment: @yadaddy You can only Accept one answer but as you have discovered you can always change it.  Also you should not feel pressured to Accept any particular answer; it's a personal choice.  However when I lose an Accept I often wonder if I could have provided a better answer, which is why I asked.