# List(Line)Plot with a big jump

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a joined plot. Some possible ways would be `ListPlot` with `Joined -> True` or `ListLinePlot`.

However, my data contains a big jump(a plot of order parameter describing a first order transition) and I want to erase a long vertical line which connects the first points before and after the jump.

To be specific, consider the following data

```
a = { {0,0}, {1,0}, {2,0}, {3,5}, {4,6}, {5,7} };
```

Then, we can observe that there is the largest jump between the data `{2,0}` and `{3,5}` and 
I want to erase the line between those points leaving other lines.
What is the most elegant way to achieve it?

Comment: see this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65513/plotting-jump-function-without-vertical-lines) !

Comment: @SquareOne Thank you. This seems helpful even though my problem is slightly different. I will try the method described in the post and then check if it can be applied to my problem.  Since they are not exactly the same problem, I will leave this post open at this moment. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Insert a `Null` (or anything that's not a real number) where you want a gap. `ListLinePlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, Null, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 7}}]`

Comment: @Rahul Thank you. It works perfectly. Could you post it as an answer so that I can accept your solution.

Comment: The answer may be found in the documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html#1214999311), too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a `Null` (or anything that's not a real number) where you want a gap.

```
ListLinePlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, Null, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 7}}]
```

[image]