# How to make Which not connect its parts?

Tags: plotting, conditional

I've noticed that when "Mod" and "Which" are used to the same effect, they plot to slightly different results. Take the following example:

```
f[x_] = 2 x;
fmod[x_] = Mod[f[x], 1];
Plot[fmod[x], {x, 0, 1}]
fwhich[x_] = Which[x < 1/2, f[x], x > 1/2, f[x] - 1];
Plot[fwhich[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

The output graphs are:

[image]

[image]

How can I graph Which without getting that connecting line?

Comment: I would suggest that you use a `Piecewise` function definition in your case, rather than `Which`: `fpiece[x_] = Piecewise[{{f[x], x < 1/2}, {f[x] - 1, x > 1/2}}];`.

Comment: `fmod[1/2]` evaluates to 0. `fwhich[1/2]` is undefined. This may be related to the result you are seeing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting jump function without vertical lines](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65513/plotting-jump-function-without-vertical-lines)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As MarcoB already pointed out in the comments, [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) is probably the better alternative.

Additionally, we [already have a related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65513/187) with good answers where you can steal ideas from:

```
f[x_] = 2 x;
fmod[x_] = Mod[f[x], 1];
fwhich[x_] = Which[x < 1/2, f[x], x > 1/2, f[x] - 1];
Plot[fwhich[x], {x, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> {1/2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]