# How to deal with this list problem?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Now, I want to write a function for some kind of list. The input list includes many integers. Take a simple example for f[x],

```
lst = {3, 6, 13};

f[x_ /; (x <= lst[[1]] && x >= 1 )] := 1;
f[x_ /; (x <= (lst[[1]] + lst[[2]]) && x >= (lst[[1]] + 1)  )] := 2;
f[x_ /; (x <= (lst[[1]]+lst[[2]] + lst[[3]])&& x >= (lst[[1]] + lst[[2]] + 1))] := 3;
```

How to write a simple and general function f[x] for a arbitrary list ?

Comment: Are you looking for the index of the entry in the (sorted) list that is less than or equal to x?

Comment: `Accumulate[]` might be useful.

Comment: @KraZug  Yes,  using Accumulate[], it is more clear.  Accumulate[lst]={3,9,22}.  If  1=<x<=3, f[x]=1 ; if 4=<x<=9, f[x]=2;  if 10=<x<=22, f[x]=3.

Comment: And how do you want arguments between 3 and 4, and between 9 and 10 to be handled?

Comment: Sorry, x is interger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too hard:

```
idx = {3, 6, 13};
f = Function @@ {\[FormalX],
                 Piecewise[MapIndexed[Append[#2, #1] &,
                                      #1 <= \[FormalX] <= #2 & @@@
                                      TranslationTransform[{1, 0}][
                                      Partition[FoldList[Plus, 0, Sort[idx]], 2, 1]]],
                           Indeterminate]};

f /@ Range[22]
   {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}
```

Comment: Nice, as for the general case, just please remove the Sort, namely Sort[idx]--> idx.

Comment: Yes, if your lists are already sorted to begin with, just remove the `Sort[]`.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way.

```
makeF[data : {_Integer ..}] :=
  With[{nums = Accumulate[data]},
    f[n_Integer?Positive] :=
       Module[{r = $Failed},
         Do[If[n <= nums[[i]], r = i; Break[]], {i, Length[nums]}];
         r]]
```

Then

```
makeF[{3, 6, 13}]; Table[f[i], {i, 23}]
```

> `{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, $Failed}`

and

```
SeedRandom[42]; data = Sort[RandomSample[Range[99], 10]]
```

> `{4, 5, 7, 16, 33, 49, 55, 67, 82, 94}`

```
makeF[data]; Table[f[i], {i, 50, 450, 50}]
```

> `{5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, $Failed}`

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume that all values in your input list are positive integers.  This then is an interpolation with order zero, or index within a list.

Interpolation:

```
mkFn1[a_List] :=
  ListInterpolation[
    Join[{"lo"}, Range @ Length @ a, {"hi"}], 
    Join[{1}, Accumulate @ a, {Tr @ a + 1}]
    , InterpolationOrder -> 0
  ] /* Quiet
```

Binary search (you must load [Leonid's `bsearchMax`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2371/121)):

```
mkFn2[a_List] := Accumulate[a] /. acc_ :> ( bsearchMax[acc, #] & )
```

Output is a little different:

```
fn1 = mkFn1[{3, 6, 13}];
fn2 = mkFn2[{3, 6, 13}];

Array[fn1, 25, 0]
Array[fn2, 25, 0]
```

> ```
> {"lo", 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, "hi", "hi"}
>
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4}
> ```

("lo" and "hi" are arbitrary expressions I chose.)

Both methods are very fast.