# How to find the smallest position of an element of an ascending list {1,4,10,12,20} such that the element is not less than 11?

Tags: list-manipulation

Assume I  have an ordered, ascending list `{1,4,10,12,20}`.
I want to find the smallest position of an element of the list such that the element is not less than 11?
The position in question is 4.

How to do this easily?

Comment: @user1066: A nice idea. But your list is not the same as mine. `11` is not in the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
FirstPosition[{1, 4, 10, 12, 20}, _?(# >= 11 &)]

(* Out: {4} *)
```

If you want just the number $4$, then use `First@FirstPosition[...]`.

Comment: you need to add `=` after `>`.

Comment: @TooFatManNoNeck You're right! Fixed, thank you, and thanks for the accept as well.

Answer (score 4):

This question is closely related to the question [Best way to insert element into an ordered list at the correct position?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224249/731)
, where it was noted that Leonid Shifrin's `bsearchMax` from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2369/731) answer is a fast way to solve the problem. Like flinty's answer it uses a binary search but it appears to be faster.

```
bsearchMax[{1, 4, 10, 12, 20}, 11]
```

> 4

For a list of decent size, `bsearchMax` can be orders of magnitude faster than `FirstPosition`.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of slower alternatives to `FirstPosition`:

```
data = {1, 4, 10, 12, 20};

Position[data, SelectFirst[data, # >= 11 &]][[1, 1]]

Needs["Combinatorica`"]; Ceiling@BinarySearch[data, 11]
```

Answer (score 3):

As the list is in ascending order, maybe:

```
1+LengthWhile[{1, 4, 10,12,20}, # <11 &]
```

> 4

A slight variation on the `FirstPosition` [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/224823/106) of [MarcoB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27951/marcob) (originally posted as a comment):

```
FirstPosition[UnitStep[{1,4,10,12,20}-11],1]
```

> {4}