# Matching pair of numbers {a,-a}, where a is numeric

Tags: pattern-matching, numerical-value

Imagine you have a list of pairs of numbers, such as

```
{{2,-2}, {1,5}, {1,-3},{-3,3}}
```

The task is to reduce the given list to a list of pairs of type `{a,-a}`, where a may be any real number, i.e. our initial list should be reduced to `{{2,-2},{-3,3}}`.

I have come up with a somewhat cumbersome solution

```
DeleteCases[{{2, -2}, {1, 5}, {1, -3}, {-3, 3}}, {a_, b_} /; a + b != 0]
```

which is, on top of that, not particularly fast. The following code

```
Ta = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -1000, 1000}, {j, -1000, 1000}], 1];
Timing[DeleteCases[Ta, {a_, b_} /; a != -b]]`
```

yields

> ```
> 4.945, {{-1000, 1000}, {-999, 999}, (*...I have cut out the rest*)}
> ```

Now the question is:

- Is this an overkill?
- Can I perform the task in a more efficient manner?
- Can I maybe define the pattern in a more natural way, which happens to be more efficient as well?

Thanks a lot!

**P.S.:**

The question might be a bit ambiguous but I'd like to hear all your suggestions. :)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: What's the distribution of pair signs? Any of the answers so far s/b easy to better for non-uniform. For that matter, how large are lists you care about? For up to midsized ones, anything other than deletecases should suffice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
lst = {{2, -2}, {1, 5}, {1, -3}, {-3, 3}};
Pick[lst, Total[lst, {2}], 0]
```

> {{2,-2}, {-3,3}}

```
First @ Timing[res0 = Pick[Ta, Total[Ta, {2}], 0];]
```

> 0.093750

```
First @ Timing[res0a = Pick[Ta, Total /@ Ta, 0];]
```

> 0.187500

```
First @ Timing[res0b = Pick[Ta, Plus @@ Transpose[Ta], 0];] (*thanks: 2012rcampion *)
```

> 0.062500

```
First @ Timing[res1 = DeleteCases[Ta, {a_, b_} /; a != -b];]
```

> 4.093750

```
First @ Timing[res2 = Cases[Ta, {a_, b_} /; a + b == 0];]
```

> 3.656250

```
Equal @@ {res0, res0a, res0b, res1, res2}
```

> True

**Update:** for the case where `a` is any real number you can `Unitize` the selector array (thanks: @MrWizard):

```
First @ Timing[Pick[Ta, Unitize@Total[Ta, {2}], 0];]
```

> 0.125000

```
First @ Timing[Pick[Ta, Unitize[Total /@ Ta], 0];]
```

> 0.156250

```
First @ Timing[Pick[Ta, Unitize[Plus @@ Transpose[Ta]], 0];]
```

> 0.046875

Comment: Much faster!  Why is that?

Comment: You can get a 2-3x speedup by using `Plus @@ Transpose[Ta]` instead of `Total[Ta, {2}]`.

Comment: Most of the time goes into computing the `Pick` selection criterion, and `Plus @@ Transpose[Ta]` indeed is nearly twice as fast as `Total[Ta, {2}]`.  Since all these approaches involve the same simple calculations, some pipelining must be involved in the faster ones to compensate for the extra memory accesses.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, `Pick` usually is faster than its siblings `Select`, `Cases`, `DeleteCases`. Re why, I will try to find references in this site.

Comment: @2012rcampion, thank you; updated with your suggested selector array.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The keyword is *packed arrays*.  Working with packed arrays is very fast, but many functions don't support them.  [Since version 8 only, `Pick` will work with packed arrays when used in certain ways.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11/12)

Comment: @bbgodfrey You touched on a big annoyance of Mathematica.  *Performance is really hard to predict and unintuitive.*  How could you have known that `Pick` would be so fast? There's no way to guess it and no documentation on this.  I know it due to experience and having spent too much time on this site.  Regarding faster alternatives to things like `Select` or `Cases`, check out my [BoolEval package](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/pages/mathematica.html), which only works in special situations, but when it does, it can be *much* faster.

Comment: Mischa says *any real number* so you will need to add `Unitize` to your `Pick` code to catch inexact zeros. +1 nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

```
Cases[{{2, -2}, {1, 5}, {1, -3}, {-3, 3}}, {a_, b_} /; a + b == 0]
```

produces the same result and is modestly faster.

```
Ta = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -1000, 1000}, {j, -1000, 1000}], 1];
Timing[DeleteCases[Ta, {a_, b_} /; a != -b];]
(* {4.34375, Null} *)

Timing[Cases[Ta, {a_, b_} /; a + b == 0];]
(* {3.92188, Null} *)
```

An irreducible amount of time goes to loading each pair, comparing the elements, and writing the answers to a new `List`.  Probably, we are near that irreducible limit.  In fact, I am uncertain why `Cases` would work faster than `DeleteCases` in this instance, since they both do the same thing.

Comment: The `:> {a, b}` is unnecessary in your `Cases` statement and might squeeze a few milliseconds off the timing!

Comment: You are correct, and I shall make the change, but it saves no time.  Thanks.

Comment: I found that a conditional pattern takes about twice as long to evaluate as a construct such as `Cases[{#[[1]], -#[[2]]} & /@ ta, {a_, a_}]`. Mr.Wizard's answer vastly outperforms us though.