# Finding the longest word in a list (WordList[])

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Hi guys I am having problems with finding the longest word available in `WordList["English"]` 
I have found that the longest word has 24 characters  thanks  to this line

```
Max[StringLength[WordList[]]]
```

but I don't know how to find the position of the word Knowing her length. I thought I need some selection rule but I fail to implement it. any help?

Comment: So you want to know the longest word, its position in the list or both?

Comment: Answer to the title: `MaximalBy[StringLength]@WordList[]`.

Comment: the word, however  i think i need the position to use Take[WordList[],n]...

Comment: You need the position for `Take` but don't assume you need `Take`.

Comment: @Kuba wow cool thanks

Comment: Now that you know that the longest entry in `WordList[]` is 24 characters long, why not `Select[]` all the entries in it whose `StringLength[]` is `==` 24? (This is one of the things I like about this language; sometimes the solution statement directly translates to usable code.)

Comment: @Kuba    however  how would you find the position?

Comment: @J.M. i tried with select, but i think  the syntax i used was wrong and couldnt make it work

Comment: What was the code you used with `Select[]`? We can suss out what you did wrong if you post it.

Comment: @J.M.    Select[WorldList[], StringLength[#] = 24 & ]  i tried with Cases too with no results ( it's the first time i use select and cases)

Comment: @Alucard, try using `==` (`Equal[]`) instead of `=` (`Set[]`).

Comment: nvm it worked, i wrote worldlist instead of wordlist xD

Comment: Do post your code as an answer if you managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok one solution  I found, aside the  one given by Kuba , is

```
length = Max[StringLength[WordList[]]]
Select[WordList[], StringLength[#] == length & ]
```

a second solution  with the function `Pick[]` is

```
Pick[WordList[], StringLength[WordList[]], length]
```

A third one with `Cases[]`

```
f = StringLength[#] == 24 &;
Cases[WordList[], x_ /; f[x]]
```

a BarChart with the absolutetiming:

[image: absolute timing of the different functions]

Comment: Well done. If you need further exercise, think about how to implement this with `Pick[]` or `Cases[]`.

Comment: @J.M. i will thanks

Comment: @J.M. i found the two additional solutions but   i did not understand the difference between the patterns used with Cases and the function with select[].what's the difference?they do exactly the same thing...

Comment: @Alucard This [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-best-practices-or-performance-considerations-are-there-for-choosing-between) should answer your question.