# Deleting unwanted elements in lists of words

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have imported *Alice in Wonderland* into Mathematica. I have made a list of the sentences and further divided them into words. Now suppose, nominally, I have the following list:

```
l={{"alice's", "adventures", "in", "wonderland", "lewis", "carroll", 
  "the", "millennium", "fulcrum", "edition", "3.0", "chapter", "i", 
  "down", "rabbit-hole", "alice", "was", "beginning", "to", "get", 
  "very", "tired", "of", "sitting", "by", "her", "sister", "on", 
  "bank", "and", "having", "nothing", "do", "once", "or", "twice", 
  "she", "had", "peeped", "into", "book", "reading", "but", "it", 
  "no", "pictures", "conversations", "what", "is", "use", "a", 
  "thought", "without", "conversation", "so", "considering", "own", 
  "mind", "as", "well", "could", "for", "hot", "day", "made", "feel", 
  "sleepy", "stupid", "whether", "pleasure", "making", "daisy-chain", 
  "would", "be", "worth", "trouble", "getting", "up", "picking", 
  "daisies", "when", "suddenly", "white", "rabbit", "with", "pink", 
  "eyes", "ran", "close"}, {"there", "was", "nothing", "so", "very", 
  "remarkable", "in", "that", "nor", "did", "alice", "think", "it", 
  "much", "out", "of", "the", "way", "to", "hear", "rabbit", "say", 
  "itself", "oh", "dear"}}
```

How can I go through each elements and delete those words that contain `"'"`, `"-"` or they are number like `3.0`
The outcome should look like:

```
{{"adventures", "in", "wonderland", "lewis", "carroll", 
      "the", "millennium", "fulcrum", "edition", "chapter", "i", 
      "down", "alice", "was", "beginning", "to", "get", 
      "very", "tired", "of", "sitting", "by", "her", "sister", "on", 
      "bank", "and", "having", "nothing", "do", "once", "or", "twice", 
      "she", "had", "peeped", "into", "book", "reading", "but", "it", 
      "no", "pictures", "conversations", "what", "is", "use", "a", 
      "thought", "without", "conversation", "so", "considering", "own", 
      "mind", "as", "well", "could", "for", "hot", "day", "made", "feel", 
      "sleepy", "stupid", "whether", "pleasure", "making", 
      "would", "be", "worth", "trouble", "getting", "up", "picking", 
      "daisies", "when", "suddenly", "white", "rabbit", "with", "pink", 
      "eyes", "ran", "close"}, {"there", "was", "nothing", "so", "very", 
      "remarkable", "in", "that", "nor", "did", "alice", "think", "it", 
      "much", "out", "of", "the", "way", "to", "hear", "rabbit", "say", 
      "itself", "oh", "dear"}}
```

I have tried `DeleteCases[l,_?ContainsAll[{"'"}]]` yet it did not work.

Comment: Because they are strings, check `StringContainsQ`

Comment: Thanks @gwr it does the job

Comment: `Select[LetterQ] /@ l`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pick[l, StringFreeQ["-" | "'" | DigitCharacter] /@ l]
```

> {{"adventures", "in", "wonderland", "lewis", "carroll", "the", 
>      "millennium", "fulcrum", "edition", "chapter", "i", "down", 
>      "alice", "was", "beginning", "to", "get", "very", "tired", "of", 
>      "sitting", "by", "her", "sister", "on", "bank", "and", "having", 
>      "nothing", "do", "once", "or", "twice", "she", "had", "peeped", 
>      "into", "book", "reading", "but", "it", "no", "pictures", 
>      "conversations", "what", "is", "use", "a", "thought", "without", 
>      "conversation", "so", "considering", "own", "mind", "as", "well", 
>      "could", "for", "hot", "day", "made", "feel", "sleepy", "stupid", 
>      "whether", "pleasure", "making", "would", "be", "worth", "trouble",
>       "getting", "up", "picking", "daisies", "when", "suddenly", 
>      "white", "rabbit", "with", "pink", "eyes", "ran", 
>      "close"},
>   {"there", "was", "nothing", "so", "very", "remarkable", 
>      "in", "that", "nor", "did", "alice", "think", "it", "much", "out", 
>      "of", "the", "way", "to", "hear", "rabbit", "say", "itself", "oh", 
>      "dear"}}}

This is several times faster than `DeleteCases`+`StringContainsQ` combination on input `l`:

```
Pick[l, StringFreeQ["-" | "'" | DigitCharacter] /@ l] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.000042

```
DeleteCases[l,  x_String /; StringContainsQ[x, "'" | "-" | NumberString], Infinity] //
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00025

Comment: (+1) Good old `Pick` made me look up this old post: [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2/764). Is it still relevant?

Comment: @gwr, thank you for the upvote. Re `Pick` vs `Cases` vs `Select`, I am not sure if `Pick` is still the fastest of the three (my impression (based on few cases) is that `Cases` and `Select` has improved since v9.)

Answer (score 3):

To make this post complete I have moved my comment here as an answer:

```
DeleteCases[ l, x_String /; StringContainsQ[x, "'" | "-" | NumberString ] , Infinity]
```

or

```
DeleteCases[l, _String?(StringContainsQ[#, "'" | "-" | NumberString ] &), Infinity]
```

Using `RepeatedTiming` reveals that the `Condition` version is minimally faster than the `PatternTest` version. It takes about 0.00021 secs on my machine. Note, that looking for patterns with head `String` only (e.g. `_String`) will speed up the process.

Alan's suggestion ( `Select[LetterQ] /@ l` ) is very concise and readable but will take twice as long (0.00041 secs) on my machine. Probably `LetterQ` does a bit more checks?

**Update**

kglr nicely shows how fast `Pick` is here and I linked an old post for those interested on why that may be. As `LetterQ` does more testing than the three `Alternatives` given above it may be worth mentioning that `DigitCharacter` as used by kglr also is faster than `NumberString`:

```
DeleteCases[l, x_String /; StringContainsQ[x, "'" | "-" | NumberString], Infinity] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00020

```
DeleteCases[l, x_String /; StringContainsQ[x, "'" | "-" | NumberString], Infinity] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00014