# What are all the ways to remove noise from an image and how to choose the right method?

Tags: image-processing, image

I am learning how to use image processing and I am a bit overwhelmed by all the options to remove speckle noise in an image. Here is a list of functions that I learned about:

- [`MedianFilter`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MedianFilter.html)
- [`DeleteSmallComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteSmallComponents.html)
- [`TopHatTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TopHatTransform.html)
- [`BottomHatTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BottomHatTransform.html)
- [`GeodesicOpening`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeodesicOpening.html)
- [`MorphologicalTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MorphologicalTransform.html)[img,{Min,Max}]
- [`MorphologicalTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MorphologicalTransform.html)[img,"Clean"]

How does one choose between these options ? How can one know in advance which functions are better suited for a certain scenario ?

Comment: For the person that down voted, could you please explain why so that I may adjust my questions ? No one learns anything from a down vote without any explanation. Perhaps the downvote was because the question was deemed too broad but it is an actual questions on how to use Mathematica functions. For example the question [What best practices or performance considerations are there for choosing between Cases, Position, Pick and Select?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2/86543) is also broad but is useful and is a real question about choosing Mathematica functions.

Comment: The documentation on these functions give examples that to the inexperienced eye look all the same and I think everyone would benefit from comparisons that actually show how these functions differ.

Answer (score 3):

See Applications at each of the following pages.

- [MaxDetect](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxDetect.html)
- [BilateralFilter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BilateralFilter.html?q=BilateralFilter)
- [FourierDCTFilter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierDCTFilter.html)
- [TotalVariationFilter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TotalVariationFilter.html)
- [CurvatureFlowFilter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurvatureFlowFilter.html)
- [GeodesicClosing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeodesicClosing.html)
- [WienerFilter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WienerFilter.html)

Notice the application for MaxDetect also uses Inpaint and MinDetect.